# Chessboard pattern

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

**Input:**
a positive number \$n\$, smaller than \$80\$, from stdin or as a command-line argument.

**Output:** A square chessboard pattern, the size of the input number. The dark fields are represented by the letter `X`, the white fields by a space. The top-left field should be `X`.

A complete program is required. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins

---

**Examples:**

**Input**: 1

**Output**:

```
X
```

**Input**: 8

**Output**:

```
X X X X 
 X X X X
X X X X 
 X X X X
X X X X 
 X X X X
X X X X 
 X X X X
```

Comment: I was looking for a tag like 'light-weight' for this.

Comment: Whole and complete program, I suppose?

Comment: @J B: Yes. How do I formulate that? Add 'to stdout' to the required output?

Comment: Just say you want a complete program.  You might also want to specify **command-line** arguments, to prevent confusion with function arguments.

Comment: When you say top-right, do you mean top-left? If not, please correct the example output for input 8.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: This is.. it is... well , it is corrected.

Comment: I assume an input of zero should produce no output?

Comment: Was it intentional that this is described as a *chessboard* pattern, yet the board is placed incorrectly for a game of chess? (Should have light square in the bottom right.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, 13 chars

Note: Pyth is much too new to be eligible to win. However, it was a fun golf and I thought I'd share it.

```
VQ<*QX*d2N\XQ
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

How it works:

```
                       Q = eval(input())
VQ                     for N in range(Q):
  <         Q                                                        [:Q]
   *Q                                    (Q*                        )
     X*d2N\X                                assign_at(" "*2, N, "X")
```

Basically, this uses `X` to generate `"X "` or `" X"` alternately, then repeats that string `Q` times, and takes its first `Q` characters. This is repeated `Q` times.

How does the `X` (assign at) function work? It takes the original string, `"  "` in this case, an assignment location, `N` in this case, and a replacement character, `"X"` in this case. Since Pyth's assignments are modular, this replaces the space at location `N%2` with an `X`, and returns the resultant string, which is therefore `"X "` on the first, third, etc. lines, and `" X"` on the others.

Comment: ... but APL isn't. Thanks for bumping. Wonder if OP will re-accept...

Comment: "Pyth is much too new to be eligible to win" I don't understand this and reaccept this one.

Comment: @steenslag To explain, there is a standard loophole that languages newer than the question are ineligible. This is to prevent languages specifically designed to do well at a specific challenge. You're free to do what you want with your challenge, of course.

Answer (score 12):

### Golfscript - 17 chars

```
~:N,{"X "N*>N<n}%
```

Analysis

`~` convert input to an int
`:N` store in the variable N
`,{...}` for each value of [0...N-1]
`"X "N*` repeat "X " to give a string of N*2 characters
`>` take the substring starting from the loop index...
`N<` ...ending N characters later
`n` put a newline a the end of each string

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, <s>41</s> 40

```
for$i(1..$_){say substr" X"x$_,$i%2,$_}
```

Perl 5.10 or later, run with `perl -nE 'code'` (`n` counted in code size)

Sample output:

```
$ perl -nE'for$i(1..$_){say substr" X"x 40,$i%2,$_}' <<<5
X X X
 X X
X X X
 X X
X X X
$ perl -nE'for$i(1..$_){say substr" X"x 40,$i%2,$_}' <<<8
X X X X
 X X X X
X X X X
 X X X X
X X X X
 X X X X
X X X X
 X X X X
```

Comment: What does the 'x' in 'x 40' do?

Comment: @steenslag: `x` is the string repetition operator. `'a' x 3` yields `'aaa'`.

Answer (score 4):

#### Python, 48 Characters

```
x,i=input(),0
exec'print(x*"X ")[i:i+x];i^=1;'*x
```

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 76 characters

```
n=input()
p='X '*n
print n/2*(p[:n]+'\n'+p[1:n+1]+'\n'),
if n&1:print p[:n]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Scala - <strike>141</strike> 95 characters

```
var a=args(0).toInt
for(y<-1 to a;x<-1 to a)print((if((x+y)%2<1)"X"else" ")+("\n"*(x/a)take 1))
```

Usage: `scala filename N` where n is your input to the program.

Answer (score 3):

### APL (16)

Assuming `⎕IO=0` (i.e. zero-indexed arrays, it is a setting)

```
' X'[=/¨2⊤¨⍳2⍴⎕]
```

Explanation:

- `⍳2⍴⎕`: read a number N, and create a N×N matrix containing (0,0) to (N-1,N-1).
- `2⊤¨`: get the least significant bit of each number in the matrix. (So now we have (0,0), (0,1), (0,0)... (1,0), (1,1), (1,0)...)
- `=/¨`: for each pair, see if the two numbers are equal. (Now we have 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...)
- `' X'[`...`]`: put a space for each 0 and an X for each 1.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby <s>45</s> 42

```ruby
(x=gets.to_i).times{|i|puts ("X "*x)[i,x]}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Mw25e

Comment: `(x=gets.to_i).times` saves three chars. Why the sudden  renewed interest in this oldie?

Comment: @steenslag Thanks! I've applied your tip. I just saw this question at the top of the list and thought I'd post an answer to dust off my Ruby skills. Apparently I haven't dusted them off enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck, 140 bytes

```
-[+[+<]>>+]>++++[<++++++++>-]<<<<<<,[->+>+>+<<<]>>[->[->.<[->>.>]<<<]<[<<<]>>>>>[-<+>]>[-<+>]<<[->>+<<]<<[-<+>]<[->+>>+<<<]++++++++++.[-]>>]
```

Answer (score 2):

### C++ - 253 obfuscated characters

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main(int i,char*c[]=0)
{
  char a=i,b=i>>8;i&32512?((i>>16&255)<a)?(cout<<b)?main((i^30720)+65536):0:(cout<<endl)?(((b=(i>>24)+1)<a)?main((i&2130706559)+((b&1)?16785408:16799744)):0):0:main((i>=2?atoi(1[c]):8)|22528);
}
```

Comment: I love all the magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 169

```
function b(w){var i=w,j=w,r='';while(i--){while(j--){if((i+j)%2)r+=' ';else r+='X'}j=w;r+="\n"}return r}do{n=parseInt(prompt('Number'))}while(isNaN(n)||n<1);alert(b(n));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can convert to number like `+'1'` instead of `parseInt('1')`. Won't give you an integer, but I don't think having it be an integer is important here, is it?

Answer (score 2):

## k (26 chars)

26 For bare function:

```
{-1',/x#',x#'("X ";" X");}
```

Or a further 7 to take input from stdin

```
{-1',/x#',x#'("X ";" X");}"I"$0:0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Bash: 60 characters

```sh
yes X|fmt -w80|paste -d '' <(yes '
 ') -|head -$1|cut -c1-$1
```

The table size is passed as command-line parameter, for example `bash chesstable.sh 8`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function. Requires `⎕IO←0` (zero-based indexing).

```apl
'X '⊇⍨2|⍳+⍀⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/9UjFNQfdbU/6l1hVPOod7P2o94GIPU/DSj5qLcPoq6r@dB640dtE4G84CBnIBni4Rn8P03BkEtXV5crTcEUSlsAAA)

`⍳` **ɩ**ndices 0…n–1

`+⍀` plus table with that horizontally and vertically:

`⍳` **ɩ**ndices 0…n–1

`2|` division remainder when divided by two

`'X '⊇⍨` use that matrix to index into the string

Answer (score 2):

## Java 10, lambda function, <s>92</s> <s>87</s> 84 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=0;i<n*n;)System.out.print(((i%n+i/n)%2<1?"X":" ")+(++i%n<1?"\n":""));}
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##lY9BawIxEIXP2V8xBITExa1bEKSr7cGzJy9C20PMRju6TpYkCkX2t2@z2x5swYKnYd6b983MXp3VyNaG9uWhrU@bCjXoSnkPS4UEl4QhBeO2ShtYfBh9MG5jlSs7h50tltC3Ik4BySJhTcJ@MD6oEEs/dIwwsQoOaff6DsrtvOwJv5D6uplDS6Pny9a6no3zcYEzGlIhV58@mGNmTyGrIzAIIXBAKT6QHDzO8he@5k8cuExFmkajU94oSlzKomkZi0ey61XZ9wd5dz37C69IyBuB6b2BfPJfokma9gs).

Thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for golfing 4 bytes and to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for golfing 3 more.

Ungolfed version:

```java
n -> { // void lambda taking an int as argument
    for(int i = 0; i < n*n; ) // loop over the entire square
            System.out.print(((i%n + i/n) % 2 < 1 ? "X" : " ") // print an 'X' or a space depending on which line&column we're on
               + (++i % n < 1 ? "\n" : "")); // print a newline at the end of a line
}
```

## Java 8, full program, <s>155</s> 139 bytes

```java
interface M{static void main(String[]a){int i=0,n=new Byte(a[0]);for(;i<n*n;)System.out.print(((i%n+i/n)%2<1?"X":" ")+(++i%n<1?"\n":""));}}
```

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##FYtPC4IwFMC/yhgIWyuzTtGUoHsnL4F5GDrlGb6JvgwRP/ta19@fzszm4AaLXf32HpDs2JjKssc6kSGo2OygZr0BFDmNgG1RGrmGjkGW7DFD@2X3hawwRVJK3bhRaEhxh1rmy0S2j92H4iGcJISACBUcUUbn9HTjT37ljEsllAriT14YEJdSb5v3/vID).

Ungolfed version:

```java
interface M {
    static void main(String[] a) {
        int i = 0, // iterator variable for the loop
            n = new Byte(a[0]); // take the argument and convert it to an int
        for(; i < n*n; ) // loop over the entire square
            System.out.print( ((i%n + i/n) % 2 < 1 ? "X" : " ") // print an 'X' or a space depending on which line&column we're on
                             +(++i % n < 1 ? "\n" : "") ); // print a newline at the end of a line
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks! I managed to shave off one more byte, and applied your approach to my full program as well. 16 bytes saved there.

Comment: Doing two `s+=` is 2 bytes shorter than those parenthesis: `n->{var s="";for(int i=0;i<n*n;s+=++i%n<1?"\n":"")s+=(i%n+i/n)%2<1?"X":" ";return s;}`

Comment: Or 1 more byte off (84 in total) by printing directly (with the parenthesis back again xD): `n->{for(int i=0;i<n*n;)System.out.print(((i%n+i/n)%2<1?"X":" ")+(++i%n<1?"\n":""));}`. [Try it online.](https://tinyurl.com/y9xqh6bu)

Comment: Suggest `"X ".charAt(i%n+i/n&1)` instead of `((i%n+i/n)%2<1?"X":" ")`

Answer (score 2):

## Japt, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
ÆîSi'XY
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xu5TaSdYWQ==&input=OAoKLVI=)

**<s>7</s> 6 bytes** if we can replace `X` with `x`:

```
ÆîSixY
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xu5TaXhZ&input=OAoKLVI=)

---

Alternative **8 byte** solution:

```
Æî"X "éY
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=xu4iWCAi6Vk=&input=OAoKLVI=)

Comment: Ah, you edited while I was in chat! Was gonna suggest the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes

```python
n=input()
s='X '*n
exec"print s[:n];s=s[1:];"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDk6vYVj1CQV0rjyu1IjVZqaAoM69EoTjaKi/Wuti2ONrQKtZaSSvv/39TAA)

---

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 47 bytes**

```python
n=input()
i=0
exec"i^=1;print'X'*i+n/2*' X';"*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P882M6@gtERDkyvT1oArtSI1WSkzztbQuqAoM69EPUJdK1M7T99IS10hQt1aSSvv/39TAA)

Trims trailing space.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 68 bytes

```
  def^(n:Int)=for(a<-1 to n)println(("x_"*n).substring(n%2+1,n+n%2+1))
```

or

```
  def^(n:Int)=for(a<-1 to n)println(("x_"*n).substring(a%2+1).take(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcrBCoJAEADQe18xCMJMobgdIw8d@wlj1FEqmV3cCQTx2zcvXh8vdjxx8u1HOgMPsphoH@ERAqypl6FBvT3VqB78jHwvHJgHpTC/1SZFzJZXdlYq46@NtuOInF8vjkrjr6ASpaM26Cqi05b@)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
:&+o~88*c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30pNO7/OwkIr@f9/CwA)

ASCII `c` 88 multiplied `*` by not `~` the parity `o` of the broadcast self-addition `&+` of the range `:` from 1 to the input.

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript, 67 bytes

```
for(j=n=readline()|0;j--;)console.log(' X'.repeat(n).substr(j%2,n))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SCPLNs@2KDUxJSczL1VDs8bAOktX11ozOT@vOD8nVS8nP11DXSFCXa8otSA1sUQjT1OvuDSpuASoT9VIJ09T8/9/QzMuAA)

### C, 83 bytes

```
i,j;main(n){for(scanf("%d",&n);i++<n;puts(""))for(j=0;j<n;)putchar(i+j++&1?88:32);}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6NzEzTyNPszotv0ijODkxL01DSTVFSUctT9M6U1vbJs@6oLSkWENJSVMTpCLL1sA6CyioCRRNzkgs0lBSiFCKztTO0tZWM4zVtK79/98CAA)

### Basic C64, 89 bytes

```
1 INPUTN:FORI=1TON;FORJ=1TON:IFI+JAND1THENPRINT" ";:GOTO3
2 PRINT"X";
3 NEXT:PRINT"":NEXT
```

[image]

Comment: You may use the `on...go to` command conditionally, like `ON-(I+JAND1)GOTO3:?"X";:` where it is zero, it will fall through to the following statement, in this case, if `(I + J AND 1) === 0` then it will print the X. This allows you to pack in more statements per line and save bytes.

Comment: C [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fco7CoAwDADQq0jAklA7uAnRewjiUCJqC0bxM4lnr7o@nrhJJKVQRF58UFS6x3XHQ7yOCPkAhVHiYG2tvF3ngQBE/4iNcnSO6VOZ/Y7QZtAFG03ZEz8pVS8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, 40 and 54

The number of characters is 40 for a function, 54 for a complete program.

**The solution giving only a function body is:**

`("X "*n)sliding n take n foreach println`

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##PccxCgIxEAXQfk7x2Sqx02oRLCytbWzHZEajcTZsUgji2aMLYvV4NXDmPp1vEhqO/ChZIM8mFiv2peBFFEWhzrY4WPPYobvhhGFlvuYUk11gaHyXLzrNwuGKMidr2bq6tadfiNRt/sPS0dO7fwA)

**The solution giving a complete program is:**

`val n=readInt;("X "*n)sliding n take n foreach println`

You can run it using the following command line.

`scala -e 'val n=readInt;("X "*n)sliding n take n foreach println' <<< 8`

where 8 is the input.

Comment: Welcome to PP&CG and nice first answer. There's a nice site called [Try It Online](https://tio.run/) that allows you to get easy byte counts and share runs. Check [the other Scala answer to see an example of it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185398/78849). It's not required mind you, just nice to have.

Comment: Thanks @Veskah for the suggestion.

Comment: Nice solution changing this to a function and using map you get 34 Characters: `("X "*n)sliding n take n map println`

Comment: @pme Thanks for the suggestion, but there is no output if I replace foreach with map. However I change it to a function as you suggested.

Comment: you are right - sorry seems map is lazy;(.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 249 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>->+++>-[<+>---]+>>>>>>+[[-]>,[>++++++[<-------->-]<<<[->>++++++++++<<]>+>[-<<+>>]]<]<[<+<+>>-]<<[->[->+<<<+<[<<<.>>>->-<]>[<<<.>>+>-]>>]++++++++++.[-]>[<+>>+<-]>>++<[>->+<[>]>[<+>-]<<[<]>-]>[-]>-[<<<<<<<[>+<[-]]+>[<->-]>>>>>>[-]]<<<<<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BCsMwDAQfpCjnHIQ@InRoA4VS6KHQ97uzjqHrWNiSPNrcP7fn@/E9X2OkFys60wieZkYqCO5tOWVV3rmViqjCl9I7IspzVaQAYwkSRnZHBzSd1UsrHz2kirhDh8KTdWMuVvqP2zVafnilEgNKNolXfmJlnSvbBZJKPd78A34nVVJmlnuM4wc)

Could definitely be golfed more.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>83</s> 82 bytes

-2 thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

And -5 more by [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat). Iterate backwards for extra confusion!

Another -1 by [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat). Iterate using negative integers for extra confusion!

```c
m;main(n,v)int**v;{for(n*=m=~(n=atoi(v[1]));n++;)putchar(n%m?n%m-n/m&1?88:32:10);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/XOjcxM08jT6dMMzOvREurzLo6Lb9II0/LNte2TiPPNrEkP1OjLNowVlPTOk9b21qzoLQkOSMRqEI11x6IdfP0c9UM7S0srIyNrAwNNK1r////bwEA)

**Ungolfed**

```c
m;

main(n, v) int**v;
{
    for (n *= m = ~(n = atoi(v[1])); n++;)
        putchar(n % m ? n % m - n / m & 1 ? 88 : 32 : 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python - 127 characters

```
from sys import*
r=stdout.write
s=int(raw_input())
[[r((x+y+1)%2 and"x"or" ")for x in range(s)]and r("\n")for y in range(s)]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C - <strike>92</strike> 86

```
i,j;main(n){for(scanf("%d",&n);i<n;puts(""),i++)for(j=0;j<n;j++)putchar("X "[i+j&1]);}
```

Comment: [83 Bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9TJ8s6NzEzTyNPszotv0ijODkxL01DSTVFSUctT9M6U1vbJs@6oLSkWENJSVMTpCLL1sA6CyioCRRNzkgs0lBSiFCKztTO0tZWM4zVtK79/98CAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Python

**48 Chars**

**EDIT:** Kinda Wrong...There's an extra space at the end...but thats not visible. If you change the space to "O" (or any nonwhitespace char) then modify `[i%2:n]` to `[i%2:n+i%2]`. for the correct version.

```
n=input()
i=0;
while i<n:print('X '*n)[i%2:n];i+=1
```

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 33

```
{$[1=x mod 2;x;x-1]cut(x*x)#"X "}
```

Comment: `{(x;x-1-x mod 2)#"X "}` for 22... ah no, has the same bug as yours - doesnt have 4 X's on the odd rows for input 8.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby 58

```
i=ARGV[0].to_i
1.upto(i*i){|n|print n%i==0?"\n":' x'[n%2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## VB.net, 161

```
Module C
   Sub Main()
     Dim n As Integer
     If Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine,n) Then
     For x=1To n
        For y=1To n
          Console.Write("* "((x+y)Mod 2))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
      Next
     End If
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP - 136 chars (without whitespace)

Allows for x and y function input.

*Also supports odd inputs now.*

If you style the output to have 0.65 em line-height and change this ▒█ and █░ to □■ and ■□ then it comes out looking like a real  (square) chessboard.

### Code:

```
function gen_cb($x,$y)
{
$c=0;
$y*=2;
for($i=0;$i<$y;$i++){
for($j=0;$j<$x;$j++){
echo $c%2==0 ? "░█" : "█░";
}
echo "<br/>";
$c++;
}
}
gen_cb(7,7);
```

### Output:

```
░█░█░█░█░█░█░█
█░█░█░█░█░█░█░
░█░█░█░█░█░█░█
█░█░█░█░█░█░█░
░█░█░█░█░█░█░█
█░█░█░█░█░█░█░
░█░█░█░█░█░█░█
```

Comment: Does it work for boards with an odd number of squares per side?

Comment: @Gareth Now it does

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 87

```
for($x=0;$x<$m=$argv[1];$x++){echo"\n";for($y=0;$y<$m;$y++)echo($y^($x%2))%2?' ':'X';}
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 18 bytes

I probably could have just ported the GolfScript answer, but here is a different approach. (And CJam is not eligible for winning anyway.)

```
l~,_f{f{+2%S'X?}N}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

The idea is to iterate over the 2D grid with x and y indices on the stack, using [the `f{f{...}}` trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/40433/8478). Given x and y, we can simply determine black and white as `(x+y)%2` and use that to pick between the character `X` and a string containing a space.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 21 chars

J was missing too.

```
   ([:u:32+56*=/~@$&1 0) 5
X X X
 X X 
X X X
 X X 
X X X
```

Previous, 22 chars:

Char codes from mod2 pattern of `row #` + `column #`:

```
   ([:u:88-56*2&|@+/~@i.) 5
```

Comment: -2 Bytes: `([:{&' X'=/~@$&1 0)`

Comment: 14 bytes `'X '{~2|+/~@i.` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1SMU1KvrjGq09escMvX@a3KlJmfkK6QpmEIY6uowAYv/AA "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 75 bytes

```
for(;@$i++<$k=$argv[1];){for($j=0;$j++<$k;)echo($i+$j)%2?' ':'X';echo"\n";}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v1.4.6 [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 bytes

```
Æç"X " tXU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI=&code=xuciWCAiIHRYVQ==&input=OA==)

-3 bytes thanks to @Shaggy!

```
Æç"X " tXU   # full program
Æ            # generate a range of numbers based on input
             # and map each number through a function 
 ç"X "       # inside the function, repeat "X " a bunch of times
       tXU   # select a substring from the "X " repeated string
             # The -R flag joins the array with new lines
```

Comment: [10 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI=&code=xuciWCAiIHRYVQ==&input=OA==)

Comment: Nice interpreter :)

Comment: Thanks :) Drop into [the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34018/japt) if you have any feedback or feature requests.

Comment: @Shaggy [8 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181925/61613) :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
XX＼ｍ⤢ｍ
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=WFgldUZGM0MldUZGNEQldTI5MjIldUZGNEQ_,i=OA__,v=8)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 61 bytes

```cs
x=>{for(int i=x++*x;--i>0;)Write(" X\n"[i%x<1?2:i/x+i%x&1]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/O@YXJKZn2eTmVdip5CmYPu/wtauOi2/SAMooJBpW6GtrVVhraubaWdgrRlelFmSqqGkEBGTpxSdqVphY2hvZJWpX6ENZKsZxmpa1/635krTMNS05oIqjckDKtUECRphEzTGJmiiaf0fAA)

-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!

Comment: This gives an incorrect output for odd inputs.

Comment: OK - Think I got it :) Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„X ×Â‚εI∍}I∍»
```

Can definitely be golfed a bit more..

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8CIXD0w83PWqYdW6r56OO3loQcWj3///mAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/R/i6nd4Qqi9upXO/0cN8yIUDk8/3PSoYda5rRGPOnprQcSh3f91Dm2z/w8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
„X ×           # Repeat string "X " the (implicit) input amount of times
    Â‚         # Pair it with its reverse
      εI∍}     # Shorten both strings to a length equal to the input
          I∍   # Extend this list of strings to a length equal to the input
            »  # Join the strings by newlines (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
param($n)1..$n|%{' X'*$n|% S*g($_%2)$n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqZgq1D9vyCxKDFXQyVP01BPTyWvRrVaXSFCXQvEUgjWStdQiVc10lTJq/1fy8WlBtRiyKWuDmYYwRjGMIbFfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Unexpanded Sinclair ZX-81/Timex TS-1000/1500 and compatibles, ~96 Tokenized BASIC bytes

```
 1 LET X$="X X X X X X X X X X X "
 2 INPUT I
 3 FOR X=SGN PI TO I
 4 PRINT X$( TO I)
 5 LET X$=X$(VAL "2" TO )+X$(SGN PI)
 6 NEXT X
```

There are some limitations here; as the Sinclair ZX-81 by default only allows 32 character per line, and only 22 lines per screen by default, I have limited the maximum "chess board" to that, 22 x 22.

`I` is used here as a user input variable to determine the required "size" of the chess board. Once entered into the loop, the `X$` string is essentially shifted to the right by one character in line 5.

Enjoy typing!

[image: ZX81 Chess Board Generator Simulator]

Answer (score 1):

## C64/128 and C64Mini (and compatibles), 68 tonekized BASIC bytes

```
 0fOi=0to11:a$=a$+"V ":nE:inputi:fOx=1toi:?leF(a$,i):a$=rI(a$,21)+leF(a$,1):nE
```

I've limited the potential size of the chess board pattern to a width of 22 because whilst the C64 might have 40 text columns, it only has 25 rows and therefore going over 22 will mean that some of the pattern is lost because when exiting a symbolic listing the C64 with typically add a carriage return, then the `ready.` prompt, and another carriage return where the cursor will reside.

To explain, here is the non-obfuscated symbolic listing:

```
 0 for i=0 to 11
 1  let a$=a$+"V "
 2 next i
 3 input i
 4 for x=1 to i
 5  print left$(a$, i)
 6  let a$=right$(a$, 21)+left$(a$, 1)
 7 next x
```

First the chess board patters is built in the `a$` variable with the shifted (or uppercase) `v` representing an X.

The user is then asked for an input of a numeric value. This will work with positive Integers with a greater value than zero, though will work also with positive floating point numbers greater or equal to one.

A `for/next` loop is set up to the Integer value of the number entered, printing out the pattern to the length of the number entered.

The `a$` variable is then shuffled one character to ensure the chess board effect in the loop.

Enjoy programming!

[image: Commodore C64 Chess Board pattern]

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 19 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x$(x;x+~2!x)#"X "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v7pCRaPCukK7zkixQlNZKUJBqdbi/38A)

**Explanation:**

Reshape the input with an odd-length so that the `X_` wraps to create the checkerboard, and then truncate to the correct width:

```
{x$(x;x+~2!x)#"X "} / the solution
{                 } / lambda taking implicit input x
              "X "  / string "X "
   ( ;      )#      / reshape to (length;width)
         2!x        / x mod 2
        ~           / not (0=>1, 1=>0)
      x+            / add to x
    x               / length is input
 x$                 / pad width to x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```scala
for(i<-1 to a;s=Seq.fill((a+1)/2)("X ").mkString)println(if(i%2==1)s else s.reverse)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcqxCsIwEIDhPU9xFIQ7xNp0qagZHB2curjG9iLRmNYmiCA@e5WA0uUfPv7QaKfH7nThJsJBWw/8jOzbALu@fwkhAFo2YFCv9z4SKBhNN6DdLiTEDvQmqJrvubHOIeq5pGVJmB0ho/x2reNg/Zn6b6PzaA3aWamUpADsAkPIB37wEJjG35MVGQmDBYm/yCRyImWSciKrJKuJVEkqEu/xAw)

Comment: Think you can drop a couple of the whitespaces for 80 chars... But doesn't look like this works for input of 1

Comment: @streetster thanks - this special case cost me 4 bytes;(

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-n -M5.10.0`, 35 bytes

```perl
eval'say substr"X "x$_,$-++,$_;'x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHvTixUqG4NKm4pEgpQkGpQiVeR0VXW1tHJd5aHcj5/9/iX35BSWZ@XvF/3bz/ur6meoYGegYA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
‛X *½h:(…Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%80%9BX%20*%C2%BDh%3A%28%E2%80%A6%E1%B9%98&inputs=8&header=&footer=)

A little long...

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell <s>89</s> 74 charaters

```
main=do n<-readLn;mapM_(putStrLn.take n).take n.cycle$map cycle["X "," X"]
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, <strike>88</strike> <strike>80</strike> 78

```
for($x=0;$x++<$i=$argv[1];){for($y=0;$y++<$i;)echo($y+$x)%2?" ":"X";echo"\n";}
```

Comment: There is no opening `<?php` tag, would this still work?

Comment: I'm assuming you are running it through the PHP interpreter, not as part of a web-page.

Comment: Thanks, an explanation would be nice to add (i.e., how to run this)

Answer (score 0):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 17 bytes

```
|
&"X "Tn/2,Z[1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/v4ZLTSlCQSkkT99IJyra0Cr2/39zAA)

### Explanation

```
|
                     Separate terms on newline
 &                   Given input n, output first n terms in sequence
                     Odd terms equal
  "X "                               "X "
      *              implicit             repeated                  times
      T                                            ceiling of 
       n/2                                                    n / 2         
          ,          Even terms equal
           Z                          previous term
            [1:]                                    with the first character removed (Python slice notation)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Ｅθ⭆θ§X ⁺ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM3sUCjUEchuATIS4dyHEs881JSKzSUIhSUdBQyFbQVcjSBwPr//2hDg9j/umWJOQA) Link is to verbose version of code.

#### Explanation

```
Ｅθ           Map over first input (predefined variable). Since it's a number, maps over 0 to input (excluding upper bound) instead
   ⭆θ        String map over first input
      §  ⁺ιλ  At (cyclic) index i + l (current loop variable for inner and outer loop respectively)
       X      The string "X ". Note there is a space after the "X"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Oracle SQL, 84 bytes

```
SQL> select rpad(substr(rpad('_',n,'x_'),mod(level,2)+1),n,'_')from t connect by level<=n
  2  /

RPAD(SUBSTR(RPAD('_',N,'X_'),MOD(LEVEL,2)+1),N,'_')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x_x_x_x_x_
_x_x_x_x_x
x_x_x_x_x_
_x_x_x_x_x
x_x_x_x_x_
_x_x_x_x_x
x_x_x_x_x_
_x_x_x_x_x
x_x_x_x_x_
_x_x_x_x_x

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

## MUMPS (<s>58</s> <s>56</s> <s>88</s> <s>86</s> 88 bytes)

Assuming you can execute this code in an interpreter:

### (ANSI M)

```
  r v,! f i=1:1:v d  w !
  . f j=1:1:v w $s(i#2:$s(j#2=1:"X",1:" "),1:$s(j#2:" ",1:"X"))
```

We could bring this down to 82 bytes if we allow a new line at the beginning of the output:

```
 r v,! f i=1:1:v w ! f j=1:1:v w $s(i#2:$s(j#2=1:"X",1:" "),1:$s(j#2=1:" ",1:"X"))
```

#### Bonus

We can take advantage of the fact that M doesn't have any reserved keywords to give further headache:

```
s s=8 f f=1:1:s w ! f w=1:1:s w $s(f#2:$s(w#2=1:"X",1:" "),1:$s(w#2=1:" ",1:"X"))
```

### Caché ObjectScript (a superset of ANSI M) (83 bytes):

```
r v,! f i=1:1:v{f j=1:1:v{w $s(i#2:$s(j#2=1:"X",1:" "),1:$s(j#2=1:" ",1:"X"))} w !}
```

Explanation:

both cases are essentially the same. Accept input "v" from user. While looping from 1 to v, execute an inner loop such that if i#2 isn't zero, write "X" if j#2 isn't zero and " " in all other cases (i.e. when j#2 is zero). if i#2 is zero, do the opposite. After completing the inner loop, start a new line.

*dang, realized I forgot to alternate lines*
*added another version of ANSI M and an ObjectScript version

Comment: How would I run this, for example on this site: https://tio.run/#mumps

Comment: I can't figure out how to give user input in that site you mention, but if you want, you can set the size at the beginning: ` s v=8 f i=1:1:v w ! f j=1:1:v w $s(i#2:$s(j#2=1:"X",1:" "),1:$s(j#2=1:" ",1:"X"))`

Though the ObjectScript version doesn't work on tio.run (proprietary to Intersystems)

Comment: Input is given as Stdin in the input box, or passed as an argument. How is your program currently taking input?

Comment: In an interactive M session, Stdin is set to be the user's terminal.

Something might be wrong with the setup for tio.run. w $ZIO is the translated I/O device and that throws an error. If I try to explicitly say to use Stdin via u 0 or u $Principal, I also get an error.

Comment: output of $ZIO: *** Z function or variable not found in or near line 1
Global arrays closed.

Termination message: 100 Software Error

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
òeφ→α♪
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9565ed1ae00d&i=1%0A8&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
cK      map over the cartesian square of [1..n] * [1..n]
        implicitly output from each row on separate lines
  +     add the coordinates
  .X @  index into string "X "
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=cK++++%09map+over+the+cartesian+square+of+[1..n]+*+[1..n]%0A++++++%09implicitly+output+from+each+row+on+separate+lines%0A++%2B+++%09add+the+coordinates%0A++.X+%40%09index+into+string+%22X+%22&i=1%0A8&m=2)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
⁾X ẋs2UÐeẋ³ŒHḢƊ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R474IhYe7uouNQg9PSAUyDm0@Osnj4Y5Fx7oeNa2J/P//vykA)

This almost certainly can be golfed further; 17 bytes seems like too many.

**Explanation:**

```
⁾X ẋs2UÐeẋ³ŒHḢƊ€Y    Example input: 3
⁾X ẋ                 Repeat the string "X " times the input: "X X X "
    s2               Split it into chunks of length 2: ["X ", "X ", "X "]
      UÐe            Upend (reverse) the even indexes: ["X ", " X", "X "]
              Ɗ€     Apply to each...
         ẋ³          ...repeat each chunk times the input...:  ["X X X ", " X X X", "X X X "]
           ŒH        ...approximately split it into halves...: [["X X", " X "], [" X ", "X X"], ["X X", " X "]]
             Ḣ       ...take the head (first item) of each: ["X X", " X ", "X X"]
              Y      Join with newlines
                     Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 25 bytes

```
Y"X "XaFi,aP(i%2?RVyy)@<a
```

A simple for loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/UilCQSki0S1TJzFAI1PVyD4orLJS08Em8f///@aWAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
+þị⁾ XY
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/78L6Hu7sfNe5TiIj8//@/BQA) or [see the results](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/78L6Hu7sfNe5TiIj8b3G4/VHTmiwg79C2Q9v@AwA) for \$n = 1, 2, ..., 8\$

### How it works

```
+þị⁾ XY - Main link. Takes n on the left from the command line
 þ      - Yield an n×n matrix where each cell (i,j) is, for 0 ≤ i, j ≤ n:
+       -   i + j
   ⁾ X  - Yield " X"
  ị     - Index modularly into " X". Even numbers are replaced with "X" and odd with " "
      Y - Join by newlines and output
```

Comment: @Bubbler Edited that in

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), <s>60</s> 51 bytes

```
ns1[p'Xf' f,,0G]ppl2%>l[<&s[pp0]p(10)&o&lr0Irpr>,]>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@v2DC6QD0iTV0hTUfHwD22oCDHSNUuJ9pGrTi6oMAgtkDD0EBTLV8tp8jAs6igyE4n1u7/f0NDAA)

I thought this would be shorter, but guess I had higher expectations for the approach than was warranted. :)

The high level idea here is to build a `X X X ...` string on a stack, then iterate as many times as requested.  Each time time through the loop, the code prints the stack then reverses it.

````
ns1[p'Xf' f,,0G]ppl2%>l[<&s[pp0]p(10)&o&lr0Irpr>,]>

>> First loop, constructs the "X X X ..." pattern on a stack <<
ns1[p'Xf' f,,0G]
ns1                             # Read board size (N), save and push 1 on stack
   [p      ,,0G]                # Loop, decrement N by 2 each time
     'Xf' f                     # Push "X", pull N forward, push " ", pull N

>> Clean-up and prep for second loop <<
>>              ppl2%>
.. pp                           # Delete N and iterator from stack
..   l2%                        # Load N, push "N%2" on stack (N even/odd bool)
        >                       # Switch to "X X ..." stack

>> Second loop, print the pattern and update <<
>> >>                 l[<&s[pp0]p(10)&o&lr0Irpr>,]
.. l[<              >,]         # Loop, decrements N on stack each time
      &s                        # Save "X X ..." stack in the backup cell
        [p 0]p                  # If-then, true if top of stack is not 0
          p                     # Delete one char (means N is even)
              (10)&o            # Push a LF, print the whole stack
                    &l          # Load the "X X ..." stack from the backup cell
                      r         # Reverse the stack
                       0I       # Push copy of entry 0 (even/odd bool)
                         rpr    # Reverse, pop, reverse (pop entry 0)

>> Final clean-up <<
>> >> >>                                          >
.. >                # Switch stacks to avoid auto print
```
````