# Factorize it! ...badly

Tags: code-golf, number, primes

A curious kid uses a program which can factorize a number or an expression into the following form: `p1^e1 * p2^e2 * ... * pn^en` . Exponents equal to `1` are omitted e.g. `360 = 2^3 * 3^2 * 5`

The kid types this output into the program as new input but they don't understand the `^` sign so sometimes they skip one or more of those concatenating the corresponding prime-base and exponent. E.g. `(360 =) 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 => 2^3 * 32 * 5 (= 1280)`

Because of these mistakes she might get a different factorization which they can input again (with skipping 0 or more `^`'s). They repeat the process until the factorization doesn't change anymore (maybe there are no more `^`'s or they copied the output correctly).

You should write a program or function which given an integer `n` (`n>1`) outputs all the possible numbers in increasing order whose factorization could be the one the kid ended up with (including `n`). E.g. for input `16` the possible final factorizations are `(16 =) 2^4, (24 =) 2^3 * 3, (23*3 =) 3 * 23`

### Input details:

- input is a single integer bigger than `1`
- no input will be given which generates output number greater than `2^31-1`
- no input will be given which generates more than `1000` output numbers

### Output details:

- a list of integers in a convenient form for your language

### Examples:

Input => Output

```
11    => 11
16    => 16 24 69
360   => 140 360 770 1035 1219 1280 2875 3680
605   => 560 605 840 2415
2048  => 211 2048
58564 => 230 456 1311 2508 9975 12768 13794 20748 58564 114114 322102
```

This is code-golf so shortest program wins.

Comment: Don't we already have Factorize It ?

Comment: @Optimizer This is quite different.

Comment: The last number for 360 should be 3**6**80: 2^3*3^2*5 => 23*32*5 = 3680

Comment: @blutorange Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## CJam - 66

```
ria{_{:XmF{1=1>},La\{a1$\f++}/La-{XI{~#}%:*/I{si}%:**}fI}%|}1e3*$p
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

**Explanation:**

```
ria                       read token, convert to integer and wrap in array
{…}1e3*                   repeat 1000 times
    _                     duplicate array
    {…}%                  transform each array item (number) using the block
        :X                store the number in X
        mF                factorize with exponents
        {1=1>},           keep only the factors with exponent > 1
        La\{a1$\f++}/     get all the subsets (*)
        La-               remove the empty subset
        {…}fI             for I = each subset of prime factors with exponent > 1
            XI{~#}%:*/    divide X by all the factors in I
            I{si}%:**     multiply with the primes from I
                          concatenated with their exponents
    |                     add the new numbers to the array, removing duplicates
$                         sort
p                         print the final array
```

(*) [Thanks Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/42325/7416)

Comment: cjam code from the cjam god

Comment: Any amount of `^`'s could be removed in one step. So for `58564 = 2^2 * 11^4` it should be able to generate `2508 = 22 * 114`.

Comment: @randomra you should add an example for this kind of thing

Comment: @randomra should be better now

Comment: Great! Added the example. Sorry for skipping it.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 219

To get this started:

```
s=->(x){A=[];def k(x)A<<x
y=Prime.prime_division x;n=0..y.size-1
n.each{|i|n.to_a.combination(i+1).each{|c|c.each{|z|v=y.dup
v[z][1]>1?v[z]=[v[z].join.to_i,1]:next
k v.inject(1){|s,b|s*b[0]**b[1]}}}}end;k x;A.uniq.sort}
```

Creates a function s returning an Array of numbers.

https://ideone.com/iOMGny

Use it like this:

```
#usage

#load from the standard library
require"prime"

#read from stdin and print to stdout
p s.call $<.read.to_i
```

So much fun writing this all of this on a mobile phone...

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 193 bytes

```pl
sub R{my($k,$v,@z)=@_;map{$k**$v*$_,$v>1?($k.$v)*$_:()}@z?R(@z):1}
@q=(0+<>);
while($x=pop@q){
my%f;@r=sort{$a<=>$b}@r,$x;
for(2..$x){$x/=$_,$f{$_}++while$x%$_<1}
$_~~@r||push@q,$_ for R%f
}
print"@r"
```

Newlines are just added for readability.

The for loop factorises the next number (`$x`) into a hash (`%f`) of primes and powers. The recursive function (`R`) uses this hash to generate all the numbers that could be attained by removing `^` signs. These numbers are added to a queue (`@q`), and the process is repeated by the outer while loop. Each number from the queue is also kept in a unique, sorted array (`@r`) for printing.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, <s>46</s> <s>45</s> 44

```
Su{smmu*/N^T/PdTv+`T`/PdTkdyft/PdT{PdGU^T3]Q
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Fixed the multiple `^` bug. For instance:

```
Input:  58564
Output: [230, 456, 1311, 2508, 9975, 12768, 13794, 20748, 58564, 114114, 322102]
```

Note that this code relies on a couple of bugfixes to the official compiler that were pushed after the question was asked. However, it does not use any new language features.

Comment: What do you get for 58564?

Comment: [230, 456, 1311, 58564, 322102], which is wrong.

Comment: @aditsu Fixed the issue.

Comment: As Pyth isn't rigorously documented (based on my findings) it is difficult to distinguish between bug fixes and new features so I decided not to choose this entry as the winning answer.

Comment: @randomra I understand your decision not to accept this answer. However, I'd just like to mention what the bugfix was: Using a reduce (`u`) inside another reduce was impossible. I changed a 2 to a 3 in the appropriate location so that reduce would take 3 inputs instead of 2. That's all.