# Largest and smallest values from concatenated integers

Tags: code-golf, number

This problem is from [Five programming problems every Software Engineer should be able to solve in less than 1 hour](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour) which itself is an interesting read.  The first few problems are trivial, but the fourth one can be a bit more interesting.

> Given a list of integers separated by a single space on standard input, print out the largest and smallest values that can be obtained by concatenating the integers together on their own line.

For example:

Input:

```
5 56 50
```

Output:

```
50556
56550
```

Various points of order:

- The order of the results are smallest then largest.
- *Only* the smallest and largest values may be printed out (iterating over all the variations and printing them out isn't valid).
- There will always be two or more integers in the list.
- It is possible for the largest and smallest results to be the same.  In the case of input `5 55`, the number `555` should be printed twice.
- The integers are not necessarily distinct. `5 5` is valid input.
- Leading `0`s on integers are ***not*** valid input.  You will ***not*** need to account for `05 55`.

As this is code golf, shortest entry wins.

Comment: If one of the input numbers contain a leading 0 (like `05`), do we consider it as `05` or simply `5` ?

Comment: @Optimizer leading zeros are not valid input.

Comment: Are leading 0s allowed in output?

Comment: @Tim Where would those come from if there are no leading zeroes in the input?

Comment: @MartinBüttner oh yes, being silly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## CJam, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
qS/e!:s$(N@W=
```

Pretty straight forward. This is how it works:

```
qS/                  e# Split the input on spaces
   e!                e# Get all permutations of the input numbers
     :s              e# Join each permutation order into a single string
       $             e# Sort them. This sorts the strings based on each digit's value
        (N@W=        e# Choose the first and the last out of the array separated by '\n'
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qS%2Fe!%3As%24(N%40W%3D&input=5%2056%2050)

Comment: OK, I give up. I didn't now `e!` existed (doesn't even appear in the wiki yet).

Comment: @Dennis [there](http://cjam-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/0.6.5.html) you go

Comment: Sweet read. Lots of useful new stuff.

Comment: It might be useful to update [Tips for golfing in CJam](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/39731/tips-for-golfing-in-cjam) with these additional tricks.

Comment: @MichaelT tips generally are not supposed to contain answer which explain the in built features of a language. A couple of answer might need updating as they might benefit from these new features though.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <strike>14</strike> 13 bytes

```
hJSmsd.pcz)eJ
```

Generates all permutations and sorts them, printing the first and last element.

Comment: Assign `J` inline: `hJSmsd.pcz)eJ`

Comment: @isaacg Good one! I just knew we wouldn't be inferior to that filthy filthy CJam!

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>104</s> 99 bytes

Yep.

```
from itertools import*;z=[''.join(x)for x in permutations(raw_input().split())];print min(z),max(z)
```

Edit: thanks to xnor for -5 bytes!

Comment: The comprehension inside `sorted` works without brackets, but you also can avoid sorting and just take `min` and `max`.

Comment: hah, yes. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, <s>64</s> 58 bytes

```
Print/@Sort[""<>#&/@Permutations@StringSplit@#][[{1,-1}]]&
```

This defines an unnamed function taking a string and printing the two lines. It's pretty straightforward as the others: get all permutations, join them together, sort them and print the first and last result.

Six bytes saved thanks to alephalpha.

Comment: `{#&@@#,Last@#}`=>`#[[{1,-1}]]`

Comment: @alephalpha Sometimes simpler is better. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) <s>54 72</s> 85

<s>That's easier than it seems. Just sort them lexicographically. The good news is: that's exactly how plain javascript sort works.</s>Well ... no, that's wrong ... still a (more convoluted) lexicograph compare can do the job.

Note: having a and b numeric, a+[b] is a shortcut for a+''+b, as we need a string concatenation and not a sum.
Note 2: the newline inside `` is significant and must be counted

**Edit** Don't argue with a moderator (...just kidding)

**Edit2** Fixed I/O format using popups (see [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2459/21348))

```js
// Complete program with I/O
// The sorting function is shorter as input are strings

alert((l=prompt().split(' ')).sort((a,b)=>a+b>b+a).join('')+`
`+l.reverse().join(''))

// Testable function (67 chars)
// With an integer array parameter, the sorting function must convert to string 

F=l=>(l.sort((a,b)=>a+[b]>b+[a]).join('')+`
`+l.reverse().join(''))
```

**Test** In Firefox / FireBug console

```
F([50, 2, 1, 9])
F([5,56,50])
F([52,36,526])
F([52,36,525])
F([52,36,524]
```

> 12509
>   95021
>
> 50556
>   56550
>
> 3652526
>   5265236
>
> 3652525
>   5255236
>
> 3652452
>   5252436

Comment: I think your input format is wrong. Should be "integers separated by a single space on standard input".

Comment: @nimi you're right.Fixed

Answer (score 2):

### J, 34 <sup><s>36</s>, <s>42</s></sup> bytes

simple brute force:

```
h=:3 :'0 _1{/:~;"1":&.>y A.~i.!#y'

h 5 50 56
50556 
56550

h 50 2 1 9
12509
95021
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 98 bytes

```
import Data.List
g=sort.map concat.permutations.words
h i=unlines[g i!!0,last$g i]
main=interact h
```

Split input string at spaces, concatenate every permutation and sort. Print first and last element.

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 77 bytes

```rb
v->(Q=extrema([int(join(x)) for x in permutations(v)]);print(Q[1],"\n",Q[2]))
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts a vector as input and prints the minimum and maximum of the permutations of the joined elements. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=v->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```rb
function f(v)
    # Create an integer vector of the joined permutations using comprehension,
    # then get the minimum and maximum as a tuple using extrema().

    Q = extrema([int(join(x)) for x in permutations(v)])

    # Print the minimum and the maximum, separated by a newline.
    print(Q[1], "\n", Q[2])
end
```

Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (*ES6*) 134

Sadly, there's no built-in permutation function in JS :(

```js
f=(o,y,i,a)=>y?o.concat(a[1]?a.filter((k,j)=>j^i).reduce(f,[]).map(z=>y+z):y):(q=o.split(' ').reduce(f,[])).sort().shift()+`
`+q.pop()
```

```html
<!-- Snippet Demo (Firefox only) -->

<input id="input" value="5 56 50" />
<input type="button" onclick="output.innerHTML=f(input.value)" value="Run" />
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

### R, 59 bytes

```r
write(range(combinat:::permn(scan(),paste,collapse="")),"")
```

Comment: Nice work. You can save a byte by using just two colons though, i.e. `combinat::permn`.

Comment: I thought `::` required the package to be loaded (via `library` or `require`) but not `:::`. I could be wrong; need to read a little more about it. Thanks.

Comment: If the library is loaded, you don't need the colons at all; you can just call the function directly since the package is attached to the namespace. If the package is installed but not loaded, you can reference functions in a particular package with two colons.

Comment: So 58 it can be. I would not allow myself using `permn` directly without a `library(combinat)`.

Comment: Yeah, because you have to load the library with `library(combinat)` before you could use `permn` anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 75

Not my 'native' language, but one I thought I'd give a try at... thus this could (possibly) use some golfing tips. Still, not a bad entrant.

```ruby
puts STDIN.read.split(" ").permutation.map{|x|x.join}.sort.values_at(0,-1)
```

I wouldn't say it is *elegant* other that everything is built in to the language.  It should be fairly obvious exactly how this works.

Comment: You can replace `{|x|x.join}` with `(&:join)` for a 3 byte savings.

Comment: A few more ruby shortcuts for 48 bytes: `puts$<.read.split.permutation.map(&:join).minmax`

Comment: [If pattern is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is the default), str is split on whitespace as if ` ‘ were specified.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split)

Comment: gets is even shorter for reading input: `puts gets.split.permutation.map(&:join).minmax`

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>79</s> 70B (68+2)

`use Math::Combinatorics;say for(sort map{join'',@$_}permute@F)[0,-1]`

Call with `echo 13 42 532 3 6|perl -M5.10.0 -an scratch.pl`. There's a +2 byte penalty for `-an`. Shame about the length of the module name...

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
#œJ{¬sθ»
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@ehkr@pDa4rP7Ti0@/9/UwVTMwVTAwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
#         # Split the (implicit) input by spaces
 œ        # Get all permutations of this list
  J       # Join each permutation together to a single string
   {      # Sort this list
    ¬     # Push the first item (without popping the list)
     s    # Swap to get the list again
      θ   # Pop and push its last item
       »  # And join all (both) values on the stack by newlines
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 90 bytes

```scala
val x=Console.in.readLine.split(" ").permutations.map(_.mkString).toSeq
print(x.min,x.max)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYrLCsIwEADvfsXSUwqy4NsePEiv3voBsjZrieZls0pA/PYYBgYGJo1kqYTbg0eBPmiegr0DZ2GvE5xjhG/5kIV86oNPwTIajzOTvhjPmKI1ohpoWow8u7eQmLqho6iu6J6DzMZPLUoY@LWINURldMYvqym35Vc6WG@2sIIdHI6wr3R/)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 85 bytes

```
F=a=>(c=a.split(" ").sort((b,a)=>b+a-(a+b)),`${c.join("")}
${c.reverse().join("")}`)
```

**usage:**

```
F("50 2 1 9")
/*
    12509
    95021
*/
```

Comment: Don't fall in love with template strings. a+\` \`+b is shorter than \`${a} ${b}\`

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ú∙n90≤╣*.vâ
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=L%7CT%7B%24mc%7CmP%7CMp&i=5+56+50)

Link is to unpacked version of code.

### Explanation

```
L|T{$mc|MP|mp implicit input
L             put all inputs in a list
 |T           get the unique orders of the list of inputs
   {$m        convert each list to string
      c       duplicate the array of strings
       |mP    print the minimum element
          |mp print the maximum element
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Œ!VṢ.ị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWwhzsX6T3c3f3/cPujpjX//0eb6iiYmgGxQawOAA)

Input and output as lists of integers. [+3 bytes](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4biyxZIhVlbhuaIu4buLWf/Dh@KCrP//IjUgNTYgNTAiLA) to input with spaces and output with newlines

### How it works

```
Œ!VṢ.ị - Main link. Takes a list L on the left e.g. [5, 56, 50]
Œ!     - All permutations of L                      [[5, 56, 50], [5, 50, 56], [56, 5, 50], [56, 50, 5], [50, 5, 56], [50, 56, 5]]
  V    - Concatenate each into numbers              [55650, 55056, 56550, 56505, 50556, 50565]
   Ṣ   - Sort                                       [50556, 50565, 55056, 55650, 56505, 56550]
    .ị - Take the first and last elements           [56550, 50556]
```