# I am greater than you!

Tags: code-golf, math, number, array

Write a function or program that given a **list** of **non negative** integers, arranges them such that they form the largest possible number.

**INPUT**

```
[50, 2, 1, 9]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
95021
```

---

**INPUT**

```
0
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0
```

---

**INPUT**
(Interesting one)

```
[7, 76]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
776
```

**RULES**

- [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) apply.
- Depending on your language you can use `int(32)` / `int(64)` or any other numeric datatype. *(Please append the chosen type to your answer)*
- take a **list** as Input
- you choose the behavior on empty input

**GL**

Comment: Can we return a list rather than a number? `[9,50,2,1]` for instance?

Comment: No, a "plain" number has to be returned., like in the example.

Comment: Is there any reason why it must be a plain number and not a list?

Comment: Because in my understanding a list can't be read as a number.
Concatenating is also the task.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/49854/34531)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
œJà
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6GSvwwv@/48211EwN4sFAA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>85</s> <s>80</s> <s>77</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```python
lambda l:''.join(sorted(map(str,l),key=lambda i:i+i[-1]*max(l))[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHSl1dLys/M0@jOL@oJDVFIzexQKO4pEgnR1MnO7XSFqos0ypTOzNa1zBWKzexQiNHUzPaygrI0/xfUJSZV6KQphFtaqBjpGOpAxTjgouZ65ibAdUAAA)

Sorts the numbers lexicographically, but each number is padded with its last  digit.

This means that 'shorter' numbers (string-wise) can be larger than 'longer' numbers:

Example:

Input: `[76, 7]`

Each number gets padded with its last digit: `['76666..','7777..']`

Sorted (descending): `['7777..',76666..']`, which gives `[7, 76]`

Joining the result gives: `776`

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
Œ!VṀ
```

### Explanation

```
       Input: list [1, 4, 5, 21, 4]
Œ!     Generate all permutations of input list
  V    Eval those lists as Jelly code: every sublist is joined and interpreted as int
   Ṁ   Pick the highest
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWwhzsb/v//H21qoKNgpKNgqKNgGQsA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
pᶠcᵐ⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@DhtgXJD7dOeNTT@f9/tKmBjpGOoY5l7P8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
pᶠ       Find all permutations of the list
  cᵐ     Concatenate each permutation into an integer
    ⌉    Take the biggest one
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>``+b+a-(``+a+b)).join``
```

Sorts the numbers by their ordering when concatenated, and joins the result.

Comment: I like those ugly concatenations, it works in Squeak Smalltalk too `[:x|(x sort:[:a :b|'',a,b>('',b,a)])join+0]`the final +0 is for answering an Integer and avoiding quotes

Answer (score 4):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
ψJì↑
```

**Explanation:**

```
ψ      All possible permutations
 J     join sublists
  ì    convert to int
   ↑   get maximum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//3yH1@E1j9om/v8fbWqgo2Cko2Coo2AZ@x8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
ñ!îL w q
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8SHuTCB3IHE=&input=WzUwLCAyLCAxLCA5LCA3LCA3NiwgNzcsIDc4XQ==)

Look ma, no permutation built-in!

#### Explanation

```
ñ           Sort the input as if each item
 !îL          were repeated to 100 chars. (!îL -> LîX for each item X, L = 100)
     w      Reverse.
       q    Join into a single string.
            Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Repeating each item to length 100 works because while `'7' < '76'`, `'7777...' > '7676...'`, and no number could possibly be length 100 when converted to a string.

Comment: Fails for `7, 78`; output should be `787` but this returns `778`.

Comment: @Neil Whoops, thanks. Fixed at +0 bytes.

Comment: Now fails for `7, 776`; output should be `7776` but this returns `7767`.

Comment: '78' is before '7', '76' after '7' and, '7' and '77' can be in any order , more generally when a number start with sequence of another wrapped the digit which comes after must be compared to the next number in shorter: for example '7625' comes before '762575' but '76257625762' before '7625'

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul thanks, fixed at +0 bytes. I promise it's finally fixed this time, for real...

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 11 bytes

```
;l@╨⌠εj≈⌡MM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/986x@HR1BWPehac25r1qLPjUc9CX9///6NNDXQUjHQUDHUULGMB)

Explanation:

```
;l@╨⌠εj≈⌡MM
;l@╨         all permutations of input
    ⌠εj≈⌡M   concatenate each permutation
          M  maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>113</s> <s>220</s> 87 bytes

```java
l->l.stream().map(i->""+i).sorted((i,j)->(j+i).compareTo(i+j)).reduce((i,j)->i+j).get()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNS8NAEIbv@RVDT7u2WVTwIK2BXhTBW3sR8TAma524X@xOKkX62@NGo1TyHp95B56ZFvdY@qBd27z3ZIOPDG1mqmMy6mxZTNhr52om74ZhUdQGU4I1fBaQkxiZargdK6sHSry6d6x3OlYL2HAkt6uA1vYuamQdt2/oHn0HN9CbsjIqceZWSGUxCCqr2WxOUqVsoBshaNHKshLtwGpvA0a99YLmrZQq6qar9W9nYGqnWcg@Ww5qoXsxWW003HtqwCI58eP09AwoxyOG/BMHk/2c/oB1jHj4HlVCLv/KRmHTiKvzCbqckIsJuT4hm0NibZXvWIVsxWLyKIUhmIMwctw6Fsf@Cw)

Comment: what about `l->l.stream().sorted((i,j)->(j+""+i).compareTo(i+""+j)).forEach(i->System.out.print(i))`

Comment: should be a function rather than a consumer `l->l.stream().map(i->""+i).sorted((i,j)->(j+i).compareTo(i+j)).reduce((i,j)->i+j).get()`

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
eSmsjkd.p
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=eSmsjkd.p&input=%5B50%2C+2%2C+1%2C+9%5D&debug=0)**

**or:**

```
eSsMjLk.p
jkeojkN.p
```

---

- `.p` - Generate all the permutations.
- `msjkd` - Map on the above with the following function that takes `d` as a variable:

  - `jkd` - Concatenate the integers into a single string.
  - `s` - Convert to integer.
- `S` - Sort the input.
- `e` - Get the last element.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB, 65 bytes

```matlab
@(x)max(cellfun(@(s)str2num(s(s>32)),cellstr(num2str(perms(x)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzN7FCIzk1JyetNE/DQaNYs7ikyCivNFejWKPYzthIU1MHJAkU1AAKGoHogtSi3GKgRhD4n6YRbWqgYKRgqGAZq8kF5BlAKHMFc7NYzf8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>13</s> 7 bytes

```
á m¬ñ Ì
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4SBtrPEgzA==&input=WzcsNzZd)

-6 thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions).

Comment: Don't think you'll need the `ms` if you change `®r+}` to `m¬`

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh so there is such a builtin :p

Comment: A built-in to join an array on the empty string? Of course :P

Comment: @ETHproductions yeah I was referring to `q` I thought it surprisingly didn't exist but japt isn't that insane so as not to include it :p

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 18 bytes

**Solution:**

```
,/x@>(|/#:'x)#'x:$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0e/wsFOo0Zf2Uq9QlNZvcJKxdRAwUjBUMHy/38A)

**Examples:**

```
> ,/x@>(|/#:'x)#'x:$50 2 1 9
"95021"
> ,/x@>(|/#:'x)#'x:$7 76
"776"
```

**Explanation:**

```
,/x@>(|/#:'x)#'x:$ / the solution
                 $ / convert to string, 50 2 1 9 -> "50","2","1","9"
               x:  / store in x
     (      )      / do this together
        #:'x       / count (#:) each (') x, "50","2","1","9" -> 2 1 1 1
      |/           / max over, 2 1 1 1 -> 2,
             #'    / take each parallel, 2#'"50","2","1","9" -> "50","22","11","99"
    >              / return sorted indices (descending), "50","22","11","99" -> 3 0 1 2
  x@               / apply these indices to x, "50","2","1","9" -> "9","50","2","1"
,/                 / flatten, "9","50","2","1" -> "95021"
```

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 113 Bytes

It's not very short, but hey, it's still C# we're talking about.

```cs
int F(List<int>n)=>n.Max(i=>{var l=new List<int>(n);l.Remove(i);return int.Parse(""+i+(l.Count>0?""+F(l):""));});
```

Formatted:

```cs
int F (List<int>n) => n.Max (i =>
{
    var l = new List<int> (n);
    l.Remove (i);
    return int.Parse ("" + i + (l.Count > 0 ? "" + F (l) : ""));
});
```

It simply recursively tries all possible permutations of the input and returns the largest one.

It uses a 32 Bit integer as input and output numerical datatype.

If anybody has an idea on how to improve this solution, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>48</s> <s>41</s> 36 bytes

Similar implementation to others, generates all permutations and takes the max. Shame that "permutation" needs to be spelled out in full . . .

```
f=->l{l.permutation.map(&:join).max}
```

Calling it:

```
f.call([50, 2, 1, 9])
 => "95021"

f.call([7, 76])
 => "776"
```

Or

```
f.([50, 2, 1, 9])
 => "95021"
```

Comment: I have assumed that the output has to be an integer in the given language - I can drop the `.to_i` at the end and save 5 bytes if this is not the case. However OP has stated output should be a "plain number"

Comment: you can also output it as a String, which s generally readable like an int

Comment: You can also use the `f.([50, 2, 1, 9])` syntax to call lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
f$¦⌉
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P03l0LJHPZ3/Ux@1TfwfbWqgYKRgqGAZCwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 27 bytes

```
join"",sort{"$b$a"cmp$a.$b}
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X1CUmVfyPys/M09JSac4v6ikWkklSSVRKTm3QCVRTyWp9r@lpaWOpY6hgY65jrkZkDb4DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>29</s> 25 bytes

<s>[:>./-.&' '&.":"1@(A.~i.@!@#)</s>

```
[:>./,&.":/"1@(A.~i.@!@#)
```

- <s>`-.&' '&.":"1` smashes a list of numbers together to produce a single number.  `-.` is "set minus" and `":` is format, so `":` turns, eg, the list `7 76` into the single string (aka list of chars) into `'7 76'`, and `-.&' '` removes the spaces from that string.  Since `":` was applied using Under `&.` the inverse is automatically applied at the end, turning the single string-now-without-spaces back into a number.</s>
- `,&.":/"1` smashes a list of numbers together to produce a single number.
- `(A.~i.@!@#)` all permutations of the list
- `>./` maximum of

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxga6VgoADE/6Ot7PT0ddT0lKz0lQwdNBz16jL1HBQdlDX/a3Ip6Smop9laqSvoKNRaKaQVc3GlJmfkK6QpmBooGCkYKljC@OYK5mb/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## bash, 96 bytes

```
f(){ local l g p=$1;shift&&{ for i;{ (($i$p>$p$i))&&l+=\ $i||g+=\ $i;};echo $(f $l)$p$(f $g);};}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##JcpNCoMwFATgfU4xi0dI6MYEn5ug9CDdWDE/EFCqu@jZ05TOYvgY5j0fsR7rCQtrYDswM7gHD9UrXZC3Zc7ICNhHMu6IyZ9SFvjtg@QKlKJE@0Q7Ja2lzI/xBUrXFf5wt1uXuIGUB2Xdbj8E3fa7Nj2rEcYKZsGdaNXS94KHZtN9AQ)

Comment: Doesn't work for inputs of `7` and `78`.

Comment: indeed, from ETHproductions solution (to append 'a' so that '7' > '76') doesn't work because shorter numbers always placed after number which begins with same sequence however it doesn't work for all numbers : '7' > '76', '7' > '77', '7' > '78' but (should be '7' < '76', '7' = '77' and '7' < '78')

Comment: fixed using bash builtins instead of coreutils

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>90</s> <s>86</s> 80 bytes

```python
lambda l:max("".join(map(str,x))for x in permutations(l))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcjBCsIwDADQ@74i7NRIER3ocOCX6A4VV4w0TUkj1K@vN9/xla@9JE89Xu89BX48A6SFQ3PjuH8LZcehuGrqG2IUhQaUoWzKHwtGkqtLiENUYSDb1ERSBeIiartelLJBdLfTwU/@4o8rDv@b/Xxesf8A)

*-4 bytes thanks to FlipTack*

*-6 bytes thanks to i cri everytim*

I believe this can be golfed a ton, but I don't really know how. Stupid type conversions added a ton of bytes.

Comment: IIRC you don't need any of your square brackets as `max` and `join` can take generators, which should save you four bytes

Comment: [80 bytes.](https://tio.run/##PcjBCsIwDADQ@74i7NRIER3ocOCX6A4VV4w0TUkj1K@vN9/xla@9JE89Xu89BX48A6SFQ3PjuH8LZcehuGrqG2IUhQaUoWzKHwtGkqtLiENUYSDb1ERSBeIiartelLJBdLfTwU/@4o8rDv@b/Xxesf8A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Groovy, 41 bytes

```
{it.permutations().max{it.join()}.join()}
```

---

If commands were 3 bytes in groovy instead of a full word I halve the size lol:

```
{it.p().max{it.j()}.j()}
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATLAB/[Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>65</s> 62 bytes

```matlab
@(n)max(str2num(sprintf([repmat('%d',size(n)) 10],perms(n)')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9Wmmerp6f330EjTzM3sUKjuKTIKK80V6O4oCgzryRNI7ootSA3sURDXTVFXac4syoVqE5TwdAgVqcgtSi3GMhT19TUBBmjEW1qoKNgpKNgqKNgGav5HwA)

Anonymous function which takes an array as an input, and spits out an integer representing the largest number that can be made.

Permutations are found, then the result is formatted to a 2D array where each line contains only the digits from the values in a given permutation in order. This is done by `sprintf` with enough `%d` markers to absorb the whole permutation. The result is then converted back to an array of integers where each line becomes its own value. The maximum from this array is returned.

---

- Save 3 bytes using `size(n)` instead of `1,numel(n)` in the `repmat()` call

<sup>Note: This was developed completely independently from the other Octave answer.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 57 bytes

```
Max[FromDigits[Join@@IntegerDigits/@#]&/@Permutations@#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773zexItqtKD/XJTM9s6Q42is/M8/BwTOvJDU9tQgipu@gHKum7xCQWpRbWgLUl59XDBL5H1CUmVei4JAeXW1qoGOkY6hjWRvLhRA01zE3q439DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, <strike>135</strike> 53 bytes

New Solution:

```
a=input('')
b=sprintf('%d', a)
c=sort(b,'descend')
```

Explanation: It takes a user matrix input, then separates it into digits, and finally orders those digits from greatest to least.

Old Solution:

```
a=input('');
b=sprintf('%d',a) - '0';
c=[];b=sort(b,'descend');
for i=1:size(b,2)
 c(i)=b(i);
end
for y=1:size(c,2)
 e(y)=num2str(c(y))
end
```

Explanation: First it takes a user input, then separates all of the numbers into individual digits. The %d in sprintf essentially converts the numbers in the string, which is necessary for sorting into each digit (afaik). I tried simply doing num2str(a) but that leaves a space between each number. From there, it is just a matter of sorting and arranging the numbers with proper formatting. The actual code has a lower byte count because it has no semi-colons and everything on one line.

Comment: I think that this might not work (based on the description your provided) because he doesn't want the individual DIGITS ordered (for example, if I'm understanding right, you would return 95210 and split up the 50 from the example, when the user requested that it return 95021).