# Me Want Honeycomb

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, tiling, hexagonal-grid

Write the shortest program that prints this ASCII art section of a [hexagonal tiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_tiling) or [honeycomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb):

```
       __
    __/  \__
 __/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/
/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/
/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/
   \__/  \__/
      \__/
```

- No input should be taken.
- Output to stdout or your language's closest alternative.
- Instead of a program, you may write a *named* function that takes no parameters and prints the result normally or returns it as a string.
- The output may have any number of leading and/or trailing newlines and each line in the output may have any number of leading and/or trailing spaces (as long as the pattern lines up properly.)
- **The shortest code in bytes wins.**

Comment: Do you play a lot of Catan?

Comment: @user3490 In fact I do ^^

Comment: Next week on PCG: write a Catan board generator?

Comment: It should have an input IMO, in your case it should be 3.

Comment: @user3819867 I did consider that but preferred this. It's too late to change but not too late for anyone to make a related challenge.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## CJam, <s>45</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```
741e8 36+Ab"\__/  "38*21/.{G2$-<\S*.e<N}
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=741e8%2036%2BAb%22%5C__%2F%20%20%2238*21%2F.%7BG2%24-%3C%5CS*.e%3CN%7D).

#### How it works

```
"\__/  "38*21/
```

repeats the pattern `\__/` **38** times and splits it into chunks of length **21**. If the chunks were separated by linefeeds, this would be the result:

```
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  
\__/  \__/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \__/  
\__/  \__/  \__/
```

This clearly contains the desired honeycomb. All that's left to do is to replace some characters with spaces, cut off some others and actually introduce the linefeeds.

```
741e8 36+Ab
```

generates the integer **74 100 000 036** and converts it into the array **[7 4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 6]**. Each array element encodes the number of leading characters of the corresponding line that have to get replaced with spaces. By subtracting this number from **16**, we also obtain the correct length for this line.

```
.{            } e# Execute for each pair of a digit D and a line L:
  G2$-<         e#   Chop off L after 16 - D characters.
       \S*      e#   Push a string of D spaces.
          .e<   e#   Compute the vectorized minimum.
             N  e#   Push a linefeed.
```

Since a space has a lower code point than the other characters of **L** and vectorized operators leave the characters of the longer string that do not correspond to one of the shorter one untouched, `.e<` replaces the first **D** characters with spaces.

Comment: This is brilliant. Nice work.

Answer (score 28):

## Python 2, 73

```python
i=0
exec"k=max(7-i,i-24,0);print' '*k+('\__/  '*9)[i:][k:16-k];i+=3;"*11
```

[See it run.](https://ideone.com/xhIDDc)

For each of the 11 output rows, computes the number of leading spaces `k` as a maximum of three linear functions that form the envelope of the left side of the hexagon. Because the diagonal lines have slope `3` and `-3`, it's better to index the row number as `i=0,3,...30`.

To create the hexagon mesh, we first tile enough of the unit `'\__/  '`. Then, shifting `[i:]` realigns it by 3 for odd rows. Finally, we take the needed portion `[k:16-k]` of it, leaving a margin of `k` on the left and right.

Answer (score 22):

## CJam, <s>65</s> <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```
"Ý6TNð*¯5"303b4b["/\_")"_ "4*S]f=sB/z{_W%"\/"_W%erN}/
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%22%C3%9D6TN%17%C3%B0*%C2%85%C2%AF5%22303b4b%5B%22%2F%5C_%22)%22_%20%224*S%5Df%3DsB%2Fz%7B_W%25%22%5C%2F%22_W%25erN%7D%2F).

#### Idea

The right half of each line is a reversed copy of the left half with slashes and backslashes swapped. Therefore, it suffices to encode the left half of the honeycomb:

```
       _
    __/ 
 __/  \_
/  \__/ 
\__/  \_
/  \__/ 
\__/  \_
/  \__/ 
\__/  \_
   \__/ 
      \_
```

Rather than analyzing this pattern line by line, we can analyze it column by column:

```
   /\/\/\  
  _ _ _ _  
  _ _ _ _  
  /\/\/\/\ 
 _ _ _ _ _ 
 _ _ _ _ _ 
 /\/\/\/\/\
_ _ _ _ _ _
```

Obvious patterns emerge:

- The string `_ _ _ _` occurs five times.
- Every `/` is followed by a `\`.

By replacing every `/\`, `_`, `_ _ _ _` and space with a number from 0 to 3, we can convert the resulting array from a base 4 number to a higher base and store the complete pattern in a compact fashion.

#### Code

```
"Ý6TNð*¯5"303b4b  e# Convert the string from base 303 to base 4.
["/\_")"_ "4*S]f= e# Replace each resulting digit by the corresponding item of the array
                  e# ["/\" "_" "_ _ _ _ " " "].
sB/               e# Split into strings of length 11.
z                 e# Zip: transpose rows with columns.
{             }/  e# For each string:
 _W%              e#     Push a reversed copy.
    "\/"_W%er     e#     Swap slashes and backslashes.
             N    e#     Push a linefeed.
```

Answer (score 10):

### C, <s>148</s> <s>144</s> 140 bytes

```
k,r,c,d,p;f(){for(;k<187;k++){r=k/17;c=k%17;d=c+r%2*3;p=3*r+c-7<33u&3*r-c+8<33u;putchar(c==16?10:p&(d+5)%6<2?95:p&d%6==3?47:!p|d%6?32:92);}}
```

With whitespace, without compiler warnings, and before some code tweaks to save a few bytes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int k, r, c, d, p;

void f() {
    for ( ; k < 187; k++) {
        r = k / 17;
        c = k % 17;
        d = c + 3 * (r % 2);
        p = 3 * r + c - 7 < 33u && 3 * r - c + 8 < 33u;
        putchar(
            c == 16 ? 10 :
            p && (d + 5) % 6 < 2 ? 95 :
            p && d % 6 == 3 ? 47 :
            p && d % 6 == 0 ? 92 :
            32);
    }
}
```

This approach does not use any character/string tables. It loops over all 187 (11 rows, 17 columns including newlines), and decides which character to print for each position, based on a combination of conditions.

The conditions include a test for being inside/outside the 4 corners, using 4 line equations, with the result stored in variable `p`. The rest is then mostly repeating every 6 characters, with the odd rows shifted by 3 characters relative to the even rows.

Comment: For the golfed one, you could use implicit-int and drop the `int `.

Comment: A few micro-improvements: `k;f(r,c,d,p){for(;k<187;putchar(c>15?10:p&d<2&p?95:p&d<3?47:!p|d-5?32:92))r=k/17,c=k++%17,d=(5+c+r%2*3)%6,p=3*r+c-7<33u&3*r-c+8<33u;}`

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby - 78 Bytes

```ruby
(-5..5).map{|i|puts' '*(j=[i.abs*3-i/6-9,0].max)+('/  \__'*4)[j+i%2*3,16-j*2]}
```

---

**A transcription of [xnor's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/50325/4098) (69 Bytes):**

```ruby
11.times{|i|puts' '*(j=[7-i*=3,i-24,0].max)+('\__/  '*9)[i+j,16-j*2]}
```

Comment: `11.times` saves 2 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 129 <s>130</s>

That's a pure string replace/replace/replace ... not taking advantage of any geometric property.

Using template strings, all newlines are significant and count.

Run snippet in Firefox to test

```js
f=_=>`70
405
 055
9992 3051
6301`[R='replace'](/9/g,`55123
30551
`)[R](/5/g,1230)[R](/\d/g,n=>['__','/',,'\\'][n]||' '.repeat(n))

// TEST

O.innerHTML = f()
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP - <s>139</s> <s>137</s> <s>107</s> <s>101</s> <s>91</s> 87 bytes

I don't know if this is the best way to  golf it but here is my try at it:

*<s>30</s> <s>36</s> <s>46</s> -50 bytes thanks to Ismael Miguel*

Test it online [here](https://ideone.com/WHWEZS)

```
<?='       __
    __',$a='/  \__',"
 __$a$a
",$c="$a$a/  \
\__$a$a/
","$c$c   \__$a/
      \__/";
```

```html
<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/WHWEZS" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

old code:

```
<?php $a="/  \\__";$c=$a.$a."/  \\\n\__".$a.$a."/\n";echo "       __\n    __".$a."\n __".$a,$a."\n".$c,$c,$c."   \\__".$a."/\n      \\__/";
```

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. Your PHP code can be reduced a lot more. You can use `<?` instead of  `<?php` to save 3 bytes. Instead of `$c=$a.$a."/  \\\n\__".$a.$a."/\n";`, you can write `$c="$a$a/  \\\n\__.$a$a/\n";` (since PHP expands variables in strings). You can apply the same logic to the `echo` to further reduce it's length. Also, you don't need that space between the `echo` and the string.

Comment: Thank you, I learn something new every time I try to golf hehe.

Comment: You are welcome. Here is a 99-byte long solution: https://ideone.com/WHWEZS. It looks a mess, but it is a lot shorter. Instead of using `\n`, you can put a *real*  newline and save 1 byte per line.

Comment: Meanwhile, I've reduced it 2 bytes. Now it has 97 bytes.

Comment: Playing around, I've reduced that file to 88 bytes. On it, one thing to look out is that I've replaced each group of 4 spaced by a tab (`\t`). This means that you slim down 3 bytes. I will paste an hex dump of the file (or similar), just to be sure that everybody has it right and that the browser doesn't replace the tabs with 4 spaces.

Comment: Here is a one-liner: `<?="\t   __\n\t__",$a='/  \__',"\n __$a$a\n",$c="$a$a/  \\\n\__$a$a/\n","$c$c   \__$a/\n\t  \__/";`. Remember to replace the `\t` with a tab character and `\n` with a real newline.

Comment: For me the `\t` is 4 spaces too long, I'm running it in the Windows Command Promt.

Comment: Tha't alright. As long as you can reproduce it. That means, if it works under a certain environment, and someone else can pick up and reproduce the same results, then it's all good. You can check the ideone link (https://ideone.com/WHWEZS) showing it working fine. It's the same code as before, but with the tabs and newlines replaced. As an alternative, you can click on the icon that looks like `<>` and paste this: `<script src="http://ideone.com/e.js/WHWEZS" type="text/javascript" ></script>`.

Answer (score 4):

## Lua 146

```
T="       __\n    __/  \\__\n __/  \\__/  \\__\n"
S="/  \\__/  \\__/  \\\n\\__/  \\__/  \\__/\n"
B="   \\__/  \\__/\n      \\__/"
io.write(T,S,S,S,B)
```

(newlines added for clarity)

Comment: Isn't this code _longer_ than the desired output because it just contains the output plus escaping and string handling stuff?

Comment: @Caleb: I suspect you've not actually counted & just guessed in making that comment. According to my text editor, there are 165 characters in the lattice (newlines included). I have 19 less characters due to repeating `S` three times.

Comment: But you are correct that the escapes and newlines do limit my code's ability to compete in this particular game. But winning also isn't why I do this, it's for the fun & learning.

Answer (score 3):

### Dart - 113

```dart
main({r:"/  \\__"}){print("       __\n    __$r\n __$r$r\n${"$r$r/  \\\n\\__$r$r/\n"*3}   \\__$r/\n      \\__/");}
```

Pure string-interpolation solution, nothing fancy.
String operations like "substring" are too verbose to compete in practice.

Run it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/1c9f6d612fea37d8481f).

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>100</s> 87 bytes

```py
n=0x85208e08e08dd445
while n:l=n>>2&15;print(' '*(8-l)+('\__/  '*4)[n&3:n&3|l*2]);n>>=6
```

And a readable version of the code below.
The idea is to hardcode the intervals (begin, length) and then pad with the correct amount of spaces to center the interval.

```py
hexagon_string = '\__/  ' * 4
for i in range(11):
    # Pick the begin and length of the i-th interval using hardcoded numbers
    b = (0x00030303111 >> 4*i) & 3   # n is a combination of these two numbers
    l = (0x25888888741 >> 4*i) & 15  #
    # Print the interval with appropriate whitespace in front of it
    spaces = ' ' * (8-l)
    print(spaces + hexagon_string[b : b+l*2])
```

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (*ES7 Draft*), <strike>96</strike> <strike>94</strike> 93 bytes

Inspiration taken from a few solutions here...

*Edit: -1 from edc65*

```js
f=z=>[for(x of[741e6]+36)' '.repeat(x)+'/  \\__'.repeat(4,z^=3).slice(+x+z,16-x+z)].join(`
`)

// For snippet demo:
document.write('<pre>'+f()+'</pre>');
```

**Commented:**

```js
f=z=>[                                 
        for(x of [741e6] + 36)        // for each character "x" in "74100000036"
            ' '.repeat(x) +           // x spaces
            '/  \\__'.repeat(4,       // build pattern string
            z ^= 3).                  // toggle z offset (3) for even lines
            slice(+x + z, 16 - x + z) // get appropriate substring
    ].join(`                          // join with newlines
    `)
```

Comment: Nice one. `.substr(+x+z,16-x-x)` -> `.slice(+x+z,16-x+z)` -1

Comment: @edc65 nice catch!

Comment: Quick question: Why is it `+x` instead of just `x`?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes It's to cast `x` to a number. Without it, it would concatenate `z`

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 66 bytes

```
<empty line>
sss __<LF>ssa__<LF> aa__<LF>lll dau<LF>ssdu
l
/daa<LF>\aau<LF>
a
ud
u
__/
d
s\
s
```

Each line should go to its own file and `<LF>` means actual newline in the file. 1 byte per extra file added to byte-count.

You can run the code as one file with the `-s` flag, keeping the `<LF>` markers and maybe changing them to newlines in the output for readability if you wish.

The algorithm is 5 simple substitute steps (change odd line content to even line content) starting from an empty input string. The results after each steps are (delimited by `=`'s):

```
sss __
ssa__
 aa__
lll dau
ssdu
============
sss __
ssa__
 aa__
/daa
\aau
/daa
\aau
/daa
\aau
 dau
ssdu
============
sss __
ssud__
 udud__
/dudud
\ududu
/dudud
\ududu
/dudud
\ududu
 dudu
ssdu
============
sss __
ss__/d__
 __/d__/d__
/d__/d__/d
\__/d__/d__/
/d__/d__/d
\__/d__/d__/
/d__/d__/d
\__/d__/d__/
 d__/d__/
ssd__/
============
sss __
ss__/s\__
 __/s\__/s\__
/s\__/s\__/s\
\__/s\__/s\__/
/s\__/s\__/s\
\__/s\__/s\__/
/s\__/s\__/s\
\__/s\__/s\__/
 s\__/s\__/
sss\__/
============
       __
    __/  \__
 __/  \__/  \__
/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/
/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/
/  \__/  \__/  \
\__/  \__/  \__/
   \__/  \__/
      \__/
```

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, <s>154</s> 151 bytes

```
b="\n",c="\t",d="/  \\",f="__",g="\\",h="/",a=f+d,j=a+a,i=d+j+b+g+j+f+h+b,k="   ";console.log(c+k+f+b+c+a+f+b+" "+j+f+b+i+i+i+k+g+a+f+h+b+c+"  "+g+f+h)
```