# Make a ASCII Hexagon Ring Tiling

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, hexagonal-grid, tiling

Using ASCII print a section of a hexagon ring tiling.

Here's a small section:

```
       /\__/\
      /_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ 
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ 
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\ 
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
      \ \__/ /
       \/__\/
```

Here's a larger section:

```
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
```

## Challenge

Given 2 integers `h` and `w`, where `h` is the height and `w` is the width, output a `hxw` section of a hexagon ring tiling.

## Examples

### Input 1

`4x4`

### Output 1

```
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
```

### Input 2

`3x3`

### Output 2

```
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
```

### Input 3

`1x3`

### Output 3

```
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
```

### Input 4

```
3x6
```

### Output 4

```
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
```

## Clarifications

- My question is similar to this one: [Me Want Honeycomb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50320/me-want-honeycomb).
- The input will be on a single line in the form `hxw`.
- Output to stdout (or something similar).
- This is code-golf so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: You should clarify exactly how large of a section we must output, to remain clear and objective

Comment: I just saw your comment I'll fix the dimensions to make it more clear

Comment: Since I don't think the moderators saw my comment, if the question stays on hold for the next 2 hours, ill make an updated question with the edits I did and a 4th example for clarity. Sorry for the confusion and if the edits I made aren't close to what you wanted please post comment telling me what's needed.

Comment: Should this be tagged kolmogorov-complexity?

Comment: ill add it in 1 sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Befunge, 137 bytes

I seem to have created some kind of scifi hand gun.

```
&>4*>~>$&>\>1-:4%3v
>00gg,\1-:v^_@#:\<>+00p\::6*\00g2/+2%+1+66+:
^%+66<:+1\_$$55+,^
_\/__\/_/  \
\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/
 /\__/\ \__/
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Jj40Kj5-PiQmPlw-MS06NCUzdgo-MDBnZyxcMS06dl5fQCM6XDw-KzAwcFw6OjYqXDAwZzIvKzIlKzErNjYrOgpeJSs2Njw6KzFcXyQkNTUrLF4KX1wvX19cL18vICBcClwgXF9fLyAvXF9fL1wKL18vICBcX1wvX19cLwogL1xfXy9cIFxfXy8&input=M3g2)

**Explanation**

```
&>4*>                    Read the height and multiply by 4.
     ~>$                 Drop the 'x' separator. 
        &>\              Read the width and swap below the height

>                        Start of the outer loop.
 1-                      Decrement the height.              
   :4%3+00p              Calculate the pattern y offset: height%4+3
           \             Swap the width back to the top.

::6*\00g2/+2%+1+         Calculate the line length: w*6+(w+y/2)%2+1 
                66+:     Initialise the pattern x offset to 12, and duplicate it.

>                        Start of the inner loop.     
 00gg                    Get a pattern char using the x on the stack and the saved y.
     ,                   Output the char.
      \1-                Swap the line length to the top of the stack and decrement it.
         :v              Check if it's zero, and if so...
          _                 ...break out of the loop to the right.
       +1\               Otherwise swap the x offset back to the top and increment it.
 %+66<:                  Mod it with 12 to make sure it's in range.
^                        Then return to the beginning of the inner loop.

$$                       Drop the x offset and line length.
  55+,                   Output a newline.
     \<                  Swap the height back to the top of the stack.
 _@#:                    Check if it's zero, and exit if that's the case.
^                        Otherwise return to the start of the outer loop.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, <strike>174</strike> <strike>176</strike> 156 bytes

*The code would print height-amount of lines, not height-amount of hexagons. Added `*4`, that fixed it, but added 2 extra bytes.*
*Saved some bytes by changing the counter from if to modulo, and by putting two `io.read()`s into one.*

Uses `io.read()` as input.

```
a,w,h,n,d={[[ /\__/\ \__/]],[[/_/  \_\/__\\]],[[\ \__/ /\__/]],[[_\/__\/_/  \\]]},io.read(,),"",0 for i=h*4,0,-1 do d=d+1 d=5%d end n=a[d]print(n:rep(w))end
```

Replicates the strings width-amount of times via `string:rep(width)`, then iterates height-amount of times with a for-loop. Needed `[[]]` (literal strings) because the backslashes really screwed stuff up.

*Old Version:*

```
a,w,h,n,d={[[ /\__/\ \__/]],[[/_/  \_\/__\\]],[[\ \__/ /\__/]],[[_\/__\/_/  \\]]},io.read(),io.read(),"",0 for i=h*4,0,-1 do d=d+1 d=5%d end n=a[d]print(n:rep(w))end
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 180 bytes

```python
a,b,c,d=' /\__/\ \__/','/_/  \_\/__\\','\ \__/ /\__/','_\/__\/_/  \\'
h,w=input()
x=w/2
e,E=[(2,1),(7,8)][w%2]
print'\n'.join([a*x+a[:e],b*x+b[:E],c*x+c[:E],' '+(d*x+d[:e])[1:]]*h)
```

Takes input as two integers

Input: `2,7`

Output:

```
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
 /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\
/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\
\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /\__/\ \__/ /
 \/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/_/  \_\/__\/
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 266 bytes

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1,1,%1)do call:l %2 " \" /__\/ "_/  \_\" " \__/ /" \__/\
exit/b
:l
call:c %1 " /" %6 %5
call:c %1 / %4 %3
call:c %1 \ %5 %6
:c
set s=%~2
for /l %%j in (2,2,%1)do call set s=%%s%%%~3%~4
set/ao=%1^&1
if %o%==1 set s=%s%%~3
echo %s%
```

The `:c` subroutine does all the legwork of concatenating the pieces together for a single line; it is called by `:l` 4 times (one by fall though by arranging for `:l`'s arguments to be a superset of `:c`'s) to generate the 4 lines for each row of rings. There was also the possibility of falling through for the last row of rings instead but it turned out to be 5 bytes longer.