# ASCII Hexagon Chain

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, hexagonal-grid

## Problem

Draw a hexagon chain `x` long, each with side of `y` length

## Input

`x` - the length of the chain <= 50

`y` - the length of each side <= 50

## Examples

`x=1,y=1`

```
 _
/ \
\_/
```

`x=4,y=1`

```
 _   _
/ \_/ \_
\_/ \_/ \
  \_/ \_/
```

`x=3,y=2`

```
  __      __
 /  \    /  \
/    \__/    \
\    /  \    /
 \__/    \__/
    \    /
     \__/
```

## Rules

- The shortest valid answer in bytes wins.
- Leading and trailing newlines allowed.
- Trailing white space allowed.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54277/58563)

Comment: Waiting for obligatory Hexagony answer...

Comment: @LLlAMnYP [Any minute now...](https://memegenerator.net/img/instances/60483873/ill-just-wait-here-then.jpg)

Comment: @user202729 If you write one now, we never have to find out what happens.

Comment: [First line in Hexagony](https://tio.run/##jY/NDoIwEITvPMWGAxQPRVHjD6A@yCbEg5GTXjXIs9dp2U08mBSabku/me60v72u9@fj7Rzpd6YBM6cMs0AtiBNlJdWUEmM9glZQNmSVdvi1gIxq6UQrWkJ@EdyCmkA8a2Rn1b7AthJggiTFyGiU7mMQd5gfNBhCBp9grQmY9hgdDhm2FoYtxAdJ4yUlzgzk2p2x8m@WBKUW5Pv5ayxsNpiMzwLR9IBcTKWsU5sc/kavig5kmqOZI5mhiAuiPIYj9B90bkebLw). Obviously need to increase edge size for the rest.

Answer (score 8):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
ＮθＦＮ«Ｍ∧﹪ι²⊗θ↓Ｐ×_θ←↖θ→↗θ×_θ↓↘θ←Ｐ↙θ↗
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY67CsIwGIXn9ilCpwTqori0k@AiWCmis/SS2kCav8akDuKzx6REaREcz@E7l6otZAUFN2Yneq0OuiupxDeShg1IhKcmIegZBhkMFG9EjTOoNQfMYrQkMdqCLjmtbdKKZAsPYSuCTHPFesmEwifW0TuOLlGMLJP6omRPG@VUPkLJuXeGQ77EkV3bOTI6nsn/lX9u@KST0@z8weTrSP4c8cPWeBmzCtdmMfA3) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the parameters in the order size, count. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the hexagon size.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop over the input number of hexagons.

```
Ｍ∧﹪ι²⊗θ↓
```

On alternate hexagons, move down a whole hexagon, so that the next hexagon is drawn to the lower right rather than the upper right.

```
Ｐ×_θ
```

Draw the bottom.

```
←↖θ
```

Draw the lower left side.

```
→↗θ
```

Draw the upper left side.

```
×_θ
```

Draw the top.

```
↓↘θ
```

Draw the upper right side.

```
←Ｐ↙θ
```

Draw the lower right side.

```
↗
```

Assume the next hexagon is to the upper right.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>254</s> 224 bytes

```python
def f(n,w):
 a=w*2
 for j in range(1+w*3):print''.join([[[' ',[' /'[i%w==-j%w],' \\'[i%w==~-j%w]][i/a+~-j/w&1]][(j>0)*(i/w>=(j>a))*((i/w/n<2)or(n%-2<~-j/w<3-n%2))],' _'[(j+i/w%4/2*w)%a<(i<n*a)]][i/w%2]for i in range(-~n*a)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5LbsIwEN3nFN4YzzhO3RhQK@RwERNVlorBWUxQhDRiw9WDEyp1M@8zv3d73K8juXn@PSeRgAzjoRKxY@0qkcZJDCKTmCJdztDWrLd4uE2Z7kp9DGMmCCEooUwpVoUsueuaQXJvlDid/ozn6vQh21gXbnnTFgXD8RM1ZMvHrvCIRSzKknc4TkCycX4d99uGpENcjv6osliXMbmzTjPK6CF70hHXByxdv4TO/6Gb59rFOUFrWqwS7N7wbdwC@zd8mT3OLw)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>264</s> 229 bytes

```python
def f(n,w):
 c=2*w;r=[[' ']*(-~n*c)for _ in' '*(1+w*3)]
 for i in range(w):
  for j in range(n):a=i+j*2*w;b=j%2*w;r[b][w+a],r[c+b][w+i+j*c],r[b+w-i][a],r[b+c-i][a+c],r[b+w-~i][a],r[b-~i][a+c]=r'__//\\'
 for l in r:print''.join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoMwEITvPkUuJb9W1JaCJU8Sg2hq2ohECULoxVe3GkF7m/lmd3bH7/QZbLYsr1YDjSzzuIiA4hnxT8eFgABKguLZEoX14EAFjF0ZQSn1JMcyAhs1KwWutu8Whf0AuxNaXNTc0I5stQ3vLqFeNFJ4WkvmhKJBbyNq8w31sZGi3rUKmh7JfES7XBPuYFUlSVnC/aM@HC9GZ@wE4bUbjEU9XjRKWYqjgCONbv8mZ9lpHuyOlx8)

Comment: @ovs Thanks a lot :)

Comment: [222 bytes](https://tio.run/##RU7basMwDH3vV/jFs@Q4c@O2bHROf8QNxdC6dR6UEgpiMPrrmZMO9qJz0dFB9@/HbSA3TedLEgnIMO5XIg2j6EUmMUa6XqCpWG9wH1vW7us@Znoo9d4PmSCEoIQyZVgVsuS2rXvJnVHiePwznovThWxjVbjlt6Yo6A9r1JAtH9rCIxYxK0ve4Q@QrJ1f0n5Tk3SIc@dJlbuqpOTWOs0oo4fsSUdc@lm6bv48/39eP5ctTgka0@AqwfYFn8bNsHvBh9nh9As "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), <s>32</s> 31 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
ā.{e╚øΚe╔*ο⁴↔±┼┼╬±fe«*If2%e*I╬5
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JXUwMTAxLiU3QmUldTI1NUElRjgldTAzOUFlJXUyNTU0KiV1MDNCRiV1MjA3NCV1MjE5NCVCMSV1MjUzQyV1MjUzQyV1MjU2QyVCMWZlJUFCKklmMiUyNWUqSSV1MjU2QzU_,inputs=MTUlMEE1,v=0.12)

Explanation:

```
ā                              push an empty array - the canvas
 .{                            repeat input times
   e╚                            push a diagonal the length of the variable E (by default: next input)
     øΚ                          prepend a line to it
       e╔*ο                      push ["_"*E]
           ⁴                     copy that diagonal
            ↔±                   and reverse it horizontally
              ┼┼                 add the 3 parts together
                ╬±               and palindromize vertically - one hexagon is finished
                  fe«*I          push counter*E*2 + 1 (the counter is 0-based)
                       f2%e*I    push counter%2 * E + 1
                             ╬5  at [counter*E*2+1; counter%2*E+1] insert the hexagon in the canvas
```

Answer (score 3):

## Befunge, <s>230</s> <s>228</s> 225 bytes

```
+&#92#<*:0< vp93*p92+1*3:p91:&+1p
>1+:29g-!#@_>:1-19g+:19g/1-:2*49p2%!2*:1+59p19g*\19g%+69p01v
,>*19g3*79g-1-69g-!2*49g1+0g2%*79g69g-!49g0g2%*++4g,1+:39g-v
^^3*!-*g95g91+1g96!-g95%4p04p01:`\g90p05`0::/g91:p97%*4g91:_$55+
 \/_
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=KyYjOTIjPCo6MDwgdnA5MypwOTIrMSozOnA5MTomKzFwCj4xKzoyOWctISNAXz46MS0xOWcrOjE5Zy8xLToyKjQ5cDIlITIqOjErNTlwMTlnKlwxOWclKzY5cDAxdgosPioxOWczKjc5Zy0xLTY5Zy0hMio0OWcxKzBnMiUqNzlnNjlnLSE0OWcwZzIlKisrNGcsMSs6MzlnLXYKXl4zKiEtKmc5NWc5MSsxZzk2IS1nOTUlNHAwNHAwMTpgXGc5MHAwNWAwOjovZzkxOnA5NyUqNGc5MTpfJDU1KwogXC9f&input=MyAy)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 215 bytes

Takes input in currying syntax `(y)(x)`.

```js
y=>(F=(x,c=!(p=y-1,w=x*y*2+y,a=[...(' '.repeat(w++)+`
`).repeat(3*y+1)],g=(d,k)=>k!=y?g(d,-~k,a[p+=d]='_\\/'[c%3]):c++))=>x--?F(x,g(1),g(w+1),p++,g(w-1),g(-1),p+=w,g(~w),p--,g(1-w),p+=(c/6&1?w:-w)*y-w+y*2):a.join``)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

y=>(F=(x,c=!(p=y-1,w=x*y*2+y,a=[...(' '.repeat(w++)+`
`).repeat(3*y+1)],g=(d,k)=>k!=y?g(d,-~k,a[p+=d]='_\\/'[c%3]):c++))=>x--?F(x,g(1),g(w+1),p++,g(w-1),g(-1),p+=w,g(~w),p--,g(1-w),p+=(c/6&1?w:-w)*y-w+y*2):a.join``)

O.innerText = f(3)(7)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
ø╶｛╷⁷«×¹２％⁷×╵⁷⇵_× ⁷／∔×╬│╋
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JUY4JXUyNTc2JXVGRjVCJXUyNTc3JXUyMDc3JUFCJUQ3JUI5JXVGRjEyJXVGRjA1JXUyMDc3JUQ3JXUyNTc1JXUyMDc3JXUyMUY1XyVENyUyMCV1MjA3NyV1RkYwRiV1MjIxNCVENyV1MjU2QyV1MjUwMiV1MjU0Qg__,i=MTElMEEz,v=1)

Explanation (some characters have been changed to look monospace):

```
ø╶{╷⁷«×¹2%⁷×╵⁷⇵_× ⁷/∔×╬│╋
ø                          push an empty canvas
 ╶{                        for 1..input
   ╷                         decrease (so this starts with 0)
    ⁷«×                      multiply by X*2; X coordinate of new hexagon done
       ¹2%                   push 0-indexed counter%2
          ⁷×                 multiply by X
            ╵                and increment; Y coordinate done
             ⁷⇵              push ceil(X/2), saving the remainder
               _×            repeat "_" that many times
                  ⁷/         push " " and an ASCII diagonal with size X
                    ∔        prepend verticall the space before the diagonal
                              done so there's space for the underscores
                     ×       and append the underscores horizontally to the diagonal
                      ╬│     quad-palindromize with Y overlap of 1
                              and X overlap of the remainder taken before
                        ╋    and at the before defined coords ((I-1)*X*2; (i%2)*X + 1)
                              insert the hexagon in the canvas
```