# How Many Atoms?

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing, chemistry

Your task is when given a chemical formula as input, output the total number of atoms in the formula.

#### Input

A chemical formula in any reasonable format. Each chemical formula has the following:

- A leading coefficient, which is a number \$N > 1\$.
- At least 0 groupings of elements surrounded by parentheses.

  - Groupings can have both elements and groupings inside of them.
- At least 1 element.

  - Elements match the regex `[A-Z][a-z]*`.
- Each grouping and element can have an optional subscript, which is an `_` followed by a number \$N > 1\$

#### Output

The total number of atoms in the formula. Rules for counting are as follows:

- A coefficient before the formula multiplies the total count that many times.
- A subscript multiples the group or atom it follows that many times.
- An element with no coefficient or subscript represents 1 atom.

#### Testcases

```
In -> Out (Notes)
H_2O -> 3
CO_2 -> 3
Co_2 -> 2 (2 cobalts)
3 C_2H -> 9
EeeEeuEetUue -> 4
3 (C_21H_30O_2)_3 -> 477 (= 3 * (53) * 3)
32H -> 32
C_10H_16N_5O_13P_3 -> 47
(Ga(U(Y_2)_3)_4)_5 -> 145 (= (1 + (1 + (2 * 3)) * 4) * 5)
Ti(Ca_2(HSO_4)_2)_2 -> 29 (= 1 + (2 + (1 + 1 + 4) * 2) * 2))
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58469/molecules-to-atoms) that asks for number of each atom

Comment: @Arnauld yep, miscalculation

Comment: @Arnauld another miscalculation

Comment: Maybe you should define the chemical formula with more detail: What syntax are aimed to support. Also, is it possible to represent [\$ {\rm {KAl(SO_{4})_{2}\cdot 12H_{2}O}} \$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_alum) with current syntax?

Comment: @tsh I actually had an entire EBNF while this was in the sandbox and someone pointed out it'd turn into an input validation challenge instead. Besides, what you have there isn't a valid input regardless (coefficient in the middle of the formula)

Comment: Can you explain what "32H" is, and why that is considered to have 32 atoms?

Comment: @CodyGray `32H` is 32 hydrogen atoms

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(s.replace(/[A-Z][a-z]*|_|^\d+|\(/g,s=>+s?`n=${s};n*=`:s>{}?"*":"+"+(s>"0"||s)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDfT4JQFAfw9/4KdtfDuRACF8hpA9cYi6doKx9K7XiHV2dj4LzqQ@LfTtiy5qW2zvPnfM@PN77jMlsvVxuzKGeinge1DEKx4znIzlqscp4JsEa35stkxM33iV5h9TqeGdUYrMVVQw05mBbB5V4ebgo9mPZluD8MiE76xCAGyJDYpKokpbTOykKWuejk5QLmQBJkKdHOi1LNsjT3QqFRiuy/tPyLMpW6WoQsIb/QnkpjIWKxjcVmuBXkjHrtVGhinQRdu9maoku@abfbwur8n8Na60bo2Ak61/fop@i4D8fkU7Bq4Y7DEJ4/51P0KPon63i@ip@WEHFkkDymR9r0MPL1sl79AQ)

#### How?

Matched patterns and replacements are summarized in the following table.

```
 pattern     | replacement
-------------+-------------------------------------------
 [A-Z][a-z]* | "+true"
 _           | "*"
 ^\d+        | "n=N;n*=" (where N is the matched number)
 \(          | "+("
```

For instance, `"3 (C_21H_30O_2)_3"` is turned into:

```
"n=3;n*= +(+true*21+true*30+true*2)*3"
```

This string is simply evaluated as JS code.

Comment: What it the reason for using "true"? Wouldn't "1" work as well?

Comment: @lisyarus He doesn't use a literal `true`, it's just that the expression `s>"0"||s` results in either `true` or `(`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```
\d+
$*
(1+) (.+)
($2)_$1
[A-Z][a-z]*(_|())
$#2$*
+1`(\((1+)\)_)1|\(1+\)_
$2$1
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYuxCsJAEET7/YqAJ@wmKNk9tZcjeJUR1EKTsAa8wkZBtBH/PW5shuHNm2d63e79MMXNZWivBbgckAvKcF4QoBNSx9CsZ@eu6WefLkf9IhG4iZhZ8AVbHP2WlPjbWrUGTuzEwxBVagi1CoSHhc@CSoQqpSq9q/Q6vpMxNMhRfWkeqQcvWYSgXEbl1VaXtbLfGcdNj0c8/SXSBekSDjcMvQrGfT0CW@QH) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the numbers to unary.

```
(1+) (.+)
($2)_$1
```

Turn any coefficient into a group.

```
[A-Z][a-z]*(_|())
$#2$*
```

Delete all elements with suffixes, but if an element did not have a suffix, then replace it with `1`.

```
+1`(\((1+)\)_)1|\(1+\)_
$2$1
```

Multiply out all of the groupings. (These have to be done one at a time to be able to collect the results correctly.)

```
1
```

Convert to decimal.

Comment: `Ti(Ca_2(3 HSO_4)_2)_2` is not a valid input

Comment: @bigyihsuan I'm glad we don't have to support it, btw. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 57 bytes

```perl
y/_a-z/*/d;s/^\d+\K.*/*($&)/;s/\pL/+1/g;s/\(/+(/g;$_=eval
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY9BS8QwFITv@RU5LPLSUt8maVyWZb2UYkCxgu5BKD6iG2Sh2GK7gv54a9LWQybDDPPB6/xnY8YeeXZ9mSDuxm8kl/1ggsddjy/1Ma1vQ5HA6kJgSOruDlOJ79ECphDcivb@yzXjaElVgcM1KypSi2tnpzgo/ta@umboBdO8IGVjvmWl96U/l344nH1M8tBCqKUlvQ4cQXqKNxsOe655wsFoET4dODNEK1aQXFuSV/dkKpL64X/E4MbBAZ4njqBckImFzE2kgeTpImoiRm4exQj2dILCkQL7WMVdAMyXbONy2Szr@KaZmkX8tt1waj/6MeuaPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 88 bytes

*A port of [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216728/83605) in Ruby!*

```ruby
p eval gsub(/_|\(/,?_=>?*,?(=>'+(').gsub(/[A-Z][a-z]*/,'+1').gsub /^\d+/,"k=#{'\&'};k*="
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpba8IwGEDf8yuKgvl6MyZRX6QtI5TlaRWcD2r1o8UwRLGiVtjFv74sbns5D@ecc1u/W3vyzK06eG@XtgaGXyWwKMMkzYIogySlIVC//xdXT/Fyvarij3XAIhry/@CxTbkNWdTZJ91PWvbofbIPko61GkVBVIGCqMZBegqFJrkxuWlzc523xjlwkmuUA/f5KIl0i0I@0MjHLzgqkMup0/BcwRwWv4@PQx9H5HUHqkIBelY8hCviuzldd83xYuPj4Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>39</s> 37 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
AмAuS„+1:'_'*:'(„+(.:.γd}ćDdi'*«}šJ.E
```

Similar approach as the other answers, except without regex. Especially the `^\d+` to `N*` therefore costs quite a few bytes (16 to be exact: `.γd}ćDdi'*«}šJ`).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8cIex9LgRw3ztA2t1OPVtazUNUAcDT0rvXObU2qPtLukZKprHVpde3Shl57r///GChrO8UaGHvHGBv7xRprxxgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf8cLexxLgx81zNM2tFKPV9eyUtcAcTT0rPTObU6pPdLukpKprnVode3RhV56rv91/nvEG/lzOfvHG3E55wMJYwXneCMPLtfUVNfUUtfUktDSVKCYBlDQ0CPe2ACoTjPemMsYqMQ53tDAI97QzC/e1D/e0DgAKKzhnqgRqhEJVqMZb6IZb8oVkqnhnBhvpOER7A8SAMoYAQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Aм           # Remove all lowercase letters from the (implicit) input-string
AuS„+1:      # Replace all uppercase letters with "+1"
'_'*:        # Replace all "_" with "*"
'(„+(.:     '# Replace all "(" with "+("
.γ }         # Adjacent group the string by:
  d          #  Whether it's a digit
    ć        # Extract head; pop and push the remainder-list and first item
             # separated to the stack
     D       # Duplicate this first item
      di     # Pop, and if it's a (non-negative) integer:
        '*« '#  Append "*" to it
       }     # After the if-statement:
        š    # Prepend the potentially modified first item back to the list
         J   # Join everything together again
.E           # And evaluate and execute it as Python code
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[Verify all test cases without the `.E`.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn3lf8cLexxLgx81zNM2tFKPV9eyUtcAcTT0rPTObU6pPdLukpKprnVode3RhV7/df57xBv5czn7xxtxOecDCWMF53gjDy7X1FTX1FLX1JLQ0lSgmAZQ0NAj3tgAqE4z3pjLGKjEOd7QwCPe0Mwv3tQ/3tA4ACis4Z6oEaoRCVajGW@iGW/KFZKp4ZwYb6ThEewPEgDKGAEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 111 bytes

```php
eval('$n='.preg_replace(["/^(\d+)/","/[A-Z][a-z]*/","/_/","/\(/"],['$1;$n*=',"+1","*","+("],$argn).';');echo$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdBda4MwFAbg@/0KCYInVk3jx0pxZQxx82oOtl5s1h3EZbYgKq7dxX58XSrrRnWDBRJI8uQ9SZp1011cNnIU71kJmlotNKtpRYGtaMosF5AQ9gyrlwllxCAsuTKf0iQzP1K9n2M/roCR1Eg0lftqpS80g0y4XNdln4DcUbO2qKil@Rr1Rb6u1crvmJ7X1VtdCqusC3gFEqEdE@W0UaowpjhnAxrEaP@X1n9Re0gdJUA7Ir/Q@ZCGQoRiF4rtcifICXXHqSBjeYTOVN6aokO@6Ww2wsP6Pw8bXTdAPo2Qn9@iFyN37g7Jx@ChhZsMlvDY16foUvSOlrveED9sIMjQhug@PlB5xiZfXzbXWTd60L5uthsZ0ZnXnw)

Just a port of [Arnauld's clever trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216728/90841) with `eval` and some adaptations:

- in PHP it was shorter to use a list of regexes instead of using `preg_replace_callback` (what a long function name)
- the evaled string has to be valid php prefixed with `$n=` and ended by `;` (in PHP `eval` does not return the result), example with "Ti(Ca_2(HSO_4)_2)_2": `$n=+1+(+1*2+(+1+1+1*4)*2)*2;`
- output of `$n` has to be explicit

Longer than what I thought, but "c'est de bonne guerre ma bonne dame", it's our good old PHP after all

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 92 bytes

I think there's definitely some room for optimization here; A lot of the bytes are just there to handle the cases with the leading "\d "

```powershell
$t=1;-split$args|%{$t*=$_-replace'\(','+('-creplace'[A-Z][a-z]*','+1'-replace'_','*'|iex};$t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNRb5swEMff8yksyx0mCVOBZNVSIWXLsvKUVGuraWPIYuSWoVJgtlG7JXz21EBDmSKWSvOL73zn3/19trP0Hrj4CXG8Iz/yJJRRmjg9pMZmR6RjnhsiiyNJAr4W25MNkX2HMINDFgchaN@oNtQGVDPC/Yr3zvjqe4Hxx@@XIVNrcpny@9o2gofinMhd0SMShJwFAgRy0JRWRaebaipHlGS5LI0yiF1mLbHeBOEhg1DCqg7aT5Fi2Ll/tmTW/@y30YxZbifh7XHCHGAO@RzkTQ6dnNFLlFAlxXSZfarOpDO7G3Z29oLGMPPUZeabBRsvmWlf/pN3HEcvAnpDv1TCdDbS2bgTZ47Gx3nXEZ0FzKLu1bKkKWz3NVrNLfT09uvaohO0qfxFfvcduGMWdTlS1Roi0uIQ9rpeVcZ@uU7mIPJYqpRXzU9B0yq3jos8DEGUjxk/5WJkwC/l7Tm4SvzMIwmGmwqJsHetVKGWNh9hdDiMRbqA@zhK4JBAKNU@BlGcc1A/7KoWoeneXo@v@7hNQMb7ILxd8zRPVrM0TjlSgA8Bv/0EKwUorQsOkPyFOCg7Qc9n7BantGHkzffdbRrh46EnJI@StT@ZzO8y@btdDKO6oc9dGQx6xe4R)

## Honorary Mention, PowerShell, <strike>99</strike> 92 bytes

This was my first solution, and I really liked it. Including it here because I think it's fun.

```powershell
$o="'-creplace'";"'$args$o^(\d)(.*)','`$1*(`$2)$o\(','+($o[A-Z][a-z]*','+1$o`_','*'"|iex|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZNhb5swEIa/51dYljdMEqoCyaplipSNsfIpqdZW00aZw8gtQ6WYGqN2TfPbMwNNyhSxVJolxJ3v/Nzrs53xOxD5L0iSDflZpJGMeTruIDVWG8LHWDMiAVkSRqDhd1gjoVjmhH@nVwudHnV1ra/Nidmlc2LphF9R5fco4f5741vgh8ZD0C1nTMLnTBldDT/GcF9@m3WHSMilE@aQozGa0KroZFX9yhGnWSFLowxij1kzrO@CcJ9BJGFRB@2nyLrfut6ZMet/1tvIYZbXSnh7mOACuFC4IC8LaOUMXqKEKimmx@xjtSed2e2wk5MXNIaZxx4z30zZcMZM@@yfvMM4ehrSS/q1Eqazgc6GrThzMDzMu4ipEzKLeuezkqaw7cdo7U6hozdv1yN6hVaVPy1ufoAYm@u6HKlq9RFpcAg7qmeVsZ2ukwXkRSJVyuvdS0GTKreO50UUQV5eZvyUi5EBt8rbcnCV@EXEEgyP5xJh/0KpQg1tAcJofxhTPoW7JE5hn0Ao1T6FcVIIUE/svBah6f5WT6AHuElAxocwul4KXqQLhydcIAX4GIrrz7BQgNI6FQDpX4i9siP0vMd2cUobRr677e6uEQHu@7kUcboMRiP3JpO/m8Uwqhv63JVer7Pe/AE)

Comment: 0. It's impressed! Thanks!  1. `A leading coefficient` may appear only once, so you can use `$args-replace' (.+)','*($1)'` instead `$t=1;-split$args|%{$t*=`.

Comment: 2. Your `first solution` is  the best! With a little golf [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBPT8JAEMXv@ykmzepuoTX0DxJDSDAN2pMlIgdFstQ6KKZksdtGIvDZ67ZSOOxh3@@9eZPZyB/M1CemaUmXMIBdSeXAYHaS4SaNE2QGMRiNsw9FJfCrtsks1uIL6phUvnL9aXMqZ7f2y3wW27/zVqU4VC5E5WPGfoXb6pUHQoacEIsDgGcBC4UbMTDPQhAJ9yTcaMGDQLjhSfK1NEIcYTHCfFrgEfi9Xu3l2uyEwuvoMabwmphf0UA4nVA41w@iGwnHG5@w43c15vcxn/LnOmcK3xTdJu1WezyteBALl4eTqILaVe9JTNjDBeyI3g0objeY5PhuAV3KbF2ksb4lFf8wQ1WkuRYu9YkbXqPZWAWFyuU6evvS@flwB5MiSVCpKn7M2fh9LujDYzPtyPtwd25syg/kUP4B "PowerShell – Try It Online"). Thanks again!

Comment: A regexp is greedy. so [1 byte less](https://tio.run/##RZBPT8JAEMXv@ykmzepuoU3oHySGkGAatCdLRA4KZKl1UEzJYreNROCz122lcNjDvt978yazlT@YqU9M05KuYAD7ksqBwewkw20aJ8gMYjAaZx@KSphP2sxiLb6kHZPKOdefNqdydme/Lmax/btoVYpD5VJUPmYc1rirXnkkZMgJsTgAeBawULgRA/MiBJFwz8KtFjwIhBueJV9LI8QRFiPMpwWegN/r1V6uzU4ovI4eYwqvifkVDYTTCYVz8yi6kXC88Rk7fldj/hDzKX@pc6bwTdFt0m61x/OaB7FweTiJKqhd9Z7EhANcwZ7o3YDibotJju8W0JXMNkUa61NS8Q8zVEWaa@FaX7jhNZqNVVCoXG6ity@dXwz3MCmSBJWq4qecjd@Xgj48NdNOvA/3l8am/EiO5R8 "PowerShell – Try It Online") :)

Comment: Impressive saves, as always, @mazzy!! :D I knew there was something to the honorary mention solution, I just couldn't crack it on my own! At the point of saving me that many bytes, you may as well just consider the solution your own! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 88 bytes

inspired by `Honorary Mentioned Solution` by [Zaelin Goodman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/216785/80745)

-1 byte thanks to Zaelin Goodman

+5 bytes the `32H` test case added

```powershell
$o="'-creplace'"
"'$args$o^\d+','`$0*($'')#$o\(','+($o[A-Z][a-z]*','+1$o`_','*'"|iex|iex
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBdT8IwFIbv@ytOZrUdjIR9IDGEBLKgu3IkyIUCljkOihkp7iMSgd8@u8kAL5q073OenpOzkd8YJx8YRTldQhd2OZVdjTXCGDdRECLTiMZoEL8nVL5OF3VmsDlt1jhlTL@icspVUOdUTvqNl9kkaPzMakViUjkX6lJj2n6F2@LkB0J6nBCDA9iWAcy2PAZ6@QZbvT1h@f8C1xfWKbgrDHDFheSoaIA4wGyA6TjDI3Da7bKWq2LTE3ZTfaMLu9KcgrrCbHrCvH0ULV@Y9vCETaelMH8I@Jg/l54uHF20Ktsq5nhacTcQFvdGfgFVVTkn0WEP17AjajaguN1gmOLCALqU8TqLArVeKv5gjEkWpSq4UVuveIkmw8TNklSu/bdP5c96OxhlYYhJUuhHr4Ff5wYd6KvyC9yB@3PDqveBHPJf)

Powershell expands the formula `32H` to:

```powershell
'32H'-creplace'^\d+','$0*($'')#'-creplace'\(','+('-creplace'[A-Z][a-z]*','+1'-creplace'_','*'
```

The first `iex` calculates this expression to:

```powershell
32*+(+1)#+1
```

The second `iex` calculates the expression before the comment to `32`.

---

Another example. Powershell expands the formula `3 (C_21H_30O_2)_3` to:

```powershell
'3 (C_21H_30O_2)_3'-creplace'^\d+','$0*($'')#'-creplace'\(','+('-creplace'[A-Z][a-z]*','+1'-creplace'_','*'
```

The first `iex` calculates this expression to:

```powershell
3*+( +(+1*21+1*30+1*2)*3)# +(+1*21+1*30+1*2)*3
```

The second `iex` calculates the expression before the comment to `477`.

Comment: Brilliant solution; -1 byte by changing `\S+` to `.+` (since there should never be more whitespace) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZBPT8JAEMXv@ykmzepuoTX0DxJDSDAN2pMlIgdFstQ6KKZksdtGIvDZ67ZSOOxh3@@9eZPZyB/M1CemaUmXMIBdSeXAYHaS4SaNE2QGMRiNsw9FJVy1mcVafEE7JpWvXH/anMrZrf0yn8X277xVKQ6VC1H5mLFf4bZ65YGQISfE4gDgWcBC4UYMzLMQRMI9CTda8CAQbniSfC2NEEdYjDCfFngEfq9Xe7k2O6HwOnqMKbwm5lc0EE4nFM71g@hGwvHGJ@z4XY35fcyn/LnOmcI3RbdJu9UeTysexMLl4SSqoHbVexIT9nABO6J3A4rbDSY5vltAlzJbF2msL0nFP8xQFWmuhUt94IbXaDZWQaFyuY7evnR@PtzBpEgSVKqKH3M2fp8L@vDYTDvyPtydG5vyAzmUfw "PowerShell – Try It Online")