# Find the Interwoven Source Codes (Cops)

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers

This is the cops' thread. For the robbers' thread, go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/find-the-nested-source-codes-robbers).

## Introduction

For this Cops/Robbers challenge, the cops will write output-producing programs and interweave them together. It is the robber's job to pick apart the cops' programs to produce the desired outputs.

## Cop rules

The cops may use up to 256 bytes total to write between 2 and 8 (inclusive) programs, all of which *must* produce some output. All programs written must be in the same language. The cops will "interweave" their programs together to make it harder for the robbers to figure out what the programs are.

Now for a description of interweaving. Consider the strings representing the different programs. The process of interweaving is the repeated pulling off of the first character of any of the programs and concatenating it to the end of a new string until no characters in any of the programs are left. For example, if two programs are `lion` and `TIGER`, a possible interweaving is `TIliGoEnR`. However, the programs cannot be scrambled in any way, so `RoITEnlGi` is not acceptable.

It should be noted that when the characters of all but one program are removed from the results of an interweaving, the remaining program would be shown intact. Removing the letters `TIGER` from `TIliGoEnR` results in `lion`.

All of the cops' programs and outputs must contain *only* printable ASCII characters (20-7E) and newlines. Programs must not contain errors and must run in 10 seconds on a reasonable machine. For any submission, there must be a free interpreter of the language somewhere. Adding comments to the submissions is not allowed, as are hashing and other forms of cryptography. Blank programs are not allowed (Sorry [Stuck](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world/55425#55425)).

The cop will post the interweaved code, the language, the number of different programs used, and the output for each program. A big thanks to Martin for writing [this CJam script](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7Bmr((o_%7Ba%7D%26%2B%7Dh&input=abcdefg%0AABCDEFG%0A0123456) to automatically interweave your programs.

Programs are deemed safe after one week has elapsed from the time of posting. At that point, the cops must post the individual programs in order to receive points.

## Scoring

There are two components that are added together when scoring a safe submission.

- 256 divided by the quantity 2 raised to the power of the number of programs used.
- Round the number of bytes in the interweaving **up** to the nearest power of 2 and divide it into 256.

For example, if the entry `TIliGoEnR` (9 bytes) were safe, it would receive 256/2^2+256/16=80 points.

When a cop's submission is cracked, the cop loses 16 points. The cop must indicate that their submission has been cracked.

The winner of the cops' challenge will be the person with the most points after a sufficient period of time for people to participate.

## Leaderboard

This is a work in progress that was adapted by [intrepidcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45393/intrepidcoder) from [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/60328/45393).

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the **exact** Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N programs, M bytes; Score ###/### (if safe/cracked)
```

Anything after a semicolon will be ignored, so you can put your score there.

If your submission is safe put a header like this:

```
# Language Name, safe, N programs, M bytes; Score ###
```

If it is cracked, put a header like this:

```
# Language Name, [cracked](link-to-crack), N programs, M bytes; Score -16
```

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 64520; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 43444; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.
var SECONDSINDAY = 86400;
var SAFECUTOFFDAYS = 7;
var SORTBYTIME = true;
var SUBTRACTCRACKEDPOINTS = true;
var EXPIREDTIME = 1448232502000;


/* App */


var SAFE_REG = /<h\d>.*?[sS][aA][fF][eE].*<\/\h\d>/;
var POINTS_REG = /<h\d>.*(\d+)\s*program.*<\/h\d>/i; // /(?:<=|≤|&lt;=)\s?(?:<\/?strong>)?\s?(\d+)/ 
// var POINTS_REG_ALT = /<h\d>.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;
var LENGTH_REG = /<h\d>.*?((\d+)\s*byte).*<\/h\d>/i;
var CRACKED_HEADER_REG = /<h\d>.*[Cc][Rr][Aa][Cc][Kk][Ee][Dd].*<\/h\d>/;
var CRACKED_COMMENT_REG = /(.*[Cc][Rr][Aa][Cc][Kk][Ee][Dd].*<a href=.*)|(.*<a href=.*[Cc][Rr][Aa][Cc][Kk][Ee][Dd].*)/
var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
var LANGUAGE_REG = /<h\d>\s*(.+?),.*<\/h\d>/;
var LANGUAGE_REG_ALT = /<h\d>\s*(<a href=.+<\/a>).*<\/h\d>/
var LANGUAGE_REG_ALT_2 = /<h\d>\s*(.+?)\s.*<\/h\d>/;
var LANGUAGE_REG_ALT_3 = /<h\d>(.+?)<\/h\d>/;

var answers = [],
  answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1,
  more_answers = true,
  comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" + QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {

  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });

}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {

        answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);

      });

      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers();

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {

  var valid = [];
  var open = [];



  answers.forEach(function(a) {

    var body = a.body.replace(/(<h\d>.*);.*(<\/h\d>)/,"$1$2"); // Ignore all text after a semicolon.
    var cracked = false;
    
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      var was_safe = (c.creation_date + (SECONDSINDAY * SAFECUTOFFDAYS) > a.creation_date);
      if (CRACKED_COMMENT_REG.test(c.body) && !was_safe)
        cracked = true;
    });

    if (CRACKED_HEADER_REG.test(body)) cracked = true;

    // if (SUBTRACTCRACKEDPOINTS||!cracked) {

    var createDate = a.creation_date;
    var currentDate = Date.now() / 1000;
    var timeToSafe = (createDate + (SECONDSINDAY * SAFECUTOFFDAYS) - currentDate) / SECONDSINDAY;
    var SafeTimeStr = (timeToSafe > 2) ? (Math.floor(timeToSafe) + " Days") :
      (timeToSafe > 1) ? ("1 Day") :
      (timeToSafe > (2 / 24)) ? (Math.floor(timeToSafe * 24) + " Hours") :
      (timeToSafe > (1 / 24)) ? ("1 Hour") :
      "<1 Hour";

    var expired = createDate > (EXPIREDTIME);

    var safe = timeToSafe < 0;
    var programs = body.match(POINTS_REG);
    var length = body.match(LENGTH_REG);
    safe = safe && !cracked

    isOpen = !(cracked || safe);

    if (programs && length) {
      
      var safepoints = (256/Math.pow(2,parseInt(programs[1],10)) +
                    256/Math.pow(2,Math.ceil(Math.log2(parseInt(length[1],10)))));
      
      var crackedpoints = Math.pow(2, parseInt(programs[1],10),2) + 
          Math.pow(2,Math.floor(Math.log2(parseInt(length[1],10))));


      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        numberOfSubmissions: (safe && !expired) ? 1 : 0,
        points: (safe && !expired) ? safepoints : 0,
        open: (isOpen && !expired) ? 1 : 0,
        cracked: (cracked && !expired) ? 1 : 0,
        expired: (expired) ? 1 : 0
      });

    }

    if ((isOpen || expired) && programs) {

      var language = body.match(LANGUAGE_REG);
      if (!language) language = body.match(LANGUAGE_REG_ALT);
      if (!language) language = body.match(LANGUAGE_REG_ALT_2);
      if (!language) language = body.match(LANGUAGE_REG_ALT_3);



      open.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        safePts: programs ? safepoints : "???",
        crackedPts: programs ? crackedpoints : "???",
        language: language ? language[1] : "???",
        link: a.share_link,
        timeToSafe: timeToSafe,
        timeStr: (expired) ? "Challenge closed" : SafeTimeStr
      });
    }
    // }
  });


  if (SORTBYTIME) {
    open.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.timeToSafe - b.timeToSafe;
    });
  } else {
    open.sort(function(a, b) {
      var r1 = parseInt(a.length);
      var r2 = parseInt(b.length);
      if (r1 && r2) return r1 - r2;
      else if (r1) return r2;
      else if (r2) return r1;
      else return 0;
    });
  }

  var pointTotals = [];
  valid.forEach(function(a) {

    var index = -1;
    var author = a.user;
    pointTotals.forEach(function(p) {
      if (p.user == author) index = pointTotals.indexOf(p);
    });

    if (index == -1) {
      if (SUBTRACTCRACKEDPOINTS && a.cracked) a.points -= 16;
      pointTotals.push(a);
    }
    else {
      pointTotals[index].points += a.points;
      pointTotals[index].numberOfSubmissions += a.numberOfSubmissions;
      pointTotals[index].cracked += a.cracked;
      pointTotals[index].expired += a.expired;
      pointTotals[index].open += a.open;
      if (SUBTRACTCRACKEDPOINTS && a.cracked) pointTotals[index].points -= 16;
    }

  });

  pointTotals.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.points != b.points)
      return b.points - a.points;
    else if (a.numberOfSubmissions != b.numberOfSubmissions)
      return b.numberOfSubmissions - a.numberOfSubmissions;
    else if (a.open != b.open)
      return b.open - a.open;
    else if (a.cracked != b.cracked)
      return a.cracked - b.cracked;
    else return 0;
  });



  pointTotals.forEach(function(a) {


    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer
      .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
      .replace("{{SAFE}}", a.numberOfSubmissions)
      .replace("{{OPEN}}", a.open)
      .replace("{{CLOSED}}", a.expired)
      .replace("{{CRACKED}}", a.cracked)
      .replace("{{POINTS}}", a.points);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);


  });



  open.forEach(function(a) {
    var answer = jQuery("#open-template").html();
    answer = answer
      .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
      .replace("{{SAFE}}", a.safePts)
      .replace("{{CRACKED}}", a.crackedPts)
      .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
      .replace("{{TIME}}", a.timeStr)
      .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#opensubs").append(answer);
  });



}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: left !important
}
#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
}
#open-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 470px;
  float: left;
}
table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
}
table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Safe</td>
        <td>Open</td>

        <td>Cracked</td>
        <td>Late Entry</td>
        <td>Score</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="open-list">
  <h2>Open submissions</h2>
  <table class="open-list">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Author</td>
        <td>Points if Safe</td>
        <td>Points if Cracked</td>
        <td>Language</td>
        <td>Time Remaining</td>
        <td>Link</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="opensubs">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr>
      <td>{{NAME}}</td>
      <td>{{SAFE}}</td>
      <td>{{OPEN}}</td>

      <td>{{CRACKED}}</td>
      <td>{{CLOSED}}</td>
      <td>{{POINTS}}</td>


    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="open-template">
    <tr>
      <td>{{NAME}}</td>
      <td>{{SAFE}}</td>
      <td>{{CRACKED}}</td>
      <td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td>
      <td>{{TIME}}</td>
      <td><a target="_parent" href="{{LINK}}">Link</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'd be extremely impressed if someone manages to crack one of the 8-programs.

Comment: I added a leaderboard, Feel free to edit it if anything isn't right.

Comment: @intrepidcoder Nice work! Thanks (If you enter, I'll give you a 50-rep thank you). Maybe you could implement the second half of ETH's suggestion too? Also, I'm not sure why, but it says that Dennis's score for his submission if cracked is 68 instead of 65.

Comment: "only printable ASCII characters" ... there goes my plan to use left to right overrides to confuse everyone.

Comment: How do you determine the score? I have to post with the following format `Score ###/###`, but what does the second `###` mean?

Comment: @Adriandmen The first score is the number of points you get if you are safe. The second score is the number of points the robber would get if you are cracked.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do with the opposing scoring systems for cops and robbers, but it creates weird incentives. It means that robbers will predominantly try to crack those answers for which the cops wouldn't receive many points anyway, whereas they have much less motivation to tackle those which would give the cop a decent amount of points.

Comment: May programs terminate with an error?

Comment: @mbomb007 No, as errors go to STDERR instead of STDOUT.

Comment: If it's useful for anyone [here is a CJam script](http://goo.gl/35Uvvl) which randomly interleaves any number of programs. Just provide the programs on STDIN, one on each line. If that's not practical (because your programs themselves contain linefeeds), you can choose any other delimiter (`|||` say) and then replace the `N` in the code with a string containing your delimiter, e.g. `"|||"`. (@Eridan feel free to include this in the challenge.)

Comment: can we output to the console? e.g. javascript console?

Comment: @ETHproductions I cracked an (albeit easy) 8-program.

Comment: Honestly, if that one made it I  would have laughed so much.

Comment: Someone pls write a cop so I can try to crack

Comment: @ev3commander Okay ^_^

Answer (score 19):

### [Hexagony](https://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 6 programs, 53 bytes; Score 8/96 (if safe/cracked)

```
  [&;//&z
 ;!X;!!/@!
@)6!< @[!.J
 @a5|9o;""
  |@!!!@]
```

Even if this goes safe, it will be very few points for me, but I thought I'd provide a nice puzzle for robbers to bank some points. :) I have no idea how easy or hard this actually is.

Here are the outputs:

```
Jazz
```

```
XX88XX88
```

```
1234562345610
```

```
111111111111111111111111
```

```
9999999999999999999999999999999999
```

```
66566565665656566565656566565656565665
```

Comment: Holy crap on a cracker. I wish luck and sanity to whoever solves this. +1

Comment: Is the interleaved program valid as well?

Comment: @mbomb007 [This is what it would look like](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=B7C0WLx5) and it terminates immediately, because the `[` switches control to the instruction pointer that starts on the `@` in the left corner.

Comment: **Hex** programs with **Hex**agony!

Comment: @ΚριτικσιΛίθος **Agony** or cracking codes using Hex**agony**!

Comment: This will be safe once you post the programs.

Comment: im trying to crach this right now, can you give me today?

Comment: @Eumel sure, I'm more interested in someone cracking it than those 8 points ;)

Comment: is the first one `/z;;@Ja`?

Comment: @Eumel I don't have the originals with me right now, but if it works, that's very likely. ;)

Comment: do you remember if you used anything bigger than a sidelenght of 2?

Comment: @Eumel I thought the total number of non-space characters would be a good hint towards answering that question. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32403/discussion-between-eumel-and-martin-buttner).

Comment: Is your answer saved? You should reveal the solution.

Comment: @zyabin101 Eumel has cracked half of them, and I wanted to give them a chance to figure out the rest as well.

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64618/45393), 2 programs, 110 bytes; Score -16

```
+(![]+!![])[[]+[]]+(![]+[])+[+[]]+(!![]+[])[[+[]]+[]]+(!![]+[])+[+[]]+(+(![]+!![])[])[+[]]+(![]+[])+[+[]](+[])
```

good luck with this one.

Note: I recommend running on a modern browser (basically not IE)

**Output, first program:**

```
ffttff
```

**Output, second program:**

```
1010
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, safe, 2 programs, 250 bytes; Score 65

#### Interweaved programs

```
"":9(x5M/Cle-Dn,1'AFjsQYirG3@+,~unY</CyUAJ!`L.Xkdq'hF_X&=-`!SnxM!hqv~'GW!4!qIfp$h,ld-;i0JM79Xs'orb@#+sE${?.Eet""""/4M.D:}~Cc^est+2]c9>^W<O%8rR(kg)(ra-P{^Fthm?WF[#KJfRxOe-5zYueb~SiX@tnFyb2-M}G8@0;Z.$u']Qc0R{\.M9V$_NyTc,HR]y""22{{''  ffmm9955bb\\}}****
```

#### Output, first program

```
169004397811215505136757551914260640157209814479670875629464038264532260025741074366481672115039451444875174892900756838476896193165147376670615268045482935802126657286722969566601154866449492847343470441618498401
```

#### Output, second program

```
236156588886135909534842810119847991195053526225488685859715966203756668582804035289768525426132740118856398404195457578486865119219669643999456580063310899697265496162944335336660228420754397359091438096239696929
```

### Solution

#### First program

```
"9(M/l-n'FsQrG@~n<CyA`.XdhF&-`SMhq~W!qI$hd-0M7X'b#sE{Ee""/MD~c^s2]>^O%r(gra{FhmW#KfOezYbSi@Fy-}G0;$u]cR.9V_TcRy"2{' fm95b\}**
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IjkoTS9sLW4nRnNRckdAfm48Q3lBYC5YZGhGJi1gU01ocX5XIXFJJGhkLTBNN1gnYiNzRXtFZSIiL01EfmNeczJdPl5PJXIoZ3Jhe0ZobVcjS2ZPZXpZYlNpQEZ5LX1HMDskdV1jUi45Vl9UY1J5IjJ7JyBmbTk1Ylx9Kio&input=)

#### Second program

```
":x5CeD,1AjYi3+,uY/UJ!Lkq'_X=!nx!v'G4!fp,l;iJ9sor@+$?.t""4.:}Cet+c9W<8Rk)(-P^t?F[JRx-5ue~Xtnb2M8@Z.'Q0{\M$Ny,H]"2{' fm95b\}**
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=Ijp4NUNlRCwxQWpZaTMrLHVZL1VKIUxrcSdfWD0hbnghdidHNCFmcCxsO2lKOXNvckArJD8udCIiNC46fUNldCtjOVc8OFJrKSgtUF50P0ZbSlJ4LTV1ZX5YdG5iMk04QFouJ1Ewe1xNJE55LEhdIjJ7JyBmbTk1Ylx9Kio&input=)

#### How it works

Both programs have this format:

```
 "…""…"2{' fm95b\}**

       2{        }*   Do the following twice:
         'fm            Subtract the char code of ' ' from each character.
            95b         Convert from base 95 to integer.
               \        Swap the two topmost stack elements.
                      This pushes two prime numbers on the stack.
                  *   Compute their product.
```

De-interweaving the programs should require either brute force or factoring the semi-primes.

Comment: Congrats on being the first safe submission!

Comment: I guessed the outputs were semiprimes. Brute-forcing a 213 (decimal) digit semiprime would certainly not be possible on a single machine in a week. This [212-digit one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-704) took [over a year](http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~bai/paper/rsa704.pdf). I doubt brute forcing the interweaving would be feasible either.

Comment: -1 This is against at least the spirit of the "no hashing or cryptography" restriction.

Answer (score 4):

## [BitShift](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BitShift), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64563/41257), 2 programs, 110 bytes; Score -16

#### Interweaved programs

```
10011110011111001011101110110110110110011001100010110000010010011100101111000111100110111101011110011101001100
```

#### Output, first program

```
! ?
```

#### Output, second program

```
? !
```

<sub>I'm so sorry</sub>

Answer (score 4):

## Java, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64576/32700), 2 programs, 155 bytes; Score -16

#### Interleaved programs

```
cliantsesr fai{pce ubc{stlaic sttatiic voidc  mavioin(Sd tmariinn(Stg[rin]g)g{Syst[em]n.)o{ut.prSiysntemtln.out.(prin"Hell"\u002bg.tlen(gth)"By;e!\n}")};}}
```

#### Output, first program

```
Hell0
```

And trailing newline.

#### Output, second program

```
Bye!
```

And trailing newline.

### Original programs

#### First

```
class i{public static void main(String[]g){System.out.println("Hell"\u002bg.length);}}
```

#### Second

```
interface c{static void main(String[]n){System.out.print("Bye!\n");}}
```

Comment: I forgot you could put `interface` instead of `class` until I saw your answer on the Hello, World! challenge. I'll try to crack this during my lunch.

Comment: Ugh, my lunch time is up. I'll try again tonight.

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, safe, 2 programs, 63 bytes; Score 68

#### Interweaved programs

```
V8j5kIqlPN1[C7=3+Z1d=G"<"C38p5)IqdZ21=ZNB;C-jk[C9Zd\</.5n0T1dG2
```

#### First program

Output:

```
 I <3 U
```

Program:

```
jk [C73d"<"3pdC-95T

j                   # Join
 k                  # Standard variable: ""
   [                # Creates a new list
    C73             # Char 73 = I
       d            # Standard variable: " "
        "<"         # String: "<"
           3        # Number 3
            pd      # Prints " ", the leading whitespace
              C     # Char
               -95T # -95T = 95 - 10 = 85. Char 85 = U
```

#### Second program

Output

```
I <3 U2
```

Program:

```
V85IqlPN1=+Z1=GC85)IqZ21=ZNB;jk[CZd\</.n01dG2

                                              # implicit Z = 0
V85                                           # For N in range(85)
   I                                          # If
    qlPN1                                     # Length of the prime factors of N equals 1
         =+Z1                                 # Z = Z + 1
             =GC85                            # G = Char 85 = U
                  )                           # Ends the if statement
                   IqZ21                      # If Z equals 21(th prime)
                        =ZN                   # Z = N (73)
                           B                  # Break out of the for loop
                            ;                 # Infinite ), to close open parentheses
                             jk               # Join ""
                               [              # New list
                                CZ            # Char Z = Char 73 = I
                                  d           # Standard variable: " "
                                   \<         # Single character '<'
                                     /        # Floored division
                                      .n0     # Pi, 3.14159...
                                         1    # Divide by 1 and round down
                                          d   # Standard variable: " "
                                           G  # G = C85 = U
                                            2 # Number 2
```

Comment: remember to write `# Pyth, safe, 2 programs, 63 bytes; Score 68`

Comment: @ev3commander, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 4):

## Befunge, Safe, 2 programs, 228 bytes; Score 65

### Interweaved programs

```
7b*2"!+:,l9ooa"v +2^*<>+:::v,v
  1- v2:,+9 -,\,,<$+":4b*,
v>"i g>:nb:"^,2$+,1'g#
+0^"gs "-*<  :-*,n,
v\,a3+v
-9*b6-3b ,*a<b:u,+|11 B'<
,:+>19v>,:'m+:9,:+3a^:,:a+"c*@9a, >': 'e^
<^;*+<v" gr"< ^
     >@,"+*or:\*:3pa, g"^0>'f^8<;
```

### Output, first program

```
Output, first program
```

### Output, second program

```
Befunge programming is cool!
```

I doubt this will be a easy one to crack. In fact you should just give up now.
Who needs 132 points anyway?

### Answer

Program 1:

```
7b*2+:,9a+2*+:::,1-:,\5-,\,,4b*,v>::,2+,'+0g\1-:,\,3+v
-9*bb,,+1,:+1,:+9,:+3,:+c*9a,: '<^;    @,+*:\*:3a,g08<;
```

> Output, first program

Program 2:

```
"!loo"v ^<>vv
   v2+9 <$+":
>"i gnb"^$1g#
^"s "*<  -*n,
va6-3 *a<b:u|1 B'<
>9v>'m:a^:a"@ >'e^
*+<v"gr"<^
   >"orp "^>'f^
```

> Befunge programming is cool!

Comment: No, no - change that source code back. As soon as you post it, it's the code you use, otherwise, it's unfair.

Comment: @VoteToClose I realized the code had an error and was invalid. I can  change the code or the output text, which would be better?

Comment: Oh. Uh. Never mind then. (insert something about checking code first here) Make sure it's clearly been changed, though.

Comment: <1 hour left for people to try. I gave up already...

Answer (score 4):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64597/44713), 2 programs, 15 bytes; Score -16

#### Interweaved Programs

```
a'5oF'2\\aI/NZO
```

[Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy) is so pretty, so clean. Look into its source, and be awed.

#### Output, first program

```
NaNo
```

#### Output, second program

That's 121 newlines.

Comment: With 32766 possibilities, this is almost brute-force-able :P

Comment: @Eridan I would be so pissed if someone bruted this. Seriously, don't brute force this beauty that is [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy). You must caress it, must take good care of it, nuture it...

Comment: @Eridan Also, that would take 32766 seconds, because Vitsy's a little slow. c:

Comment: It's a nice itsy bitsy Vitsy!

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64597) (fairly and squarely)

Comment: Well that was a lot shorter than 9 hours of brute-forcing

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), safe, 2 programs, 255 bytes; Score 65

#### Interleaved programs

```
aalleerrtt((l=[](+(!l[=[l])+="(l "=l+[]l][[+l>=+1l]]=l+=>(l>l=>l=l<l,")"+l+(l(=l>l>=l)=+ (l)l+= +l)l+=>((ll==l)>(l=l)+l++ ()l+>l()+(l=>l(l===l>l=l)(l()l>=l)+))+""(l +(=""l=+)+(l+l(=)l<)+(=l+)+l++(ll=<<l)+++l)(l+=(=l(==ll)=>l+<l()(ll=))))(l<=l)<l)+(+l<l)))
```

#### Output of First Program

```
false12truetruetruefalse
```

#### Output of Second Program

```
falsefalseundefinedtruetruetruetruefalse116truetruefalse
```

I tried to use the characters `(l)+=<>` as much as possible. The rest is just type conversion.

#### First program

```
alert((l=[l=" "][+l>=+1]=l=>l>=l<l,""+l(l=l>=l)+ +l)+((l>=l++ )+((l=>l=l>=l)(l>=l))+(l="")+(l+=l<=l)+l+(l=l)+(l==(l=>l<l)(l))))
```

#### Second program

```
alert((l=[]+![])+(l=l+[l][l]+(l>=l)+(l>=l)+ (l=l=>l==l)(l)+l(l>l)+(l==l(l))+"" +(l=+l())+(++l<<++l)+(l==l)+(l=(l<=l)<l)+(+l<l)))
```

Comment: Gave you the bounty. Thanks for the leaderboard!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/find-the-interwoven-source-codes-robbers/64760#64760), 2 programs, 255 bytes; Score -16

Good job @Bas! GG.

```
trvya{"fru nxcti;on{;ale"r;Otb(j(fe=c>t(.kfe.yrs(efv)e}rcsate(cf+h(e~)~{ff,=Mast=h>!.posw?f((12),:M"a"t;hal.Ee)r))t)((nfe(wf A(rfr(a0y/(909)) +.f(7/f5il)l()0))+.fma(pf()(x,+`i$,{ff)}=>i`/.s3p)l).ijt`o`.imn(ap"("e)=.>repela.cceh(/ar.Co.d/egA,t""())*)2}3))}
```

### Output 1:

```
36666666666666643333333333333336323666666666666668333333333333333231366666666666666833333333333333323026666666666666682333333333333332292666666666666668233333333333333228266666666666666823333333333333322726666666666666682333333333333332262666666666666668233333333333333225266666666666666823333333333333322426666666666666682333333333333332232666666666666668233333333333333222266666666666666823333333333333322126666666666666682333333333333332201666666666666668133333333333333219166666666666666813333333333333321816666666666666681333333333333332171666666666666668133333333333333216166666666666666613333333333333341516666666666666661333333333333334141666666666666666133333333333333413166666666666666613333333333333341216666666666666661333333333333334111666666666666666133333333333333410666666666666666333333333333334966666666666666633333333333333486666666666666673333333333333337666666666666667333333333333333666666666666666733333333333333356666666666666673333333333333334666666666666666533333333333333353666666666666666533333333333333352666666666666666733333333333333331666666666666666633333333333333330
```

### Output 2:

```
2645,1403,1426,759,2645,1449,2346,920,1127,943,1334,782,782
```

Comment: [cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64760/41257)

Comment: @Bas indeed! Nice work.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64751/41859), 2 programs, 71 bytes; Score -16

**Interleaved**

```
$ec=tchR;$ho =qs;$cu=$ho.$tc.e_me.$tha(.'p^l/it]';e.cchoo.$c('[$$h'));;
```

**Output**

*1st program*

```
Array
```

*2nd program*

```
\^/\]co\[\$
```

---

<sup>**Note**: `Notices` should be suppressed.</sup>

Comment: Are you sure this isn't missing one space?

Comment: @primo *Argh*, you're right. I have fixed it. Sorry. I assume you've cracked it already? :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64751/4098).

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64726/2537), 2 programs, 64 bytes; Score -16

**Interleaved**

```
p w,%=?(w.ord,40,?)(;"jb inv inv is{2").bytes{|*b|?aput%?c} b-w}
```

**Output**

*1st program*

```
"bananas"
```

*2nd program*

```
BANANAS
```

Both outputs have trailing newlines.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64726/2537).

Answer (score 3):

## Malbolge, 2 programs, 194 bytes; Score 65

### Interweaved

```
D'`D$'#`pK~A5:]|3!W1ICw;A|RXsWP0xgN;BLeJmd[c#bGa!`3p%n$BS9?~m*,+N)6ii9E%CAxw"Y!Xtbslw2SR|n^gf)9ex+ZLphuan`s_l%F2bS[ZRYn}@gVfUey+SL;QPba`O_s^$[MZR_K^JWO{N>G=kY.XJQuCHUAT@65d>QJ&nN<0;FjJ,H@G@9d]JQ
```

### Output 1

```
haha nope
```

### Output 2

```
malbolge
```

---

It was only a matter of time.

## Programs

### O1

```
D'`A:]\!I;|XWxgBedcba`pn9m*6iiE%CA"!bw|^)9xZpunsl2SRngfe+Lba`_^$\[Z_^W{>=YXQuUT65QJnN0FjJ,HG@dQ
```

### O2

```
D'`$#pK\~5|3W1CwARsP0N;LJm[#G!3%$BS?~,+N)9xwYXtsl2SRngfe+Lha`_%Fb[ZY}@VUyS;QPOsMRKJONGk.JCHA@d>&<;@9]J
```

Comment: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5wUr4Lut4A](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5wUr4Lut4A)

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, safe, 2 programs, 102 bytes; Score 66

```
sprint""@(u{[|<$/{W)xor$^ldH&~!<]#3,/H-61+e#]l#:l7o#3:3}>]3$^WS}[_$#:,=(~s#30-)3;)^#,]$")]>=">reverse]
```

---

**First Output**

```
Hello, World!
```

**Second Output**

```
Hello, World!
```

---

**Solution**

First Program:

> `print@{[<{World!,Hello}>]}[$,=~s)),$")=>rvrs]`

Second Program:

> `s""(u|$/)x$^H&~<]#3/-61+#]#:7#3:33$^WS_#:(#30-3;^#]]>"eee`

Comment: Is your answer saved? Say so in the header.

Comment: @zyabin101 done.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 2 programs, 61 bytes; Score 68/36 (if safe/cracked)

**Interleaved programs**

```
*vsC{`.m`DsPCd..[Gn9`T2vjkpv`/JmsC\Pid~T.n1tt`.VJp~T%n*TCG731
```

**Output, first program**

```
491670984540320247032212137862815
```

**Output, second program**

```
46252265449938954198657919684976120662891392853344868455756073
1063494620552721403954429737131814326362865215612332412466411486182225511644503132172962643458535768453543651970155938693047567602310634946205527214039544297371318143263628652156123324124664114861822255116445031321729626434585357684535
```

Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Frankly, that looks terrible. Then again, I don't know Pyth very well.

Comment: Well done me, I've lost the source code.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/Japt), safe, 3 programs, 63 bytes; Score 36

The version of the interpreter that this was built for can be found [here](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=8e7dc20f23074b672116cbf5dfd52d55c1660ca4). Unfortunately, I've lost the originals, so I'll have to see if I can crack it myself...

#### Interweaved programs

```
"AARoooLv mLv m@(_y6Xpp33*  ay%2%|v2n"+95+'H+2   m@(Xdcq)q -A d
```

#### Output 1

```
112221174199804510029601998159214179608538147196191138431341951029363738456410116231158105100149362111411782137669714451962921697122751841161758017110476673747582101138199681951421371867326511541191741031345182116631134159
```

That's *222* digits, in case you were wondering.

#### Output 2

```
R!2,tR+dE34N('QM!2'e4Xx;e>+2YGaNsw`4Xs,Gk?(,Q>XFmta:d'Gk:xm~RNxwQklZ;tM+sm~M?ZEea?dw~ !(;`
```

#### Output 3

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Is your answer saved? You'd reveal the solution already.

Comment: @zyabin101 This is safe, but I've lost the solution. Plus, it doesn't even work with the current version of Japt! I'll add a link for the old version, then see if I can crack it myself.

Answer (score 2):

## [Microscript II](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Microscript_II), safe, 2 programs, 44 bytes; score 68

Interleaved sources:

```
6$4sv{{3@0s>s"`+`"}s<s3320s*{1+s+K+s<}*p}*h`
```

Output, first program:

```
>=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"! >=<;:9876543210/.-,+*)('&%$#"!
```

Output, second program:

```
[5.477225575051661,2.340347319320716,1.5298193747370035,1.2368586720951604,1.1121414802511236,1.0545811871312343,1.026928034056542,1.0133745773683798,1.0066650770580947,1.0033270040510693,1.001662120702919,1.0008307153074985,1.0004152714285695,1.0002076141624645,1.0001038016938364,1.000051899500139,1.0000259494133834,1.0000129746225213,1.0000064872902181,1.0000032436398485,1.0000016218186092,1.0000008109089757,1.0000004054544056,1.0000002027271822,1.000000101363586,1.0000000506817917,1.0000000253408956,1.0000000126704478,1.000000006335224,1.000000003167612]
```

---

And here's the answer:

Program 1:

```
64s{30s>""s<32s{1+s>K+s<}*p}*h
```

Program 2:

```
$v{@s`+`}s30*`
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64705/41859), 3 programs, 31 bytes; Score -16

This should be an easy one using 3 programs.

**Interleaved**

```
print ppprrriiinnnttt!!$x'0';;;
```

**Output**

*1st program*

```
1
```

*2nd program*

```
1
```

*3rd program*

```
1
```

---

<sup>**Note**: `Notices` should be suppressed.</sup>

Comment: Assuming notices are to be ignored (as in your other answer), [you've been cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/find-the-interwoven-source-codes-robbers/64705#64705).

Comment: @SuperJedi224 You're right. I've updated the answer. And nice solution. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, safe, 2 programs, 106 bytes; Score 66

```
alert(2ale98374rt("q883wope2jv+sjn[d]s^234j8kfdk7j9b|12f8ns7"[9]98+"jskfsd3"2+13()3892721+[]+{}*6^5|27&3))
```

#### Output 1

```
-35655169
```

#### Output 2

```
njskfsd7
```

### Solution

#### Program 1

```
alert(2983748832+[]^234879|1287983213)
```

#### Program 2

```
alert("qwopejvsjndsjkfdkjbfns"[9]+"jskfsd"+(3892721+[]+{}*6^5|27&3))
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 2 programs, 225 bytes; Score 65/132 (if safe/cracked)

Interweaved:

```
 alaelretrt((((cb=>c=>b.replace(/.replace[a-(/[azA-Z]-z]/gi/g,a,s=>String=>String.fromCharCode(s.fromCharCode(("Z">=a.charCodeAt(0)?90:122)>=(a=a.charCodeAt(0+(s.toLowerCase())+13)?a<'n'?13:-13:a-26)))))))((""gfvbznfcyrg""))))
```

First output:

```
simple
```

Second output:

```
toast
```

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65391/42545) Thanks for a good puzzle.

Answer (score 2):

## Brainfuck, 4 programs, 251 bytes; 17/144 (if safe/cracked)

**Interweaved programs**

```
--[+++++--+[----++[+-->+[+++++><-]--++->->---<>--]<]+>><.+-+[-+.--[+-++]+.>->-+.-+-.>-+<-<][]>[----+---+>->->.-+<+<]]>>+--..++----+-++-.---+--++-+..----.-----.-.--.--++..-+++++.++-+++[-++-[-->>++++++<+]<>-+.++]++>.+[->++++.<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.------.
```

**Output, first program**

`Eridan`

**Output, second program**

`Ampora`

**Output, third program**

`PPCG`

**Output, fourth program**

`Code Golf`

Comment: What is the specific Brainfuck variant, e.g. is there any cell wrapping/overflow, are the cells 0..255 or unlimited, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy/tree/b66ca18fca2f2cf0076c1788d363cf0c795fd810), 4 programs, 228 bytes; Score 17

(Uses an older version, which is linked)

Heeeyyyy @VoteToClose. I don't expect this one to be up long, but you never know… I love your language, now that I'm using it a lot!

### Interweaved program

```
1E2P-0P1E^l*312359121E4/13+1*-205+-5Pv*92t\9\[931[2-\D+\*12/]1N5*[t22*^50\+[\72C]\[[2r***t]PC^s]]2TNL2l\*2v2-D2E12[+48/3*-]2\**v+i8+1D+++NL*5N]-*4Z525L5L2*26E/-{'^2N6+l"015v52\2[{v/\[1*12]/r+^ZDs"6p'TO2N{^v]1v{\/3N\[52*]*4-^*N\*
```

## Output 1

```
2014794345195992700000000000000000000000000.00000049.2129129367736101
```

## Output 2

```
679:;=>@ABDEFHIJLMNPQSTUWXY[\]_`b
```

## Output 3

```
44.5'+26
```

## Output 4

```
100000.315464876785728777498798913309289000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

---

Good luck! I used the online interpreter, but it should work in the safe jar.

---

## Programs

## O1

```
El94+*2+Pt*t7\[rP^]N2248*2*8**2LLE{^N0v\[v1+DpN{v]v\N
```

## O2

```
EPP^*E/3-05-v\[32\[52]***vDE2/-v++]Z
```

## O3

```
12-1313111159991-\+12/152*0+\[2*]2Ll2-1+\+DN5-552*/-'+"5522\[*]rZ"6'O
```

## O4

```
0252*2\[D*]N2^\[CtCs]T2\[3]*i1++LN452626l1{/12/^sT2^1{/3\[52*]*4-^*N\*
```

Comment: :D I didn't see this until just now! *fangirls* Just about to go to sleep as well, but I'll work on it.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you're using a certain version... ;)

Comment: @VoteToClose Oh, yeah, right.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 2 programs, 255 bytes; Score 65/132 (if safe/cracked)

```
a=c(([]o[0]+[][0n]+[][0]s+[][0o]+"l")e+(((new .Date)+"l").osplit(" g")[8])+"".match((/aa/)+t([0o][1]+"b")).split(")").join("('").split("bn");Vconssole.blog(aA=[1]=.toUpperCase()+a[7]+a[13]+" '))"+a[4].toUpperCase()+"`"+a[5]+" "+a[15]+a[16]+a[17;]+a[018]);
```

First program output:

```
And I`m fine
```

Second Program output:

```
null
```

The second programs output is text and not JavaScript's:`null`

This should be easy for the robbers.

Comment: Is your answer saved? Reveal the solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Candy, safe, 2 programs, 85 bytes; Score 66

See: [Candy](https://github.com/dale6john/candy)

```
75~z43+/k20*416+k-1612+1++k2
8343-k92k*4+5k~7*Ak70kR(4122
5612=x53bAR2((hkDXhZ*h)))ZZ??
```

Outputs:

`51450000`

`1609944`

Update:  This is the two programs followed by their interleaving:

```
7 ~z4  /k 0 41 +k  612   +k28 4 -k92k 4 5k~  Ak70k  41225612  53   2(  kD  Z*h)  Z  ?
 5   3+  2 *  6  -1   +1+    3 3     * +   7*     R(        =x  bAR  (h  Xh    )) Z?
75~z43+/k20*416+k-1612+1++k28343-k92k*4+5k~7*Ak70kR(41225612=x53bAR2((hkDXhZ*h)))ZZ??
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Foo](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Foo), 6 programs, 197 bytes; Score 5/192 (if safe/cracked)

Interweaved code:

```
&(@@11&5@@756&@04$+110)c5*@@1$*1+c52$&&@+15*@@2c$(c61>(51/6+10)@<*2$0c*-$0+6c*$6@1$+$c-01c@1c4$c$@/2&-)$50c++c(+$@2*$c2($+6c+c>0*(>+42&$1c+1$6+c--2@<$<5)c>$c>+7$$cc)-<++1+11$$cc)@2(32/$c)&+5*2$c"B"
```

Output from 1st program:

```
   
@ 
B
```

Note the tab on first line and trailing space on second line

Output from 2nd program:

```
<83.-
```

Note that the first line is blank

Output from 3rd program:

```
<=$)
```

Output from 4th program:

```
72}
```

Output from 5th program:

```
$#%*+&
```

Output from 6th program:

```
Foo
```

There is only one interpreter for Foo which i know of, you can find it [here](http://foo.tryitonline.net/)

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. Great first answer. If you need any help with the site, reply by including `@wizzwizz4` in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, safe 2 programs, 148 bytes; Score 65

```
execexec'prin'""it`sum(map(ormpd,(stor.rparrt""('""thellitio"on.__n"'ame_)'_*".3**/7".__len.__()re)pl[ace++-2(]))**061`[+*+2]'.re'"_pl'a)ce(*"+:")
```

Output 1:

```
Hello world...
```

Output 2:

```
188381387815229576775053627587460257651836527329727069542076068076585927926328856199896
```

Program 1:

```
exec'""import""(\'""hello""\')'.replace(*'"_')
```

Program 2:

```
exec'print`sum(map(ord,(str.rpartition.__name__*".3**/7".__len__())[++-2]))**061`[++2]'.replace(*"+:")
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 8 programs, 233 bytes; Score 2/384 (if safe/cracked)

OK, now I'm being evil:

```
aalaaalaalllelreeereatlrterlreer(trtr(t(("t(t(!ft(!u\(untc!(y!t[0![p(!ty2!0p6ioee]a[8+0[0tbon(\o!fuo0)fb0 0 |(|h!6["t!Z5y!{!ze"[)0pb}b]01e]+"+")"+o\uo[]0]o0b1f110 al)]4d+1")+)]cl)"("\o!fu0u))0.4slc\incu00c6e(4,f"t)8))ion(){}+![])+"")
```

1st Output:

```
false
```

2nd Output:

```
true
```

3rd Output:

```
heLLo
```

4th Output:

```
2015
```

5th Output:

```
0
```

6th Output:

```
good
```

7th Output:

```
fine
```

8th Output:

```
string
```

Comment: The snippet says 2/384 as the score.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 8 programs, 92 bytes; Score: -16

Another easy one:

```
ppprirnriipnnprtp rrpti"piirnrinio"ntt n n"bt"Tunht" t"is ""dot n"t ohhe"el""w lo"aleal"l"s"
```

8 outputs:

```
This

hello

well

no

alas

but

oh

done
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64521/find-the-interwoven-source-codes-robbers/65241#65241). BTW, you don't need to put spaces after `print` in Python 2.

Comment: That was quick, this was probably the easiest answer.