# Find the Interwoven Source Codes (Robbers)

Tags: code-golf, cops-and-robbers

This is the robbers' thread. For the cops' thread, go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64520/find-the-nested-source-codes-cops).

## Introduction

For this Cops/Robbers challenge, the cops will write output-producing programs and interweave them together. It is the robber's job to pick apart the cops' programs to produce the desired outputs.

## Robber rules

Robbers will try to find the different programs that people post in submissions to the cops' thread (linked above). If a robber solves a cop's code, they must post the separated programs and match them with their outputs in an answer here and post that they have cracked the code on the cop's answer.

## Scoring

There are two components that are added together when scoring a cracked submission.

- 2 to the power of the number of different programs used in the cop's answer
- Round the number of bytes in the interweaving **down** to the nearest power of 2.

For example, if a robber cracks `TIliGoEnR` as being `TIGER` and `lion`, then the robber receives 2^2+8=12 points.

The winner of the robbers' challenge will be the person with the most points after a sufficient period of time for people to participate.

---

(Who wants to help with a snippet?)

Answer (score 6):

## [Vitsy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64590), 12 points

```
'o'2\I/NO
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=J28nMlxJL05P&input=)

```
a5F\aZ
```

[Try it online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=YTVGXGFa&input=)

The `NaN` in `NaNo` was a dead giveaway.

The obvious way to push `NaN` would be to divide **0** by itself, `2\I` pushes the input length (**0**) twice, `/` performs division, and `N` prints a float.

We're left with printing `o`, and `'o'` is a string literal that `O` prints.

Whatever characters were left had to belong to the other program. In fact, `a` pushes a linefeed, `5F` the factorial of **5** (**120**), `\a` turns that into 120 linefeeds, and `Z` prints the entire stack.

Comment: So fancy, so beautiful. Well done. +1

Answer (score 4):

## [BitShift](https://esolangs.org/wiki/BitShift), 2^2 + 64=68 points

[cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64556/46249)

```
0101100110110101001001010110111011101110111011101101010
```

prints `! ?`

```
1011101110111011101110110101000000000110010101101101010
```

prints `? !`

#### Code

```
0101100110110101001001010110111011101110111011101101010 # '! ?'
01011001101101010 # '! '
0101              # XOR 0 with 128 
                  # Making current value 128 (1000 0000)
    10            # Bitshift 1 to left making 10000000 -> 01000000
      01          # Bitshift 1 to left making 01000000 -> 00100000  
        101       # XOR 00100000 with 1 making it 00100001
           101010 # print 00100000 which is binary for !
010010101         #
010               # XOR 00100001 with 1 making it 00100000
   010101         # print 00100000 which is binary for <space>
10111011101110111011101101010  # '?'
101               # XOR 00100000 with 1
   1              # Bitshift 1 to left making 00100001 -> 01000010
                      # This gets repeated till 01000010 becomes 0111111
101010                # print 0111111 which is binary for ?
```

I will add some description later(split the code in the parts that print individual parts)

Comment: Can someone explain how to calculate the score I don't quite understand the calculation

Comment: Well done. The score is calculated by `2^programs + 256/bytes=points`. In this case it's `2^2 + 256/128=6 points`. I think this will be edited though, because as it is now, fewer byte count programs receive a higher bonus for robbers. Which feels off

Comment: @Bas As of yesterday, that was changed.

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64638), 68 points

```php
$c=tR;$h=s;$c=$h.$c._.$h.plit;echo$c($h);
```

Output: `Array`

```php
echo quotemeta('^/]'.co.'[$');
```

Output: `\^/\]co\[\$`

---

I like this submission, because it relies on a few lesser know features - one might say *misfeatures* - of PHP. PHP allows function references to be assigned to variables, so for example:

```php
$f = function($a, $b) { return pow($a, $b); };
echo $f(2, 4);
```

would do exactly what you expect. As would:

```php
$f = pow;
echo $f(2, 4);
```

...except it's not doing what you think. `$f = pow` does not assign a function reference to `$f` (that would make too much sense, right?), but rather the *string* `'pow'`. The implication is that any string may be used as a function call, if it represents the name of a defined function. Bad code waiting to happen. I don't even know why you'd *want* to allow this.

Another misfeature of PHP, is that function names and keywords are case-insensitive. I wish I were joking. So `echo pow(2, 4)`, `ECHO POW(2, 4)`, and `EcHo PoW(2,4)` are all functionally equivalent.

The last misfeature on showcase is that whenever an array is typed as a string, such as for printing, the result is always the amazingly helpful string `Array`. Take a moment to reflect on the fact that someone actually did this deliberately.

So in the first program, @insertusernamehere builds up the string `stR_split`, this string is used as a function reference (which, for reasons above, actually works), and the result, an array, is output.

Comment: Nice work that comes with a great explanation. :)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 68 points

[Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64598/45393)

#### First program

Output: `ffttff`

```
(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]]+(![]+[])[+[]]
```

#### Second program

Output: `1010`

```
+!![]+[+[]]+(+!![])+(+[])
```

#### Interweaving

```
+     !!    []             +                [    +[]]          +      (+     !![])                 +     (+[])
 (![]+  [])[  +[]]+(![]+[]) [+[]]+(!![]+[])[ +[]]    +(!![]+[]) [+[]]+  (![]+     [])[+[]]+(![]+[]) [+[]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64699/2537), 68 points

First:

```
p %w(b n n s)*?a%?}
```

Second:

```
w,=?(.ord,40,?);"jivivi{2".bytes{|b|putc b-w}
```

It followed pretty naturally from working out the end, with `putc`.

Comment: Whoops, I had a slightly different intended solution with one more weird syntax trick, but I guess I'll keep that in my back pocket for another challenge. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 132 points

[Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64568/34388)

First program:

```
interface c{static void main(String[]g){System.out.println("Hell"\u002bg.length);}}
```

Second program:

```
class i{public static void main(String[]n){System.out.print("Bye!\n");}}
```

The first program outputs `Hell0` and the second program outputs `Bye!`

Comment: Ah, I was an hour too late. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

## [Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64622/41257), 132 points

#### Program 1

```
var x;{;alert((f=>(f.reverse(f+~~f,Math.pow(2,Math.E))))(new Array(99).fill(0).map((x,i,f)=>i/3)).join("").replace(/../g,""))}
```

#### Program 2

```
try{"function";Object.keys(f)}catch(e){f=s=>!s?f(1):"";alert(f(f(f(0/0) +f(7/5)))+f(f)+`${f}`.split``.map(e=>e.charCodeAt()*23))}
```

Whew. This was terrible.

After a lot of debugging I found out that after calling (parts of) the 2nd program, it wouldn't run again. This is because the global variable `f` was still assigned. Because of `f` being assigned, the try/catch didn't fail on `Object.keys(f)`. I don't know if this is a sneaky trick or unintentional but it caused me a headache.

Also, I believe the output of the first program is platform specific.
`/../g` removes all characters on my machine, because of the regex `.` which means any character. Escaping it with `/\../g` works however, I hope someone can shed more light onto this. Also, my output is prone to rounding errors, perhaps some global javascript variable can change this?

**Output**

```
32666666666666643233333333333336323166666666666668313333333333333231306666666666666830333333333333323029666666666666682933333333333332292866666666666668283333333333333228276666666666666827333333333333322726666666666666682633333333333332262566666666666668253333333333333225246666666666666824333333333333322423666666666666682333333333333332232266666666666668223333333333333222216666666666666821333333333333322120666666666666682033333333333332201966666666666668193333333333333219186666666666666818333333333333321817666666666666681733333333333332171666666666666668163333333333333216156666666666666615333333333333341514666666666666661433333333333334141366666666666666133333333333333413126666666666666612333333333333341211666666666666661133333333333334111066666666666666103333333333333410966666666666666933333333333334986666666666666683333333333333487666666666666677333333333333337666666666666667633333333333333656666666666666753333333333333354666666666666674333333333333334366666666666666533333333333333353266666666666666523333333333333352166666666666666713333333333333331066666666666666603333333333333330
```

This was tested on chrome 46 (my only browser), Windows 7.

I hope this is still a valid submission, despite the different output

Comment: There was a slash in there, I don't know how it was missed. Good job, though! This is correct. I will update my submission when I am not on mobile ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (ES6)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/65088/42545), 68 points

#### Program 1

```
alert((c=>c.replace(/[a-z]/gi,a=>String.fromCharCode(("Z">=a?90:122)>=(a=a.charCodeAt(0)+13)?a:a-26)))("fvzcyr"))
```

#### Program 2

```
alert((b=>b.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g,s=>String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0)+(s.toLowerCase()<'n'?13:-13))))("gbnfg"))
```

#### Interweaved programs

```
 alaelretrt((((cb=>c=>b.replace(/.replace[a-(/[azA-Z]-z]/gi/g,a,s=>String=>String.fromCharCode(s.fromCharCode(("Z">=a.charCodeAt(0)?90:122)>=(a=a.charCodeAt(0+(s.toLowerCase())+13)?a<'n'?13:-13:a-26)))))))((""gfvbznfcyrg""))))
 al e r t  ( ( c =>c             .replace   (/[a     -z]/gi  ,a  =>String                       .fromCharCode(("Z">=a              ?90:122)>=(a=a.charCodeAt(0                 )+13)?a           :a-26)))    ( "  fv z  cyr " ))
   a l e rt ( ( b   =>b.replace(/        [a-    zA-Z]      /g  ,s        =>String.fromCharCode(s                     .charCodeAt(0)                           +(s.toLowerCase()       <'n'?13:-13        )))) ( "g  b nf   g "  ))
```

This would've been a lot harder, had the cop torn apart the keywords. ;)

Comment: I manually interwove it and got lazy, but good job. I tried being sneaky. Oh well. Actually thank you for cracking this one because I lost The original unweaved programs somehow.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64696/39022), 24 points

Program 1

```
print!0;
```

Program 2

```
print!$x;
```

Program 3

```
print print'';
```

Tested with http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64520/find-the-interweaved-source-codes-cops/65231#65231), 320 points

```
print "This"
print "hello"
print "well"
print "no"
print "alas"
print "but"
print "oh"
print "done"
```