# Reversed Engineered from Uniqueness (Robber's Thread)

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, cops-and-robbers

Given the output of the cop's program (`o`), the byte-count (`n`) and the number of unique bytes (`c`) used, come up with a corresponding piece of code that is `n` bytes long with `c` unique bytes which matches the cop's output `o`.

---

## This is the ***robbers thread***. Post solutions that you cracked here.

## [The COPS thread is located here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147635/36398).

---

Robbers should post solutions like this:

```
#[Language], `n` Bytes, `c` Unique Bytes (Cracked)[Original Link to Cop Thread]

    [Solution]
    
(Explanation)
```

---

## Rules

- You may not take any input for your program.
- The program must use at least 1 byte, but cannot exceed 255 bytes.
- The output itself is also limited to 255 bytes.
- The program must have consistent output results when executed multiple times.
- If your submission is not cracked within 7 days, you may mark it as "safe".

  - When marking it safe, post the intended solution and score it as `c*n`.

## Winning

- The uncracked post with the lowest `c*n` score, wins the cop's thread.
- Whomever cracks the most wins the robbers thread, with earliest crack breaking the tie.
- This will be decided after 10 safe answers, or a few weeks.

## Caveats

- If you feel cocky, you may tell the user the algorithm using a ***spoiler*** tag.

---

Note: Also, please remember to upvote cracks, they're usually the impressive part.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes, 4 unique bytes, [Stewie Griffin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147648/36398)

```
1X2p
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zDCqOD/fwA)

#### Explanation

```
1X2   % Push predefined literal: string 'double'
p     % Product of array. For strings it uses code points. Implicit display
```

Comment: You know all the predefined literals... I don't... It wasn't exactly the same as I had, but it was of course the product of `'double'`. :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Ah, I see, so you used something like `1X%p`. Actually I only know a few predefined literals. I brute-forced with `9:"@X1pD` changing `X` and `1`

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 97 Bytes, 34 Unique Bytes, [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147659/73904)

```
interface Fillerrrrrrrrrrr{static void main(String...a){System.out.println(1.4241570377303032);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcgxDoMwDEDRq2SEoRYQqgzdewFOYIFBpsFBwSAhlLMHtv63/RkPfIWVZB5@ObMoxRF7Ml/2nuK/a1NU7s0ReDALshSdRpYJALC8unNTWiDsCutz1UtRQ9u09dtV1jlbPZryk1LONw)

Super innovative crack, spent hours on it

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes, 3 unique, [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147650/67312)

```
FFFTZF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/383NLSTK7f9/AA)

I immediately recognized the output

```
1+0i 0+1i -1+0i 0-1i
```

as the 4-th roots of unity, and I knew that the `fft` on `[0 0 0 1]` would result in this.

It took me quite a while to figure out that `FFFT` would push `[0 0 0 1]` <s>and I'm still not sure how it works.</s> EDIT: Luis Mendo explained that `F` and `T` are "sticky", so a sequence of `F` and `T` will automatically `horzcat` them together, hence, `FFFT` pushes `[0 0 0 1]`.

This is expressed succinctly in the documentation (once I looked it up):

> For logical row vectors the square brackets can be omitted; that is, the notation
>   `[T F T]` or `[TFT]` can be simplified to `TFT`. A separator may be needed if a new
>   logical array follows: `TFT TT`. But it’s not necessary in other cases: `TFT3.5`.

Comment: `F` and `T` are "sticky". So `FFT` defines a row vector `[false, false, true]`

Comment: @LuisMendo thank you, that is clear now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 29 bytes, 15 unique, [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147876/71256)

```hs
f<$>[1..74]
f 47='4'
f f1='3'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfXFKUmZeuYKsQ8z/NRsUu2lBPz9wklitNwcTcVt1EHchIM7RVN1b/n5uYmQdUVlBaElxSpADR9v9fclpOYnrxf93kggIA)

I previously had the two nearly solutions:

```hs
do;d<-[2..74];'3':['4'|d==47]    -- 29,16
do;d<-[-41..31];'3':['4'|d==4]   -- 30,15
```

Comment: ahh, Laikoni’s comment led me to think the answer needed to be a single expression… closest I got was `["34"!!(0^x^2)|x<-[-46..27]]` (28, 18).

Comment: also, I had no idea you could place a semicolon right after `do` like that!

Comment: Yes, I had a space there for a long time before guessing it might be valid.

Comment: @Lynn Laikoni has claimed that the solution *is* a single expression in chat

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), [Brian H.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147662/58563)

*Thanks [@Milk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58106/milk) for fixing the last trailing '5'*

```js
f=f=>1/44.4

console.log(f())
```

Unique characters: `.`, `/`, `1`, `4`, `=`, `>`, `f`

Comment: This one outputs the extra 5 at the end: `_=_=>1/44.4`

Comment: @milk That looks better indeed. Let me know if you'd like to post it and I'll delete this one.

Comment: That's cool, you can just update your post if you want. I got this from building off your crack.

Comment: said it was an easy one :p

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147734/71256)

```hs
0x90090009
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfqWCrEPPfoMLSwACIDCz/5yZm5gHFCooy80oUMv//S07LSUwv/q@bXFAAAA)

I feel like I got lucky here...

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 8 bytes, 3 unique, [Jenny_mathy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147732)

```
7!!!/77!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/99cUVFR39xc8f///7oFRZl5JQA)

Breakdown: `Factorial[7!!] / Factorial[77]` where `!!` is double factorial.

First I notice the long sequence of `0` at the end so I guess it may be some kind of factorial. `FactorInteger` gives the largest factor `103`, so I try `n/103!`, and get the next largest (negative) prime factor is `73`. Tweaking the factors for some time gives `105!/77!`, then I think "there are already 3 symbols `7`, `!` and `/`, so the way to create 105 must be from those symbols!". So I tried `7!!` (which is one of a few things to try) and get 105 as the correct result.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 62 total bytes, 6 unique, [Wheat Wizard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147636/57100)

```
(((((((()()()){}){}){}){}){}){(({})[()])}{})({{()({}[()])}{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMKNEFQs7oWFWloAMloDc1YzVogQ6O6GqiquhYmUKv5/z8A)

Comment: Good job! That's not what I had intended but it works!

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes, 5 unique bytes, [Shaggy's submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147727/73884)

```
10l Ä
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/39AgR@Fwy///AA)

Simple enough: 3628801 is 10! (`10l`) plus one (`Ä`).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes, 6 unique, [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147651/53748)

- For some reason I started with a trailing zero in the result. Without it I would have given
`8,16!PP`
as a solution.

---

```
8,⁴!PP0
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99C51HjFsWAAIP//wE)**

#### How?

```
8,⁴!PP0 - Main link of a program taking no arguments and no input
  ⁴     - literal sixteen
8       - literal eight
 ,      - pair = [8,16]
   !    - factorial (vectorises) = [8!, 16!] = [40320, 20922789888000]
    P   - product = 40320 × 20922789888000 = 843606888284160000
     P  - product (no effect) = 843606888284160000
      0 - literal zero (just gets printed)
        - leaving STDOUT displaying 8436068882841600000, as required
```

...`8,⁴!’P` for 6 bytes, 6 unique would have been much harder to crack since the result of `843585965494231681` <sub>(**40319 × 2092278988799**)</sub> does not look so factorial-based.

Comment: Alternative: `8µḤ!×! ` (with trailing space)

Comment: Or `8,⁴!P` with 2 trailing spaces (Or `q` or some other unimplemented byte)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), 3 unique [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147761/53748)

```
ȷc⁵
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///E9uRHjVv//wcA)**

#### How?

```
ȷc⁵ - Main link: no arguments, no input
ȷ   - literal one-thousand
  ⁵ - literal ten
 c  - choose (A.K.A. binomial coefficient) = 263409560461970212832400 as required.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 7 Bytes, 5 Unique Bytes, [AdmBorkBork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147716/64121)

```powershell
1PB#---
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3zDASVlXV/f/fwA)

The output `1125899906842624` is equal to `2^50` and `2^50 Bytes` is equal to `1 Pebibyte`.
The actual code is just 3 bytes, therefore I added a comment at the end.

Comment: Nice. I had thought tacking on a comment would toss people for a loop, but looks like I was wrong. :)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 22 bytes, 16 unique bytes, [EngineerToast](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147672)

A possible solution is:

```
=BAHTTEXT(2^(480-300))
```

The unique characters are `=BAHTEX()^02348-`.

I recognized that BAHTTEXT was used when seeing the output. By translating the output back from Thai to English, I was able to find the value of the number. I guessed it to be a power of 2, which it indeed is (namely 2<sup>180</sup>). The expression 480-300=180 was then constructed to make sure the solution contains 22 bytes with 16 unique.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 9 bytes, 8 unique bytes, [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147886/69059)

```
/Yr@
\no/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/ssiBKyYvX///fwA)

Unfolded, this is `nrYo@`.

```
n  negate the implicit empty string: creates the string "Jabberwocky".
r  range expansion: produces a string that starts with J, 
   goes up in ASCII order to w, down to c, and then up to y.
Y  separate this string into even and odd positions
o  output the even positions
@  terminate
```

Incidentally, the orientation of the mirrors in the first column is completely irrelevant, so this could easily be reduced to 7 unique bytes.

Comment: You're right about the mirrors! I've become too rusty with Alice :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell, Laikoni, 30 bytes, 17 unique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/148105/3852)

```
show.length.show=<<['\0'..'0']
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 4 bytes, 4 unique, cracks [emanresu A's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233768/101522)

```
ka¦²
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=d&code=ka%C2%A6%C2%B2&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Nice! How did you get tins?

Comment: @emanresuA I saw every letter of the alphabet, so I knew there was `ka`, which by itself was half the program. Then I noticed that there was a pattern of `a..., a... b..., a... b... c..., a... b... c... d..., etc.`, so I knew there was `¦`, for prefixes. From there, the only thing I knew of that created that specific pattern was multiplying strings together, so I thought about `*`, `e`, and `Π`, before remembering that `²` doesn't vectorise properly, and would multiply the strings instead of splitting them. It really just came down to knowing the quirks of the commands.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 8 bytes, 6 unique bytes, [Bolce Bussiere](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149613/78410)

```
;p.p:i.9
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKegnqZga6WuoKNQa6VgoADE/60L9AqsMvUs/2v@TwMA)

Output:

```
23 _0.677447j0.296961 _0.677447j_0.296961 0.125003j0.726137 0.125003j_0.726137 _0.379097j0.630438 _0.379097j_0.630438 0.518498j0.521654 0.518498j_0.521654
```

The obvious hint is that, in the given output, complex numbers always appear as conjugate pairs. It made me suspect the `p.` verb, which converts between plain polynomial and multiplier-and-roots forms.

So I tried:

```
p. 23;(...those complex numbers)
   2 3 5 7.00001 11 13 17 19 23
```

Yes, my thought was correct. The list of primes is easy. Monadic `;` flattens the list of boxed arrays to simple linear one. The resulting expression has two p's and two dots, so the byte count is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 4 bytes, 3 unique bytes, [Tom Carpenter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147743/36398)

```matlab
j^7j
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/K8486/9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), 6 unique, [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/147667/53748)

```
7x7²¤ḌḤ²
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARgA5/9qZWxsef//N3g3wrLCpOG4jOG4pMKy//8)**

#### How?

```
7x7²¤ḌḤ² - Main link: no arguments & no input
7        - literal 7
    ¤    - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
  7      -   literal 7
   ²     -   square -> 49
 x       - repeat elements -> [7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7]
     Ḍ   - convert from a decimal list -> 7777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777
      Ḥ  - double -> 15555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555554
       ² - square -> 241975308641975308641975308641975308641975308641926913580246913580246913580246913580246913580246916
         - implicit print
```