# Calculate Standard Deviation

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, statistics

### Challenge

Given a list of numbers, calculate the population standard deviation of the list.

Use the following equation to calculate population standard deviation:

[image]

### Input

The input will a list of integers in any format (list, string, etc.). Some examples:

```
56,54,89,87
67,54,86,67
```

The numbers will always be integers.

Input will be to STDIN or function arguments.

### Output

The output must be a floating point number.

### Rules

You may use built in functions to find the standard deviation.

Your answer can be either a full program or a function.

### Examples

```
10035, 436844, 42463, 44774 => 175656.78441352615

45,67,32,98,11,3 => 32.530327730015607

1,1,1,1,1,1 => 0.0
```

### Winning

The shortest program or function wins.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=60901,OVERRIDE_USER=30525;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: You mean the output must be a floating point OR integer?

Comment: I think most build-in standard deviation functions calculates the the sample standard deviation.

Comment: What about if input list is void?175656.78441352615 result to me 175656.78441352614

Comment: @RosLuP You don't have to worry about that

Comment: Does the code need to have some provision for taking input? For example, in Matlab you could do std(x), where x is the list of numbers. So do I need to have code that asks the user for input (prompt, etc)?

Comment: @a13a22 As per PPCG's standard rules, you are fine to take input via function arguments

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [Clip](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), 3

```
.sk
```

`.s` is the standard deviation, `k` parses the input in the form `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: What formula is used for the standard deviation? I could not find it int he reference.

Comment: @flawr It's [this chart](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip#Constants), towards the bottom.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I saw that, but there is no formula given.

Comment: @flawr Oh, I see. Perhaps then it is up to the interpreter, if such a thing exists.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I found it [here](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/clip-language/subversion/source/10/trunk/Clip/src/language/LArray.java) on line 493, it seems to be ok!

Comment: @flawr That's great! Nice reference. Worries aside, this is a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 12):

## Mathematica, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

Nice, Mathematica has a built-in `StandardDevi...` oh... that computes the sample standard deviation, not the population standard deviation.

But what if we use `Variance`... oh... same deal.

But there is yet another related built-in:

```
CentralMoment[#,2]^.5&
```

Yay. :)

This also works for 22 bytes:

```
Mean[(#-Mean@#)^2]^.5&
```

And this for 27:

```
N@RootMeanSquare[#-Mean@#]&
```

Answer (score 10):

## Octave, 14 bytes

```
g=@(a)std(a,1)
```

Try it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/noczhf).

Comment: You can save two bytes by removing `g=` since the function handle doesn't need a name to be a valid submission.

Answer (score 10):

## [kdb+](http://kx.com/software-download.php), 3 bytes

```
dev
```

One of the APL derviates *had to* have this as a built-in.

#### Test run

```
q)dev 56, 54, 89, 87
16.53028
q)f:dev
q)f 10035, 436844, 42463, 44774
175656.8
q)f 45,67,32,98,11,3
32.53033
```

Answer (score 8):

## Dyalog APL, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
*∘.5∘M×⍨-M×M←+/÷≢
```

This defines an unnamed, monadic function train, which is equivalent to the following function.

```
{.5*⍨M(×⍨⍵)-M⍵×(M←{(+/⍵)÷≢⍵})⍵}
```

Try them online on [TryAPL](http://tryapl.org/?a=%28%20%28*%u2218.5%u2218M%D7%u2368-M%D7M%u2190+/%F7%u2262%29%20%2C%20%7B.5*%u2368M%28%D7%u2368%u2375%29-M%u2375%D7%28M%u2190%7B%28+/%u2375%29%F7%u2262%u2375%7D%29%u2375%7D%20%29%2056%2054%2089%2087&run).

#### How it works

The code consists of several trains.

```
M←+/÷≢
```

This defines a monadic 3-train (fork) `M` that executes `+/` (sum of all elements) and `≢` (length) for the right argument, then applies `÷` (division) to the results, returning the arithmetic mean of the input.

```
M×M
```

This is another fork that applies `M` to the right argument, repeats this a second time, and applies `×` (product) to the results, returning **μ<sup>2</sup>**.

```
×⍨-(M×M)
```

This is yet another fork that calculates the square of the arithmetic mean as explained before, applies `×⍨` (product with itself) to the right argument, and finally applies `-` (difference) to the results.

For input **(x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>N</sub>)**, this function returns **(x<sub>1</sub> - μ<sup>2</sup>, …, x<sub>N</sub> - μ<sup>2</sup>)**.

```
*∘.5∘M
```

This composed function is applies `M` to its right argument, then `*∘.5`. The latter uses right argument currying to apply map input `a` to `a*0.5` (square root of `a`).

```
(*∘.5∘M)(×⍨-(M×M))
```

Finally, we have this monadic 2-train (atop), which applies the right function first, then the left to its result, calculating the standard deviation as follows.

[image: formula]

Answer (score 6):

## R, <s>41</s> <s>40</s> <s>39</s> <s>36</s> <s>30</s> 28 bytes

#### code

Thanks to [beaker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42892/beaker), [Alex A.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20469/alex-a) and [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31347/mickyt) for much bytes.

```
cat(sd(c(v=scan(),mean(v))))
```

#### old codes

```
v=scan();n=length(v);sd(v)/(n/(n-1))**0.5
m=scan();cat(sqrt(sum(mean((m-mean(m))^2))))
m=scan();cat(mean((m-mean(m))^2)^.5)
```

This should yield the population standard deviation.

Comment: I think this does not output the required result: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/25961/43450

Comment: I don't know R, but would it be possible to augment the input array with the mean of the array? It seems that might be shorter.

Comment: @beaker I am not sure, I think it is not possible but I am no expert.

Comment: On this site we typically can't assume a REPL environment unless explicitly allowed by the question. Thus in this case you'll need to use `cat` to print to the console.

Comment: Also, R uses `^` for exponentiation, which is a byte shorter than `**`.

Comment: @AlexA. Thats true! I don't know how but I had some problems with `^` a while ago and totaly forgot it, thank you Alex.

Comment: You don't need to sum the mean since `mean` returns a scalar; `sum` has no effect. 36 bytes: `x=scan();cat(mean((x-mean(x))^2)^.5)`

Comment: @MickyT that doesn't seems to work, it says it can't find `x`

Comment: @AndréMuta apologies, when I tested it I had an X hanging around.

Comment: @AlexA. too much information, thanks for the edit.

Comment: The scan can be moved in, but there are no savings unfortunately `cat(mean(((x=scan())-mean(x))^2)^.5)` since it would need to be bracketed.

Comment: Well you taught me something new at least @MickyT. ;)

Comment: @AndréMuta I was talking about doing something like this: `v <- c(v,mean(v))` (I think this is correct) and then taking the standard deviation of the updated list.

Comment: @beaker you are a genious.

Comment: @beaker very nice

Answer (score 5):

## CJam, <s>24</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

```
q~_,_@_:+d@/f-:mh\mq/
```

*Thanks to @aditsu for golfing off 1 byte!*

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_%2C_%40_%3A%2Bd%40%2Ff-%3Amh%5Cmq%2F&input=%5B56%2054%2089%2087%5D).

#### How it works

```
q~                    e# Read all input and evaluate it.
  _,                  e# Copy the array and push its length.
    _@                e# Copy the length and rotate the array on top.
      _:+d            e# Copy the array and compute its sum. Cast to Double.
          @/          e# Rotate the length on top and divide the sum by it.
            f-        e# Subtract the result (μ) from the array's elements.
              :mh     e# Reduce by hypotenuse.
                      e# a b mh -> sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
                      e# sqrt(a^2 + b^2) c mh -> sqrt(sqrt(a^2 + b^2)^2 + c^2)
                      e#                           = sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)
                      e# ⋮
                 \mq/ e# Divide the result by the square root of the length.
```

Comment: I think you can convert just the length to double

Comment: @aditsu Of course. Thanks!

Comment: `:mh` is genius btw :)

Comment: `Reduce by hypotenuse.` isn't something you see every day.

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
@.O^R2-R.OQQ2
```

*Thanks to @FryAmTheEggman for golfing off 4 bytes!*

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%40.O%5ER2-R.OQQ2&input=56%2C54%2C89%2C87)

#### How it works

```
        .OQ    Compute the arithmetic mean of the input (Q).
      -R   Q   Subtract the arithmetic mean of all elements of Q.
   ^R2         Square each resulting difference.
 .O            Compute the arithmetic mean of the squared differences.
@           2  Apply square root.
```

Comment: I like how the decomposition of a Pyth program looks like a skewed parabola.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>26</s> 19 bytes

```julia
x->std([x;mean(x)])
```

This creates an unnamed function that accepts an array and returns a float.

Ungolfed, I guess:

```julia
function f(x::Array{Int,1})
    # Return the sample standard deviation (denominator N-1) of
    # the input with the mean of the input appended to the end.
    # This corrects the denominator to N without affecting the
    # mean.
    std([x; mean(x)])
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, 7 bytes

```
stdDev(augment(Ans,{mean(Ans
```

I borrowed the algorithm to get population standard deviation from sample standard deviation from [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/stddev).

The shortest solution I could find without `augment(` is 9 bytes:

```
stdDev(Ans√(1-1/dim(Ans
```

Comment: I agree with AndréMuta, this does not produce the required result, see [here.](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/stddev)

Comment: @AndréMuta @flawr TI's builtin `stdDev(` calculates the sample SD; `stdDev(augment(Ans,{mean(Ans` computes the population SD. That's on the page you linked to.

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 24 bytes

```
{.5*⍨+/(2*⍨⍵-+/⍵÷≢⍵)÷≢⍵}
```

A little different approach than [Dennis' Dyalog APL solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60913/20469). This should work with any APL implementation.

This creates an unnamed monadic function that computes the vector (*x* - *µ*)<sup>2</sup> as `2*⍨⍵-+/⍵÷≢⍵`, divides this by *N* (`÷≢⍵`), takes the sum of this vector using `+/`, and then takes the square root (`.5*⍨`).

[Try it online](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B.5*%u2368+/%282*%u2368%u2375-+/%u2375%F7%u2262%u2375%29%F7%u2262%u2375%7D%2045%2067%2032%2098%2011%203&run)

Comment: Not every APL implementation supports `{`dfns`}`, `⍨`, or `≢`. However, *every* version supports `R←F Y` `R←(+/((Y-+/Y÷⍴Y)*2)÷⍴Y)*.5`

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.4+, 30 bytes

```py
from statistics import*;pstdev
```

Imports the builtin function `pstdev`, e.g.

```py
>>> pstdev([56,54,89,87])
16.53027525481654
```

Comment: I think just `pstdev` after the first line is ok? I believe xnor did that a while ago with `sum`. It sort of makes sense wrt how anonymous lambdas would be used i.e. `p=pstdev` or `map(pstdev, [...])`

Comment: I was going to say the same thing. Meta posts seem to support just putting a function literal.

Comment: I think you still need to write the literal `pstdev` though, like `from statistics import*;pstdev`. Otherwise, this could be any function from that library.

Comment: @xnor Edited. tbh I'm not really sure about the ruling on these situations...

Comment: Maybe a meta question would be helpful? :)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 61 bytes

```
d n=1/sum(n>>[1])
f a=sqrt$d a*sum(map((^2).(-)(d a*sum a))a)
```

Straightforward, except maybe my custom length function `sum(n>>[1])` to trick Haskell's strict type system.

Comment: You can use `sum(1<$n)` and `<$>` for `map`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that those functions might not be present because of an older GHC version at the time of this answer, but according to [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52949/56433) they were introduced to prelude in March 2015, and the site policy has changed anyway to allow newer language features.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

**11 bytes**

```
S÷L
Ç²_²ÇN½
```

This is a direct translation of [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60913) to Jelly. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=U8O3TArDh8KyX8Kyw4dOwr0&input=&args=NDUsNjcsMzIsOTgsMTEsMw)

#### How it works

```
S÷L        Helper link. Argument: z (vector)

S          Compute the sum of z.
  L        Compute the length of z.
 ÷         Divide the former by the latter.
           This computes the mean of z.

Ç²_²ÇN½    Main link. Argument: z (vector)

Ç          Apply the previous link, i.e., compute the mean of z.
 ²         Square the mean.
   ²       Square all number in z.
  _        Subtract each squared number from the squared mean.
    Ç      Take the mean of the resulting vector.
     N     Multiply it by -1.
      ½    Take the square root of the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, 18 bytes

```
[:%:@M*:-M*M=:+/%#
```

This is a direct translation of [my APL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60913) to J.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulEG2lauXgq2Wl66vla2ulra@q/D81OSNfIU3BxFTBzFzB2EjB0kLB0FDB@D8A)

Comment: I had no idea `M` was a predefined built in.

Comment: It isn't. `M=:+/%#` is an inline function definition.

Comment: But it's predefined, right? Perhaps builtin is the wrong term

Comment: No, it's not predefined. `M=:+/%#` saves the verb `+/%#` in `M`, then calls it.

Comment: I am sorry XD I didn't see the last part

Comment: That link doesn't work anymore. Could you perhaps move it to https://tio.run/nexus/J ? I would, but I don't know enough about J to setup the input correctly/verify it still works.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Done. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Haha, no problem. I came across it [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/36498).

Comment: Yes, I saw. The post author gets a notification when an edit it suggested.

Comment: [16 bytes](https://tio.run/##RYhBCoMwFAX3nuKh1GCtaeJ/JvZDoCB01Wx6iCx6/31MV2WYxcy39tYUJIXBDQ7aXCyOz/tV82j1qk9dctL5fhnqVAu8c7KBEnYSXBkEZIzsCrghRMiKxw7vIW35P786AQ "J – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## Prolog (SWI), 119 bytes

**Code:**

```
q(U,X,A):-A is(X-U)^2.
p(L):-sumlist(L,S),length(L,I),U is S/I,maplist(q(U),L,A),sumlist(A,B),C is sqrt(B/I),write(C).
```

**Explanation:**

```
q(U,X,A):-A is(X-U)^2.   % calc squared difference of X and U
p(L):-sumlist(L,S),      % sum input list
      length(L,I),       % length of input list
      U is S/I,          % set U to the mean value of input list
      maplist(q(U),L,A), % set A to the list of squared differences of input and mean
      sumlist(A,B),      % sum squared differences list
      C is sqrt(B/I),    % divide sum of squares by length of list
      write(C).          % print answer
```

**Example:**

```
p([10035, 436844, 42463, 44774]).
175656.78441352615
```

Try it out online [here](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/dzwqjuYT.pl)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
(?)i=sum.map(^i)
f l=sqrt$2?l/0?l-(1?l/0?l)^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X8NeM9O2uDRXLzexQCMuU5MrTSHHtriwqETFyD5H38A@R1fDEMLQjDP6n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCikKYQbWKqY2auY2ykY2mhY2ioYxz7/19yWk5ievF/3eSCAgA)

The value `i?l` is the sum of the i'th powers of elements in `l`, so that `0?l` is the length and `1?l` is the sum.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>10</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅA-nÅAt
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@ovs*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKujbh6QKPn/P9rCWMfQ0EzH0hxMGRqaxgIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/8Otjrp5QKLkv87/6GhDAwNjUx0TYzMLExMdEyMTM2MdExNzc5NYnWgTUx0zcx1jIx1LCx1DQx1joJChDhzGxgIA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅA       # Get the arithmetic mean of the (implicit) input-list
  -      # Subtract it from each value in the (implicit) input-list
   n     # Square each of those
    ÅA   # Take the arithmetic mean of that
      t  # And take the square-root of that
         # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Just found this challenge, [`ÅA-nÅAt`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKujbh6QKPn/P9rCWMfQ0EzH0hxMGRqaxgIA) is a more literal implementation of the given formula at 7 bytes. (This scores about 404 points in the other challenge)

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), [<s>19</s> <s>18</s> 14 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
¯‡iʠØbmÅQƥªÈªÆ
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Oi9tZWFuKG57OipuLW1lYW46c31c&input=MTAwMzUgNDM2ODQ0IDQyNDYzIDQ0Nzc0CjQ1IDY3IDMyIDk4IDExIDMKMSAxIDEgMSAxIDE=)

## Explained

Unpacked: `:/mean(n{:*n-mean:s}\`

```
:/                      Square root
  mean                  Mean function
    (                   Begin expression
        n{              Block with key of n
          :*            Square
              n
            -           Subtraction
              mean
                    _   Variable initialized to STDIN; implied
                  :s    Split on spaces
         }              End of block
       \                Mapped over
         _              Implied
    )                   End of expression; Implied
```

Comment: I'm very intrigued by *Arn* as a cool new different language.  But am I getting it wrong or is the compression ('packing') quite inefficient?  The 'unpacked' code is only 21 characters, including 2x the word 'mean' (which surely must be a single-byte token (?)) and 1x parenthesis (which could be completely avoided by rearranging to RPN), so I would have guessed that the 'packed' code would be at most 14 characters long.  What am I missing?

Comment: Packing does not use that method of compression (mainly because most of the time you are NOT using a single word, but rather punctuation 90% of the time). Because of this, I essentially had two options for compression; pack the 7-bit characters into 8-bit characters (11% compression) or do something a bit stranger. The latter involves converting the ascii into a massive number (base 95) and then reading it off into a codepage, which results in approximately a 17% compression rate. Naturally, I chose option B here. That is why the compression doesn’t seem nearly as efficient as you thought.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  It's particularly interesting to hear other languages' strategies now that there's a new 'golf a golfing language' challenge!  Could you (or do you) at least reduce the text of 'mean' to 'M' (or 'ME' once you run-out of one-character function names) before doing the base95->256 compression, though?

Comment: I’ve considered shortening function names, but so far I haven’t. If a user wanted to shorten it manually, they could do this: m(_):=.mean

Comment: However, what you suggested is a good idea, and so I’ll test it out a bit

Comment: Cool.  You wouldn't actually need to shorten the names in the unpacked code: the 'packing' could first shorten names, and then base-95->256 compress.  Then you'd have the win-win situation of a golfy language that's actually readable (at least, before packing)!

Comment: When will there be an Arn manual page or 'how-to'?

Comment: There is one, it can be found [here](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki). If anything isn't clear just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 16 bytes

```
⟨∋-⟨+/l⟩⟩ᶠ^₂ᵐ↰₂√
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8FY86unWBlLZ@zqP5K4Ho4bYFcY@amh5unfCobQOQ8ahj1v//0YYGBsamOgomxmYWJiZA2sjEzBhImZibm8T@jwIA) [(all cases at once)](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/9H8FY86unWBlLZ@zqP5K4Ho4bYFcSAVWyeAlbY86pj1/390tKGBgbGpjoKJsZmFiQmQNjIxMwZSJubmJrE6CtEmpjpm5jrGRjqWFjqGhjrGIDFDHTgEcU3NdExNdCwsdSzMQVygchDXDKgvNhYA)

I feel like *maybe* there's some shorter way to compute the squared deviations than 13 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 73 bytes

```
a=>Math.sqrt(a.reduce((b,c)=>b+(d=c-eval(a.join`+`)/(l=a.length))*d,0)/l)
```

Comment: @BetaDecay Regarding precision of the output? My original actually didn't have that correct, and I fixed it right after, only to discover floating point was ok hehe... So is it good now as it is?

Comment: Yeah that's fine :)

Comment: Psst... you can shave off 5 bytes by using this summing method `eval(a.join\`+\`)` instead of  `a.reduce((e,f)=>e+f)`

Comment: @GeorgeReith Nice trick! I'm going to have to remember that one for later...

Comment: @StevenPenny It seems to work for me.

Comment: @TheFourthMarshal this answer is using the naive algorithm https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Na%C3%AFve_algorithm - so it wont really be useful outside the scope of this answer

Answer (score 1):

## [Simplex v.0.5](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Simplex/), 43 bytes

Just 'cuz. I really need to golf this one more byte.

```
t[@u@RvR]lR1RD@wA@T@{j@@SR2ERpR}u@vR@TR1UEo   
t[      ]                                     ~~ Applies inner function to entire strip (left-to-right)
  @                                           ~~ Copies current value to register
   u                                          ~~ Goes up a strip level
    @                                         ~~ Dumps the register on the current byte
     R                                        ~~ Proceeds right (s1)
      v                                       ~~ Goes back down
       R                                      ~~ Proceeds right (s0)
                                              ~~ Go right until an empty byte is found
         lR1RD                                ~~ Push length, 1, and divide.
              @                               ~~ Store result in register (1/N)
               wA                             ~~ Applies A (add) to each byte, (right-to-left)
                 @T@                          ~~ Puts 1/N down, multiplies it, and copies it to the register
                    {          }              ~~ Repeats until a zero-byte is met
                     j@@                      ~~ inserts a new byte and places register on it
                        SR                    ~~ Subtract it from the current byte and moves right
                          2E                  ~~ Squares result
                            RpR               ~~ Moves to the recently-created cell, deletes it, and continues
                                u@v           ~~ takes 1/N again into register
                                   R@T        ~~ multiplies it by the new sum
                                      R1UE    ~~ takes the square root of previous
                                          o   ~~ output as number
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl5, <s>39</s> 38

---

16 for the script
+22 for the `M` switch
+ 1 for the `E` switch
=39

```
perl -MStatistics::Lite=:all -E"say stddevp@ARGV" .1 .2 300
```

Tested in Strawberry 5.20.2.

---

Oh, but then I realized that you said our answers can be functions instead of programs. In that case,

```
{use Statistics::Lite":all";stddevp@_}
```

has just 38. Tested in Strawberry 5.20.2 as

```
print sub{use Statistics::Lite":all";stddevp@_}->( .1, .2, 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), <s>10</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ë_▓-²▓√
```

Port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210034/52210).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///w6vhH0ybrHtoEJB91zPr/39DAwNhUwcTYzMLERMHEyMTMWMHExNzchMvEVMHMXMHYSMHSQsHQUMGYy1ABDgE)

**Explanation:**

```python
ë        # Read all inputs as float-list
 _       # Duplicate that list
  ▓      # Get the average of that list
   -     # Subtract that average from each value in the list
    ²    # Square each value
     ▓   # Take the average of that again
      √  # And take the square root of that
         # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 105 bytes

```
> Input
>> #1
>> ∑1
>> 3÷2
>> L-4
>> L²
>> Each 5 1
>> Each 6 7
>> ∑8
>> 9÷2
>> √10
>> Output 11
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMvOTkHZEEQ@6pgIpo0PbzcC0T66JmDq0CYQ5ZqYnKFgqmAIZ5spmEN1WYBoS6iuRx2zDA1ADP/SEqDxCoaG//9HGxoYGJvqKJgYm1mYmABpIxMzYyBlYm5uEgsA)

In the latest version of Whispers, the builtin [`σ`](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers/blob/master/whispers%20v3.py#L1474) can be used to shave off around 70 bytes.

### How it works

For those unfamiliar with Whispers, the language works by using numbers as line references in order to pass values between lines. For example, the line `>> 3÷2` doesn't calculate \$3 \div 2\$, rather it takes the values of lines **3** and **2** and calculates their division. Execution always begins on the last line.

This program simply implements the standard formula for standard deviation:

$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}{(x_i-\bar{x})^2}}$$
$$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}{x_i}$$

Lines **2**, **3** and **4** define \$\bar{x}\$, with it's specific value accessible on line **4**. Line **2** stores \$N\$. We then calculate \$(x_i-\bar{x})^2\$ for each \$x_i \in x\$ with the lines **5**, **6**, **7** and **8**:

```
>> L-4
>> L²
>> Each 5 1
>> Each 6 7
```

Line **7** runs line **5** over each element in the input, which takes the difference between each element in the input and the mean, We then square these differences using lines **8** and **6**. Finally, we take the sum of these squares (line **9**), divide by \$N\$ (line **10**) and take the square root (line **11**). Finally, we output this result.

Answer (score 1):

## [Shasta <sup>v0.0.10</sup>](https://github.com/jacobofbrooklyn/shasta/tree/d66d19a634eb70bd73feac1972327867a7f0ede4), 65 bytes

```
{(**(/(sum(map${|x|(**(- x(/(sum$)(length$)))2)}))(length$)).5)}
```

Online interpreter not set up yet, tested on my machine

Explanation:

`{...}` Function taking argument $

`(** ... .5)` Square root of

`(/ ... (length $))` Dividing ... by the length of $

`(sum ...)` The sum of

`(map $ {|x| ...})` Mapping each x in $ to

`(** ... 2)` The square of

`(- x ...)` The difference between x and

`(/ (sum $) (length $))` The mean of $

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 57 bytes

```
lambda l:(sum((x-sum(l)/len(l))**2for x in l)/len(l))**.5
```

Takes input as a list

Thanks @xnor

Comment: I think you can do `.5` in place of `0.5` to save a byte. Also do you mean `len(x)` instead of `len(l)`?

Comment: @AlexA. Uhh, no I don't think so...

Comment: Sorry, got confused. Disregard the `x` and `l` nonsense. But you can still do `.5` to save a byte.

Comment: @BetaDecay It's shorter to use a list-comp than to map a lambda: `sum((x-sum(l)/len(l))**2for x in l)`.

Comment: A different formulation gave the same length: `lambda l:(sum(x*x*len(l)for x in l)-sum(l)**2)**.5/len(l)`.

Answer (score 0):

#### PowerShell, 122

```
:\>type stddev.ps1
$y=0;$z=$args -split",";$a=($z|?{$_});$c=$a.Count;$a|%{$y+=$_};$b=$y/$c;$a|%{$x+
=(($_-$b)*($_-$b))/$c};[math]::pow($x,0.5)
```

explanation

```
<#
$y=0                            init
$z=$args -split","              split delim ,
$a=($z|? {$_})                  remove empty items
$c=$a.Count                     count items
$a|%{$y+=$_}                    sum
$b=$y/$c                        average
$a|%{$x+=(($_-$b)*($_-$b))/$c}  sum of squares/count
[math]::pow($x,0.5)             result
#>
```

result

```
:\>powershell -nologo -f stddev.ps1 45,67,32,98,11,3
32.5303277300156

:\>powershell -nologo -f stddev.ps1 45,  67,32,98,11,3
32.5303277300156

:\>powershell -nologo -f stddev.ps1 45,  67,32, 98 ,11,3
32.5303277300156

:\>powershell -nologo -f stddev.ps1 10035, 436844, 42463, 44774
175656.784413526

:\>powershell -nologo -f stddev.ps1 1,1,1,1,1,1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran, 138 bytes

Just a straightforward implementation of the equation in Fortran:

```
double precision function std(x)
integer,dimension(:),intent(in) :: x
std = norm2(dble(x-sum(x)/size(x)))/sqrt(dble(size(x)))
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 105 bytes (as a function)

I just noticed it's allowed to be a function. Whoops, that reduces my answer dramatically. This defines a function `S` which takes an array and returns the population standard deviation. Go read the other one for an explanation, but skip the parsing part. I don't want to do it again.

```
DEF S(L)N=LEN(L)FOR I=0TO N-1U=U+L[I]NEXT
U=1/N*U FOR I=0TO N-1T=T+POW(L[I]-U,2)NEXT RETURN SQR(1/N*T)END
```

### As a program, 212 bytes

Unfortunately, I have to take the input list as a string and parse it myself. This adds over 100 bytes to the answer, so if some input format other than a comma-separated list is allowed I'd be glad to hear it. Also note that because `VAL` is buggy, having a space *before* the comma or trailing the string breaks the program. After the comma or at the start of the string is fine.

```
DIM L[0]LINPUT L$@L I=INSTR(O,L$,",")IF I>-1THEN PUSH L,VAL(MID$(L$,O,I-O))O=I+1GOTO@L ELSE PUSH L,VAL(MID$(L$,O,LEN(L$)-O))
N=LEN(L)FOR I=0TO N-1U=U+L[I]NEXT
U=1/N*U FOR I=0TO N-1T=T+POW(L[I]-U,2)NEXT?SQR(1/N*T)
```

Ungolfed and explained:

```
DIM L[0]  'define our array
LINPUT L$ 'grab string from input

'parse list
'could've used something cleaner, like a REPEAT, but this was shorter
@L
I=INSTR(O,L$,",")                 'find next comma
IF I>-1 THEN                      'we have a comma
 PUSH L,VAL(MID$(L$,O,I-O))       'get substring of number, parse & store
 O=I+1                            'set next search location
 GOTO @L                          'go again
ELSE                              'we don't have a comma
 PUSH L,VAL(MID$(L$,O,LEN(L$)-O)) 'eat rest of string, parse & store
ENDIF                             'end

N=LEN(L) 'how many numbers we have

'find U
'sum all of the numbers, mult by 1/N
FOR I=0 TO N-1
 U=U+L[I]
NEXT
U=1/N*U

'calculate our popstdev
'sum(pow(x-u,2))
FOR I=0 TO N-1
 T=T+POW(L[I]-U,2)
NEXT
PRINT SQR(1/N*T) 'sqrt(1/n*sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 137 bytes

```
m(a:List Float):Complex Float==(#a=0=>%i;reduce(+,a)/#a)
s(a:List Float):Complex Float==(#a=0=>%i;n:=m(a);sqrt(m([(x-n)^2 for x in a])))
```

The function m() would return the mean of the list in input. Both the functions on error return %i the imaginary constant sqrt(-1).
Code for test and results. [but the result if it is ok, it is the real part of one complex number]

```
(6) -> s([45,67,32,98,11,3])
   (6)  32.5303277300 15604966

(7) -> s([10035,436844,42463,44774])
   (7)  175656.7844135261 4035

(8) -> s([1,1,1,1,1,1])
   (8)  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda l,N:(sum((i-sum(l)/N)**2for i in l)/N)**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc1BDoIwEIXhNZxili0ZldJpiyRegQtgFxglNCmFIC48fS2GvMWffJu3fLdxDjIOt3v0/fR49uCxbdj7MzHmTns8v7S8KKphXsGBC3DAWcWd/E5dJ8pSKgSSuiZKrUjLFDKGLOYZQEcKtUFZ4bVGIVAeLPA/a5s8W1YXNjYwj@BfIT1zHn8)

Takes in `l`, a list of integers, and `N`, the number of integers present.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki), 13 bytes

```
←Đ↔Ł↔Đµ-²Ʃ⇹/√
```

Implements the formula for standard deviation

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 80 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU5NS8NAEL3vr5jjDKyxiR@1kQ0IXgQ9iadSyrZN6spmN@5MFSn57XGjc3pfzHu8t95Orh9iEuCZFL2V92Kr4u6j3Qu8WBfgrNSX9dDVz45l/RRkY5rHeNr5FszkTXOeXTa4AIlQUX4xoDON/wND/MatdkQFn3q6588kyFjRJeOCLmaXsfxnuiIaJ6UADm0Hfa5Gm45cw0NK9mf9KsmF44ZqeAtOwORdkG/IqviAHc7z8PpGw@1Sw1WlYXWnoSwzJqKcHZUap18)

```scala
l=>{val s=(0 to 2).map(i=>l.map(pow(_,i)).sum);sqrt(s(2)/s(0)-pow(s(1)/s(0),2))}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBPS8MwGMbv/RTPMYFY106dK3gQvAz0NDwNkWxrt0iadkmqiOyz1zcZHWXsEpL3lzx/4jZSy75v1l/lxuNNKoO/JAG2ZYW2@SntsquZKrAwXkAr5wu80rqi8wcv8NJ0a13iiV4g4rSWLXNBlHZ@n5IG@xRQnKeuqwfliunrOmQelL6lBl2f0OAcYkL@fEyzMc0uaT6meaQRj7K5g/UsXr09ud3gInl0OUGBnAeD49Chpr9i0u5cgWdr5e9q6a0yu9Dm3Sh/7tLS1GvDKhYKs7t7gYeZwJQyzR8FMko@5YP0Men7fw)

```scala
object Main {

  def powerSum(i: Int, list: List[Int]): Double =
    list.map(scala.math.pow(_, i)).sum

  def f(l: List[Int]): Double = {
    val sum0 = powerSum(0, l)
    val sum1 = powerSum(1, l)
    val sum2 = powerSum(2, l)

    scala.math.sqrt(sum2 / sum0 - scala.math.pow(sum1 / sum0, 2))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(List(45, 67, 32, 98, 11, 3)))
  }

}
```