# Novel Prime Factors of Repunits

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, primes, factoring

#### The Background

Folks were talking prime factorization in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240/15-17) and we found ourselves talking about repunits. [Repunits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) are a subset of the numbers known as repdigits, which are numbers consisting of only repeating digits, like `222` or `4444444444444444`, but repunits consist only of `1`.

The first couple repunits are therefore `1`, `11`, `111`, etc. These are referred to by *R*<sub>n</sub>, so *R*<sub>1</sub>=`1`, *R*<sub>2</sub>=`11`, etc., and are generated by the formula `R(n) = (10^n - 1)/9`, with `n > 0`.

Prime factorization of these repunit numbers follows sequence [A102380](https://oeis.org/A102380) in the OEIS. For example:

> R<sub>1</sub> = 1
>   R<sub>2</sub> = 11
>   R<sub>3</sub> = 111 = 3 * 37
>   R<sub>4</sub> = 1111 = 11 * 101
>   R<sub>5</sub> = 11111 = 41 * 271
>   R<sub>6</sub> = 111111 = 3 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 37
>   R<sub>7</sub> = 1111111 = 239 * 4649
>   ...

#### The Challenge

Write a program or function which, when given an input integer *n* with `n >= 2` via [STDIN or equivalent](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1326/42963), outputs or returns the [novel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/novel#novel-2) prime factors for *R*<sub>n</sub>, in any convenient format. "Novel prime factors" here means all `x` where `x` is a prime factor of *R*<sub>n</sub>, but `x` is not a prime factor for any previous *R*<sub>k</sub>, with `1 <= k < n` (i.e., if we write the prime factors for all *R* in sequence, we've not seen `x` before).

#### The Examples

```
Input: 6
Output: 7, 13
(because 3, 11, and 37 are factors of a smaller R_k)

Input: 19
Output: 1111111111111111111
(because R_19 is prime, so no other factors)

Input: 24
Output: 99990001
(because 3, 7, 11, 13, 37, 73, 101, 137, 9901 are factors of a smaller R_k)

Input: 29
Output: 3191, 16763, 43037, 62003, 77843839397
(because no factors of R_29 are also factors of a smaller R_k)
```

#### The Extras:

- Your code can do anything or nothing if `n < 2`.
- You can assume a "reasonable" upper limit for `n` for testing and execution purposes -- your code will not be *expected* to output for `n = 10000000`, for example, but your algorithm should *work* for such a case if given unlimited computing power and time.
- [Here](http://stdkmd.com/nrr/repunit/) is a site dedicated to the factorizations of repunits for reference.
- I've not gone through the math, but I propose a hypothesis that every *n* has a distinct result for this algorithm -- that is, no *n* exists such that *R*<sub>n</sub> has no novel factors. <s>I'll offer a **250-point bounty** if someone proves or disproves that in their answer.</s> Thomas Kwa proposed an [elegant proof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67111/42963), and I awarded the bounty.

Comment: Built-in prime checking and factorisation are fair game?

Comment: @MartinBüttner No restrictions.

Comment: [OEIS A204845](http://oeis.org/A204845)

Comment: @alephalpha Because of course there's an OEIS link ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Your link to reference factorizations is stale. [worldofnumbers: repunits: Sources](http://www.worldofnumbers.com/repunits.htm) has good links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>16</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
-F_m{P/^Td9SQ
```

As best I can tell, 19 takes forever.

```
-F_m{P/^Td9SQ      Implicit: Q = input
           SQ      Inclusive range 1 to Q
                        Implicit lambda d:
    {P                  unique primes dividing
       ^Td              10**d
      /   9                  //9
   m               map lambda over the range
   m{P/^Td9SQ      Unique prime factors of all repunits up to the Qth
  _                Reverse the list
-F                 Reduce by set difference
```

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-F_mP%2F%5ETd9SQ&input=6&debug=1).

Comment: If you run it from the command line and have SymPy installed, 19 completes in under a second. The first one that takes over 2 seconds is the input 38.

Answer (score 12):

## Proof that every repunit has a novel prime factor

Using [Zsigmondy's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem), the proof is simple. From Wikipedia:

> In number theory, Zsigmondy's theorem, named after Karl Zsigmondy,
> states that if ***a > b > 0*** are coprime integers, then for any integer ***n
> ≥ 1***, there is a prime number ***p*** (called a primitive prime divisor) that
> divides ***a<sup>n</sup> − b<sup>n</sup>*** and does not divide ***a<sup>k</sup> − b<sup>k</sup>*** for any positive integer ***k
> < n***, with the following exceptions: [things that don't apply here].

Consider the repunits times 9: that is, ***10<sup>n</sup>-1***. By Zsigmondy's Theorem with **a=10**, **b=1**, there is some prime ***p*** **|** ***10<sup>n</sup>-1*** that does not divide any ***10<sup>k</sup>-1***, ***k < n***.

- Since ***p*** is prime and ***10<sup>n</sup>-1 = 9 · R<sub>n</sub>***, it must divide either **9** or ***R<sub>n</sub>***.
- ***p*** cannot divide **9**, since ***9 = 10<sup>1</sup>-1***.
- Therefore ***p*** divides ***R<sub>n</sub>***.
- ***p*** cannot divide any ***R<sub>k</sub>***, since it doesn't divide ***10<sup>k</sup>-1 = 9 · R<sub>k</sub>***.

Therefore the ***p*** from Zsigmondy's Theorem is a novel prime factor of any ***R<sub>n</sub>***, ***n ≥ 2***. ∎

---

### An example of a repeated novel prime factor

The prime **487** is a repeated prime factor of ***R<sub>486</sub>***:

By the Fermat-Euler theorem, **10<sup>487-1</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 487)**. The order of 10 mod 487, that is, the smallest power of 10 that is 1 mod 487, therefore must be a divisor of 486. In fact, the order is equal to 486. It also happens that not only is **10<sup>486</sup> ≡ 1 (mod 487)**, it's also **1 (mod 487<sup>2</sup>)**.

See [here](https://repl.it/B9pA/0) that the order of 10 mod 487 is 486; that is, that no smaller ***10<sup>k</sup>-1*** is divisible by 487. Obviously, 487 doesn't divide 9, so it must divide ***R<sub>486</sub>***.

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, 18 bytes

```
{{)'1*imf}%W%:-_&}
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=18%0A%0A%7B%7B)'1*imf%7D%25W%25%3A-%7D%0A%0A~p)

Starting at 19 (the first repunit prime after 2) it will take a fairly long time.

#### Explanation

This is an unnamed block (CJam's equivalent of a function), which expects the input number `n` on the stack and leaves a list of prime factors instead:

```
{      e# Map this block over [0 1 ... n-1]...
  )'1* e#   Increment and create a string of that many 1s.
  i    e#   Convert to integer.
  mf   e#   Get its prime factors.
}%
W%     e# Reverse the list.
:-     e# Fold set difference onto the list, removing from the first list the elements of
       e# all other lists.
_&     e# Remove duplicates. Unfortunately, this necessary. Thomas Kwa found that the 486th
       e# repunit contains 487^2 (where 487 is a novel prime factor).
```

Comment: Did ... did you seriously just golf from 20 to 16 in the past three minutes? >.>

Comment: @TimmyD Sort of... I had to go up to 18 again for now, because it turned out my code was based on an assumption which I can neither prove or disprove right now.

Comment: Ooo, that's an interesting case - duplicate novel factors. Nice catch.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell 86 bytes

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
f n=[x|x<-primeFactors$div(10^n-1)9,notElem x$f=<<[1..n-1]]
```

Usage example: `f 8` -> `[73,137]`.

Takes a lot of time and memory for big `n`.

Direct implementation of the definition: take all prime factors `x` of `Rn` which do not show up before (`f=<<[1..n-1]` are all prime factors of `R1 ... R(n-1)`).

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica <s>82 74</s> 63 bytes

With 11 bytes saved thanks to alephalpha.

```
Complement@@Reverse@FactorInteger[(10^Range@#-1)/9][[;;,;;,1]]&
```

---

**Prime factors of R70**

(10^70 - 1)/9 = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

```
FactorInteger[(10^70 - 1)/9]
```

> {{11, 1}, {41, 1}, {71, 1}, {239, 1}, {271, 1}, {4649, 1}, {9091, 
>     1}, {123551, 1}, {909091, 1}, {4147571, 1}, {102598800232111471, 
>     1}, {265212793249617641, 1}}

---

**Novel prime factors of R70**

```
Complement@@Reverse@FactorInteger[(10^Range@#-1)/9][[;;,;;,1]]&[70]
```

> {4147571, 265212793249617641}

Comment: `Complement@@Reverse@FactorInteger[(10^Range@#-1)/9][[;;,;;,1]]&`

Comment: Kindly explain the meaning of `[[;;,;;,1]]` or `[[1 ;; All, 1 ;; All, 1]]`.  I'm puzzled!

Comment: @DavidCarraher It takes the first element of every element of every element of a list.

Comment: @DavidCarraher `[[;;,;;,1]]` is the same as `[[All,All,1]]`.

Comment: Now that makes sense.  BTW, your re-location of `Range` was very clever.

Answer (score 2):

## LabVIEW, 33 [LabVIEW Primitives](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7589/39490)

19 takes forever...

Work by saving all Primes and deleting elements from the last set when they are found in the other array.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 25 bytes

This works for input up to `16`:

```
10,i:^9/Y[t0)Yftb!w\~s1=)
```

The following version uses **31 bytes** and works up to `18`. For `19` it requires about 4 GB memory (I haven't been able to run it).

```
10,i:^9/Y[t0)5X2Y%Yfotb!w\~s1=)
```

#### Example

```
>> matl
 > 10,i:^1-,9/t0)5X2Y%Yfotb!w\~s1=)
 > 
> 6
7 13
```

#### Explanation

Consider for concreteness input `6`. First the prime divisors of `111111` are computed; in this case the results are `3`, `7`, `11`, `13`, `37`. Then the modulo operation (division remainder) is computed for all combinations of numbers `1`, `11`, ... `111111` and the computed divisors. This exploits MATL's implicit singleton expansion. The result is in this case a `6`x`5` matrix, with each column corresponding to one of the divisors. Accepted divisors (columns) are those for which only `1` value (namely the last) gives zero remainder.

```
10,i:^9/Y[   % generate vector with `1`, `11`, ... depending on input number, say "n"
t0)          % pick the last element: `111...1` (n ones)
5X2Y%        % * convert to uint64, so that larger numbers can be handled
Yf           % prime factors                                             
o            % * convert to double precision, so that modulus can be done
t            % duplicate                                                 
b            % bubble up element in stack                                
!            % transpose                                                 
w            % swap elements in stack                                    
\            % modulus after division (element-wise, singleton expansion)
~s           % number of zero values in each column
1=           % is equal to 1? (element-wise, singleton expansion)
)            % index divisors with that logical index
```

(*) Removed in short version

Comment: That's a clever way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 103 bytes

```julia
R(n)=[keys(factor((10^n-1)÷9))...]
n->(r=R(n);isprime(r)?r:setdiff(r,reduce(vcat,[R(i)for i=1:n-1])))
```

This is an unnamed function that calls a helper function `R`. To call it, give the main function a name, e.g. `f=n->...`.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function R(n::Integer)
    collect(keys(factor((10^n - 1) ÷ 9)))
end

function f(n::Integer)
    r = R(n)
    if isprime(r)
        r
    else
        setdiff(r, reduce(vcat, [R(i) for i = 1:n-1]))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 24 bytes

```
[:({:-.}:)@:q:[:+/\10^i.
```

Expects extended-precision numerics after 6 (e.g. `19x` instead of `19`).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL9pKo9pKV6/WStPBqtAq2kpbP8bQIC5Tjys1OSNfIU3BDMYwtKyAMY1MEEzLiv//AQ)

There's probably a shorter way to generate the repunits which avoids the caps, too.

## Explanation

```
[: ({: -. }:) @: q: [: +/\ 10 ^ i.
                                i. Range [0, input)
                           10 ^    10 raised to the power of the range
                       +/\         Running sum of this list (list of repunits)
                 q:                Prime factors of the repunits
              @:                   Composed with
   ({: -. }:)                      Unique prime factors of last repunit
    {:                              Factors of last repunit (tail of matrix)
       -.                           Set subtraction with
          }:                        Rest of the matrix (curtail)
```

#### How it works, visually

I think that these sorts of visual explanations are easier to stomach for those who don't know J. These are results from the REPL.

```
   10 ^ i.6
1 10 100 1000 10000 100000

   +/\ 10 ^ i. 6
1 11 111 1111 11111 111111

   q: +/\ 10 ^ i. 6
 0   0  0  0  0
11   0  0  0  0
 3  37  0  0  0
11 101  0  0  0
41 271  0  0  0
 3   7 11 13 37

   ({: -. }:) q: +/\ 10 ^ i. 6
7 13
```