# Distance between two points in n-dimensional space

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, geometry

Here is another simple one:

## The Challenge

Given two points in an n-dimensional space, output the distance between them, also called the Euclidean distance.

- The coordinates will be rational numbers; the only limits are the restrictions of your language.
- Lowest dimension is 1, highest is whatever your language can handle
- You may assume that the two points are of the same dimension and that there will be no empty input.
- The distance has to be correct to at least 3 decimal places. If your language does not support floating point numbers, output the nearest whole number.

## Rules

- As usual, function or full program allowed.
- Input may be taken from STDIN, command line- or function arguments.
- Input format is up to you, specify which one you used in your answer.
- Output may be provided by printing to stdout or return value.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest byte-count wins! In case of a tie, the earlier answer wins.

## Test cases

Each point is represented by a list of length n.

```
[1], [3] -> 2
[1,1], [1,1] -> 0
[1,2], [3,4] -> 2.82842712475
[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8] -> 8
[1.5,2,-5], [-3.45,-13,145] -> 150.829382085
[13.37,2,6,-7], [1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89] -> 22.5020221314
```

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: I'll give brainfuck a shot. Let's see what horrible monster comes out.

Comment: I assume you mean the Euclidean distance?

Comment: @flawr Yep, exactly. Just wanted to keep the title simple, since not everyone might know what that is at first glance. Could definetly write that in the challange tho :)

Comment: @DenkerAffe is it OK to return the distance squared if "your programming language does not support floating points"? This would make my brainfuck program a lot more accurate (Otherwise I'll have to implement some sort of estimation algorithm).

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Go for it then. Brainfuck won't win this one anyway, but I really wanna see your solution :) Just make it clear in your answer that you output the distance squared.

Comment: @DenkerAffe I think it's safe to say that brainfuck will *never* win a code golf. But it's just for fun anyways :)

Comment: I propose adding a non-floating point clause (See my edit)

Comment: Can we assume the input is all in floating-point (no ints) if our language supports it/is strongly-typed?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 2 bytes

```
ZP
```

[**Try it online**!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WlA&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDRdCls1LCA2LCA3LCA4XQ)

The `ZP` function (corresponding to MATLAB's `pdist2`) computes all pairwise distances between two sets of points, using Euclidean distance by default. Each set of points is a matrix, and each point is a row. In this case it produces a single result, which is the distance between the two points.

Comment: No way this is real

Comment: I'm patiently waiting for the inevitable single-byte MATL answer;)

Comment: Ever heard those languages whereas the main point of the language is to solve obscure Code Golf problems? This sounds exactly like it. Makes me wonder if esoteric languages exist exactly for this.

Comment: This definitely puts the money where the mouth is. Nice job Luis!

Comment: The pdist2 function literally changed my life when I found it...

Answer (score 16):

## MATL, <s><s>4.0</s></s> 3 bytes

Thanks for -1 by @AndrasDeak!

```
-Zn
```

Reads two vectors (via implicit input that is requested by `-`) then substracts those and calculates the norm of their difference with `Zn`.

[Try it Online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=LVpu&input=WzEsMiwzLDRdCls1LDYsNyw4XQo)

Comment: Please start upvoting tomorrow, I already motorboated today.

Comment: Too late...You gotta motorboat again :P

Comment: Save some upvotes [for me](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70555/36398) :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo dat shameless advertising :O

Comment: @DenkerAffe never trust a bounty hunter.

Comment: _Bounty hunters... we don't need that scum_

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not sure yet whether I should flag your self promotion as  *rude or offensive*, *not constructive* or *too chatty* :D

Comment: PS: You can start to upvote now!

Comment: @flawr way ahead of you;)

Comment: @flawr How could you forget about pdist2? :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Because I only knew about `pdist` but not about `pdist2`. Only a noob would make a second function with the same name again with an appended `2`... Staring at you *MATLAB*.

Comment: _quietly leaves and posts a challenge that's solved with two-dimensional convolution_

Comment: Where is that challenge?

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
.a
```

> `.a` - L2 norm of vector difference of A[0] and A[1].

Literally a function that does this problem

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.a&input=%5B%5B13.37%2C2%2C6%2C-7%5D%2C+%5B1.2%2C3.4%2C-5.6%2C7.89%5D%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
_²S½
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=X8KyU8K9&input=&args=WzEzLjM3LDIsNiwtN10+WzEuMiwzLjQsLTUuNiw3Ljg5XQ)

#### How it works

```
_²S½    Main link. Left input: A (list). Right input: B (list).

_       Subtract B from A, element by element.
 ²      Square all differences.
  S     Add all squares.
   ½    Take the square root of the sum.
```

Comment: Yikes. Just 4 bytes with Jelly. I cannot see how anyone can do better than that.

Comment: @CarpetPython Apparently MATL can...

Comment: @CarpetPython And Pyth

Comment: @CarpetPython and Vyxal too

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, 11 bytes

```
Norm[#-#2]&
```

Input as two lists, output as a number. If the input is exact (integers, rationals, etc.) the output will be exact as well. If the input contains a floating-point number, the output will be a float as well.

Comment: [`EuclideanDistance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EuclideanDistance.html) would work nicely too... if the name weren't so darn long!  If only there were "MATL for Mathematica" this would be a single byte =)

Comment: I'm working on a golfy Mathematica-based language >:)

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, <s>11</s> 8 bytes

*Thanks to Dennis for saving 3 bytes.*

```
q~.-:mhz
```

[Run all test cases.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%22%20-%3E%20%22%2F0%3D'%2CSer%3AQ%3B%0A%0AQ~.-%3Amhz%0A%0A%5DoNo%7D%2F&input=%5B1%5D%2C%20%5B3%5D%20-%3E%202%0A%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C1%5D%20-%3E%200%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%20%5B3%2C4%5D%20-%3E%202.82842712475%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C%20%5B5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D%20-%3E%208%0A%5B1.5%2C2%2C-5%5D%2C%20%5B-3.45%2C-13%2C145%5D%20-%3E%20150.829382085%0A%5B13.37%2C2%2C6%2C-7%5D%2C%20%5B1.2%2C3.4%2C-5.6%2C7.89%5D%20-%3E%2022.5020221314)

#### Explanation

```
q~   e# Read and evaluate input.
.-   e# Vectorised difference.
:mh  e# Reduce √(x²+y²) over the list.
z    e# Take abs() to handle 1D input.
```

[See this tip for why `:mh` works.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61089/8478)

Comment: That trick with `:mh` is very nice indeed

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 46 bytes

```
d :: Floating c => [c] -> [c] -> c
d a=sqrt.sum.map((^2).uncurry(flip(-))).zip a
```

## Haskell, 35 bytes (By @nimi)

```
d :: Float c => [c] -> [c] -> c
d a=sqrt.sum.zipWith(((^2).).(-))a
```

## Haskell, 31 bytes

> Like [this Scala answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70543/29474), takes input as a sequence of tuples

<hack>

```
d :: Float c => [(c,c)] -> c
d=sqrt.sum.map$(^2).uncurry(-)
```

</hack>

### Examples:

```
Prelude> d [1] [3]
2.0
Prelude> d [1,1] [1,1]
0.0
Prelude> d [1,2,3,4] [5,6,7,8]
8.0
Prelude> d [1.5,2,-5] [-3.45,-13,145]
150.82938208452623
Prelude> d [13.37,2,6,-7] [1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89]
22.50202213135522
```

Comment: *uncurry* ಠ_ಠ When cooking I sometimes wish to have an *unsalt* function.

Comment: @flawr https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)?

Comment: `map` + `uncurry` + `zip` rarely pays off, use `zipWith`: `d a=sqrt.sum.zipWith(((^2).).(-))a`.

Comment: can't you save another couple of bytes by eta reduction?

Comment: @jk. Not sure... I don't think so, since `(.)` always returns a function that takes only one argument... I think you can do something like (.).(.), but that isn't really worth it.

Answer (score 6):

## Octave, 15 bytes

```
@(x,y)norm(x-y)
```

Example:

```
octave:1> d=@(x,y)norm(x-y);
octave:2> d([13.37,2,6,-7], [1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89])
ans =  22.502
```

Answer (score 5):

## APL, <s>14</s> 11 bytes

```
.5*⍨(+/-×-)
```

This is dyadic function train that takes the vectors on the left and right and returns the Euclidean norm of their difference.

Explanation:

```
       -×-)  ⍝ Squared differences
    (+/      ⍝ Sum them
.5*⍨         ⍝ Take the square root
```

[Try it here](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190.5*%u2368%28+/-%D7-%29%20%u22C4%2013.37%202%206%20%AF7%20f%201.2%203.4%20%AF5.6%207.89&run)

Saved 3 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Comment: `.5*⍨(+/-×-)` saves a few bytes.

Comment: Can this really be the first time I've seen commented APL code? *That* symbol! I've always found the APL character set weird, but I never realized a dismembered zombie finger was the comment marker. ;-)

Comment: @steveverrill I <s>comment</s> put zombie fingers in just about all of my APL submissions here. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AlexA. The poor alignment (due to the non-monospaced APL characters) happened to give it a particularly hand-like appearance this time. You've golfed it down from 4 lines to 3, and ruined the effect :-S This answer of yours has 4 lines, but doesn't have the hand-like appearance  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/70595/15599 Anyway, I like that you still have a single character smiley in your code.

Answer (score 4):

## Julia, 16 bytes

```
N(x,y)=norm(x-y)
```

This is a function that accepts two arrays and returns the Euclidean norm of their difference as a float.

You can verify all test cases at once online [here](http://goo.gl/dMBgy0).

Comment: You can save 3 bytes by using an operator as the function name : [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/@/IqbSNi@/KFejQrdS839BUWZeSU6eRrShjlFsTLSxjkmspsJ/AA "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>130</s> <s>117</s> <s>114</s> <s>107</s> 105 bytes

This is the obvious solution. I don't usually golf in Java, but I was curious to see if Java could beat the Brainfuck version. Doesn't seem like I did a good job then.. Maybe one could use the new Map/Reduce from Java 8 to save some bytes.

Thanks to @flawr (13 bytes), @KevinCruijssen (9 bytes) and @DarrelHoffman (3 bytes)!

Golfed:

```
double d(float[]a,float[]b){float x=0,s;for(int i=0;i<a.length;x+=s*s)s=a[i]-b[i++];return Math.sqrt(x);}
```

Ungolfed:

```
double d(float[] a, float[] b) {
  float x=0,s;

  for(int i=0; i<a.length; x+=s*s)
    s = a[i] - b[i++];

  return Math.sqrt(x);
}
```

Comment: You can certainly shorten the function name to one character. The `for` loop be compressed to `double x=0,s;for(int i=0;++i<a.length;s=a[i]-b[i],x+=s*s);`

Comment: You can use int instead of double to save characters too, and declare i next to x.

Comment: This is _way_ oversized. See flawr's suggestion for the loop. Using Java 8 lambda, this can be reduced to: `double[]a,b->{double x=0,s;for(int i=0;++i<a.length;s=a[i]-b[i],x+=s*s);return Math.sqrt(x);}` for a total of 93 bytes.

Comment: I totally forgot to shorten the function name.. @flawr thanks a lot for those tips, I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: If you don't care too much about precision, you can replace three of the `double`s with `float`s and save 3 bytes.  (You can't change the return type, because `Math.sqrt()` returns a `double`, and you'd have to add a cast.)  It's not much of a savings, but 3 bytes is enough to beat the BF solution right now...  Also, it's not necessary to initialize `x` to 0, Java variables start at 0 automatically, so -2 more bytes there.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman thanks for saving me 3 bytes! I don't get it to work when I don't initialize x to zero. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187632/why-does-javac-complain-about-not-initialized-variable) might be relevant, I'm using `javac` version 1.8.0_66.

Comment: @Bruce_Forte: Ah, my bad.  I forgot that Java class member variables are initialized to 0, but local variables are not.  Oh well.  (My last few jobs have all been C++ or C#, been a while since I put on the Java-hat.)

Comment: However, if this were a full program, complete with class declaration and `main` function et al, you could use that trick.  Of course then it wouldn't be close to competing with even BF, but that's Java for you...

Comment: You can remove the `public ` in front of the method to save 7 bytes, and you can also place the `x+=s*s` outside the for-loop so you don't need the comma (i.e. `for(int i=-1;++i<a.length;s=a[i]-b[i])x+=s*s;`) for -1 byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Cheers for the 7 bytes! But about the s, I can't get this to work. This is the same as with Darrel's suggestion, the variable `s` wouldn't get initialized that way.

Comment: @Bruce_Forte Ah, I see.. In that case you could use this: `for(int i=0;i<a.length;x+=s*s)s=a[i]-b[i++];` (and I also changed the `-1` to `0` for an additional byte)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen True. I like the change to `0` by using the operator precedence rules! Thanks for saving me a whole lot of bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 9 bytes

```
+&.*:/-/>
```

This is a function that takes one set of coordinates from the other (`-/>`), and then performs a sum `+` under `&.` square `*:`.

The input should be in the format `x y z;a b c` where `x y z` is your first set of co-ordinates and `a b c` is the other.

Comment: Since the inputs are always the same length, you can drop the `>` and specify that input should be given as `x y z,:a b c`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 47 bytes

A straight forward solution. The function expects 2 points as sequences of numbers, and returns the distance between them.

```
lambda a,b:sum((d-e)**2for d,e in zip(a,b))**.5
```

Example:

```
>>> f([13.37, 2, 6, -7], [1.2, 3.4, -5.6, 7.89])
22.50202213135522
```

Comment: Works in Python3.6, but might not be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

## [golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/), 43 chars

```
\d(x,y)s=0~@i,v i(x)s=s+(v-y[i])^2$~M.q(s)$
```

Works by calling it as

```
> w(d({1,1},{1,1}))
0
> w(d({1,2},{3,4}))
2.82842712475
> w (d({1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}))
8
```

A Lua equivalent would be

```
function dist(x, y)
    s = 0
    for index,value in ipairs(x)
       s = s + (value - y[index])^2
    end
    return math.sqrt(s)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

### Seriously, 12 bytes

```
,iZ`i-ª`MΣ√A
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LGlaYGktwqpgTc6j4oia&input=WzEzLjM3LDIsNiwtN10sIFsxLjIsMy40LC01LjYsNy44OV0)

Explanation:

```
,iZ`i-ª`MΣ√A
,iZ           get input, flatten, zip
   `   `M     map:
    i-ª         flatten, subtract, square
         Σ√A  sum, sqrt, abs
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl 6, <s>30</s> <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```perl6
{sqrt [+] ([Z-] $_)»²}
```

(Thanks @b2gills for 2 more bytes lost)

**usage**

```perl6
my &f = {sqrt [+] (@^a Z-@^b)»²};

say f([1], [3]); # 2
say f([1,1], [1,1]); # 0
say f([1,2], [3,4]); # 2.82842712474619
say f([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]); # 8
say f([1.5,2,-5], [-3.45,-13,145]); # 150.829382084526
say f([13.37,2,6,-7], [1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89]); # 22.5020221313552
```

Comment: `{sqrt [+] ([Z-] $_)»²}`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript <s>ES7, 45</s> ES6, 37 bytes

```
a=>Math.hypot(...a.map(([b,c])=>b-c))
```

Expects an array of pairs of coordinates, one from each vector, e.g. `[[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 7], [4, 8]]`. If that is unacceptable, then for 42 bytes:

```
(a,b)=>Math.hypot(...a.map((e,i)=>e-b[i]))
```

Expects two arrays of equal length corresponding to the two N-dimensional vectors, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]`. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @l4m2. (Also, did nobody notice my typo?)

Comment: Please add an example on how to invoke this function including a specification of the input format, since this is not obvious on the first glance.

Comment: @DenkerAffe Sorry, having overlooked that clause, I had just used the same format as the examples and indeed everyone previous to me at the time.

Comment: `a=>b=>Math.hypot(...a.map((t,i)=>t-b[i]))`

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 52

```
->p,q{t=0;p.size.times{|i|t+=(p[i]-q[i])**2}
t**0.5}
```

**In test program**

```
f=->p,q{t=0;p.size.times{|i|t+=(p[i]-q[i])**2}
t**0.5}

p f[[1], [3]] # 2
p f[[1,1], [1,1]] # 0
p f[[1,2], [3,4]] # 2.82842712475
p f[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]] # 8
p f[[1.5,2,-5], [-3.45,-13,145]] # 150.829382085
p f[[13.37,2,6,-7], [1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89]] # 22.5020221314
```

Answer (score 2):

## AppleScript, <s>241</s> 239 bytes

This is golfed code, but I've put comments in in the form `--`.

```
on a()    -- Calling for getting input
set v to{1}          -- Arbitrary placeholder
repeat until v's item-1=""       -- Repeat until no input is gathered
set v to v&(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned   -- Add input to list
end      -- End the repeat
end      -- End the method
set x to a()   -- Set the array inputs
set y to a()
set z to 0     -- Sum placeholder
set r to 2     -- 2 is the first significant array index
repeat(count of items in x)-2     -- Loop through all but first and last of the array
set z to z+(x's item r-y's item r)^2    -- Add the square of the difference
end   -- End the repeat
z^.5  -- Return the square root of the sum
```

This uses the same algorithm as most of the other programs here.

[image: run sample]

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell, 32 bytes

```
((sqrt.sum.map(^2)).).zipWith(-)
```

---

```
λ> let d = ((sqrt.sum.map(^2)).).zipWith(-)
λ> d [1] [3]
2.0
λ> d [1,1] [1,1]
0.0
λ> d [1,2] [3,4]
2.8284271247461903
λ> d [1..4] [5..8]
8.0
λ> d [1.5,2,-5] [-3.45,-13,145]
150.82938208452623
λ> d [13.37,2,6,-7] [1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89]
22.50202213135522
```

Comment: [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##BcHBEkAgEADQu6/Yg0PN0ODedziQmSZSo1iVi4@33nM6H1sIZOVMjOU7FZGfKKJGtgycCy5ej6MvjrWcovYnSFivCgCTPwvUYGHqm07BNDS9os/YoPdMrUH8AQ "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @Angs Thanks for the improvement. After some tinkering, I found a way to remove 6 more bytes (by removing `map` and parentheses).

Comment: I'm sorry to intervene again, but `sqrt$sum$(^2)<$>zipWith(-)` is not a valid anonymous function. The underlying rule is actually quite simple: If you can write `f = <mycode>` and `f` afterwards performs the required task, then `<mycode>` is a valid anonymous function. In your case you need to add `f p q = <mycode> p q`, so `<mycode>` on it's own is not valid.

Comment: @Laikoni You're right. I edited my answer and used Angs's suggestion. If you find a way to shorten it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>79</s> 77 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.

TIO requires compiler flag `-lm`. GCC of MinGW (that I use) does not.

```c
f(p,q,d,s)float*p,*q,s;{for(s=0;d--;)s+=*p++*=*p-=*q++;printf("%f",sqrt(s));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVHNboMwDD7DU1hIFQESVJLQdmNsD1L1UMFASP2Bhu1S8epjMSWwdpftYiJ/f7bJWJllfV@QmjY0p8orDud969fUb6hKrsX5QlS6THLGEk8FqV8Hga8rS/0mCJL6Up3agjiLwqGqubREeV7S9Z/nKoeSDFbg1xEF8@QUtALy6ujZV9vCd5XYlm3pICDGbut4mgcpLBP9eUG6fgSBZ1vWFBnyYpGBQ6GOttVu4KfIBAYRvIG7c@EZXOp6v/0p/DOB/yHByNgrOGMmwdVxZ9z3RvpoFXEQ72wbtz/uqxMZbnE7Ufuu2khvtNOzXaNw2dGxxW8toVvJTzL/QaYwK7hRTP07mbiTcSwCi5wMhDGIsb/CssayebSSs1U8WrF4spHGholQapxFQ04k40efePIRoViPTkMuW0928bwWx5HlELbC2TZP3XBj2yrJeMbpeDoQf8AN4AbgCPAZEAYQCMgZkAaQCIgZiA0QG0XXf2XFYV@qnh2O3w)

Comment: @ceilingcat Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
∆d
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIZkIiwiIiwiNywgNCwgM1xuMTcsIDYsIDIiXQ==)

Laughs in built-in. Generalised euclidian distance do be like that sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

## R, 38 bytes and 25 bytes

Sure, it is impossible to compete with the shortest 4 bytes answer, but I wanted to share anyway a hopefully interesting solution (38 bytes):

```
f=\(x,y)sd(c(x-y,y-x))*(nrow(x)-.5)^.5
```

How does it work? Standard deviation of a sample is calculated as a square root of the sum of squares of deviation scores divided by sample size minus one.
[image]

The trick is to add to the sample a second set of the same numbers with the opposite sign (like `c(1,2,-1,-2)`). This way we get rid of mean (=0) out of the formula, but also we are getting each number twice. To obtain the sum of squares we only need to "neutralize" the term `sqrt(2/(N-1))`, whereby the sample size N is 2*N_dimensions.

...but unfortunately this bright =) solution sucks to the old good straightforward formula (25 bytes):

```
g=\(x,y)(sum((x-y)^2))^.5
```

Here is the result:

```
> list.x <- list(matrix(1),
+                matrix(c(1,1),2),
+                matrix(c(1,2),2),
+                matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 4),
+                matrix(c(1.5,2,-5), 3),
+                matrix(c(13.37,2,6,-7),4))
> 
> list.y <- list(matrix(3), 
+                matrix(c(1,1), 2),
+                matrix(c(3,4),2),
+                matrix(c(5,6,7,8),4),
+                matrix(c(-3.45,-13,145),3),
+                matrix(c(1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89),4))
> 
> correct = list(2,0,2.82842712475,8,150.829382085,22.5020221314)
> 
> do.call(rbind, Map(\(x,y,z)c(f(x,y),g(x,y),z),list.x,list.y,correct))
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,]   2.000000   2.000000   2.000000
[2,]   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
[3,]   2.828427   2.828427   2.828427
[4,]   8.000000   8.000000   8.000000
[5,] 150.829382 150.829382 150.829382
[6,]  22.502022  22.502022  22.502022
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, <strike>67</strike> 62 bytes

```
def e(a:(Int,Int)*)=math.sqrt(a map(x=>x._2-x._1)map(x=>x*x)sum)
```

Requires input as a <strike>sequence/vector of</strike> var-arg tuples
Example:

```
scala> e((1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8))
res1: Double = 8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

## , 6 chars / 13 bytes

```
МŰМŷ…ï
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%20%5B1%2C1%5D%5D&code=%D0%9C%C5%B0%D0%9C%C5%B7%E2%80%A6%C3%AF)</kbd>

Calculates norm of difference of input arrays.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 72 bytes

```
(float[]i,float[]n)=>System.Math.Sqrt(i.Zip(n,(x,y)=>(x-y)*(x-y)).Sum())
```

A simple solution using Linq.

Answer (score 1):

### Sage, 35 bytes

```py
lambda a,b,v=vector:norm(v(a)-v(b))
```

This function takes 2 lists as input and returns a symbolic expression. The distance is calculated by performing vector subtraction on the lists and computing the Euclidean norm of the resultant vector.

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwlkdFuhCAQRd9N_IdJ-qA2IxGE1d1k-yObPuDKbklVLKDt_n0BeZlk7pk7XHhcJzkPowSJA-7XXd29sZfF2LncS1nVezlUVZ7lmVfOO7hCURQ3-olwaz-h_gCWZzeKqRFLbDWpxRKD_KBIz3rOOsp4Jw4ZoxYQgSfssE9YHyUigliLqNUt4QJr2iLlIhFUNMHq3Pas6ZNRS9ou8Cesu3QHEowJD_Mk2JL-fKxnRDSsYYy2lIcAxK2T9pNelCtTuIexEAOCXlJ1lzyDcKR9OgSz-RB8lmupdjlhBA6HsojuRXygSK9WLx4e5Xscq465N_BfCqzym13UCGF-U6AdSHCveTCTvoP6W61yTpsFwRkYtQ2fML3gbuZVBssnqJ9NhnUvGI1yS-Hh19jvfyPhd7o=&lang=sage)

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 48 bytes

```
#(Math/sqrt(apply +(for[d(map - % %2)](* d d))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
-nOt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@b51/y/3@0obGesbmOkY6Zjq55LFe0oZ6RjrGeiY6uqZ6ZjrmehWUsAA)

Negative not y'all!

```
-    # a-b
 n   # (a-b)**2
  O  # sum((a-b)**2) for all a,b
   t # sqrt(sum((a-b)**2) for all a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, 4 bytes

```
dist
```

This is a built-in function to calculate the distance matrix of any input matrix. Defaults to euclidean distance.

Example usage:

```
> x=matrix(c(1.5,-3.45,2,-13,-5,145),2)
> x
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.50    2   -5
[2,] -3.45  -13  145
> dist(x)
         1
2 150.8294
```

If you're feeling disappointed because it's a built-in, then here's a non-built-in (or at least, it's *less* built-in...) version for **22 bytes** (with thanks to [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)):

```
pryr::f(norm(x-y,"F"))
```

This is an anonymous function that takes two vectors as input.

Comment: `function(x,y)norm(x-y,"F")` is shorter than your second version.

Answer (score 1):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), 74 bytes

```
:math.sqrt Enum.reduce Enum.zip(p,q),0,fn({a,b},c)->:math.pow(a-b,2)+c end
```

[**You can try it online**](http://elixirplayground.com?gist=663568808c8f5eaa09070363516c9e30)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE), 15 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
√(sum((LA-LB)2
```

TI-Basic is a [tokenized language](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/one-byte-tokens).

Prompts for input as two lists, and returns the Euclidian distance betwrrn them in `Ans`

Explanation:

```
Prompt A,B    # 5 bytes, Prompts for two inputs; if the user inputs lists:
           # they are stored in LA and LB
√(sum((LA-LB)2 # 10 bytes, Euclidian distance between points
           #(square root of (sum of (squares of (differences of coordinates))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes

```python
lambda*a:sum((x-y)**2for x,y in zip(*a))**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDLasMwELzrK/ZiIpmV0DNWAsmPuKW4uCGGxhaxC3F@3l05lFoHaTUzO1pNmqfr0LulPb0t383ts23K5jj@3Dh/yFmUpb0Md3jgDF0Pzy7xshGEqrCw6WucPtLQ9dMIJ@AMaPHavCPUjjYr8A/CFXwdegPbVYs@q1W00dvKWF@FrQRffB1wjxVGKuM/rQIJZMi8dMoHlMah8RkwQZPlwUWr48bQKVdRzx5ltc6k6AHlyUORvYqHPIpVQVttrXHGCyYYyxGkHMDmy8fVMd2p5rtiRChGkGcoLjsogKdak1Na02g3NyEEW34B)

**Ungolfed version:**

```python
      ₙ
sqrt( ∑(xᵢ - yᵢ)² )
     ⁱ⁼¹

def d(a, b):                    # two points (lists or tuples)
    return sum(                 # sum of...
        (x - y) ** 2            # (xᵢ - yᵢ)²
        for x,y in zip(a, b)    # 
    ) ** 0.5                    # square root of sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
äÖ╙í▼=╬b
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8499d3a11f3dce62&i=[1],+[3]+%0A[1,1],+[1,1]+%0A[1,2],+[3,4]+%0A[1,2,3,4],+[5,6,7,8]+%0A[1.5,2,-5],+[-3.45,-13,145]+%0A[13.37,2,6,-7],+[1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89]+&m=2)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
\       zip the coordinates into pairs
{       for each pair,
  :s    compute the absolute span
  J+    square and add to total
F       
|Q      square root result
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5C+++%09zip+the+coordinates+into+pairs%0A%7B+++%09for+each+pair,%0A++%3As%09compute+the+absolute+span%0A++J%2B%09square+and+add+to+total%0AF+++%09%0A%7CQ++%09square+root+result&i=[1],+[3]+%0A[1,1],+[1,1]+%0A[1,2],+[3,4]+%0A[1,2,3,4],+[5,6,7,8]+%0A[1.5,2,-5],+[-3.45,-13,145]+%0A[13.37,2,6,-7],+[1.2,3.4,-5.6,7.89]+&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 26 bytes

```
f(a,b)=total((a-b)^2)^{.5}
```

The function \$f(a,b)\$ takes in two lists, \$a\$ and \$b\$, representing the two points, and returns the distance between them.

I think the code is pretty self explanatory, even for someone unfamiliar with Desmos.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/s9sjobvfnj?nographpaper)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rxudbv9fvi?nographpaper)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
√Σzo□-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HHrHOLq/IfTVuo@////2hDPSMdYz0THV1TPTMdcz0Ly1igmLGesbmOkY6Zjq55LAA)

#### Explanation

```
√Σzo□-
  z     zip input arguments
   o    with composed function
     -  difference
    □   squared
 Σ      sum
√       sqrt
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 70 Chars

Loops through, finding the square of the difference and then the root of the sum:

```python
a=input()
b=input()
x=sum([(a[i]-b[i])**2 for i in range(len(a))])**.5
```

Comment: Drop a few more: `sum([(x-y)**2 for x,y in zip(a,b)])**.5`

Answer (score 0):

### Mathcad,  bytes

[image]

Uses the built-in vector magnitude (absolute value) operator to calculate the size of the difference between the two points (expressed as vectors).

---

Mathcad golf size on hold until I get (or somebody else gets) round to opening up the discussion on meta.  However, the shortest way (assuming that input of the point vectors doesn't contribute to the score) is 3 "bytes" , with 14 bytes for the functional version.

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 7 bytes

```
,A-MXs,
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2CA-MXs%2C&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%5D%2C+%5B5%2C6%2C7%2C8%5D)

Transpose, apply subtract, map square, sum, sqrt.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 50 bytes

Zip, then map/reduce. Barely edges out the other Ruby answer from @LevelRiverSt by 2 bytes...

```
->p,q{p.zip(q).map{|a,b|(a-b)**2}.reduce(:+)**0.5}
```

[Try it online](https://repl.it/C1I2)

Answer (score 0):

### C 276 bytes

```
f(){*a,*b,d=0;l=1;a=malloc(sizeof(float)*50);b=malloc(sizeof(float)*50);scanf("%f",&a[0]);while(getchar()!='\n'){scanf("%f",&a[l]);l++;}l=1;scanf("%f",&b[0]);while(getchar()!='\n'){scanf("%f",&b[l]);l++;}for(int i=0;i<l;i++){d+=pow((a[i]-b[i]),2);}printf("%.5f",pow(d,0.5));}
```

Ungolfed version:

```
void f()
{

  float *a,*b,d=0;
  int l=1;

   a=malloc(sizeof(float)*50);
   b=malloc(sizeof(float)*50);

   //Accept p1,p2,p3.....pn
   scanf("%f",&a[0]);

   while(getchar()!='\n')
   {    
     scanf("%f",&a[l]);
     l++;
   }
   l=1;

   //Accept q1,q2,q3.....qn
   scanf("%f",&b[0]);
   while(getchar()!='\n')
  {    
    scanf("%f",&b[l]);
    l++;
  }

  for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
  {
    d+=pow((a[i]-b[i]),2);   
  }

  printf("\n%.5f",pow(d,0.5));
}
```

Pretty straightforward. This solution lets you measure distance between 2 points in upto 50 dimensions (can be increased).

In Cartesian coordinates, input the position of first point of `n` dimensions. (`p1 p2 p3 ...pn`) and press `Enter`.

Next, input the position of second point of `n` dimensions. (`q1 q2 q3 ...qn`) and press `Enter` to get the Euclidean Distance.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 36 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as two vectors, which are projected unto the range `1:2`, and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vb
[3:3]="=(A1-A2)^2":?[Sqrt(Sum(3:3))]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.distances`, 18 bytes

```
euclidian-distance
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDBCsIwDIbve4r/BRqYXd3UBxAvXsTT2KHUikPdRlsPMvbsNawKiikk8OVLSnvWJvQuHg@7/XYN7X1vPK7WdfaGuw4XOrU@6M5Yj8HZEJ6Da7uATZaNGThGPjkmzpLz9MUSTfWbL9528ccTG6GwRInqt0@KDaFmQUgqFEQukRfqV5MkSxaXEGW6n3gvFTxJvJSq1axPqKN9mFt7anUnPk@MDWoQGpj@PvTepu8QVptLfAE)

Built-in.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 35 bytes

```ruby
+:zip|:*&(+:-|~:**&2)|:sum|~:**&0.5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9BCsIwEEX3niIgFK2TIZlkTBrQpZcoRXAhKAgF7UIpXsRNETyU9_AApq1aV0Py3vyZuT3262pzbu6rxaM6baV_jmfhsivrkCaTWZD1NaRpQtM6HKtD_1DIH_VVilWe57oAkZuiKMRYyKWg0ecbOtCWDrVM_Rh1TWAHRujJW3KarOPBg1aKLsMcHPjB918HOVqSW0katAxSG9CWB1WziuGZ8aT8L9qgcbFxDtJ1e2IchTYGYRyEPvvbjJAVKSJttO1vb5q-vgE)

```
+:zip | :* & (+:- | ~:** & 2) | :sum | ~:** & 0.5

+:zip |                                            # Zip input arrays, then
        :* & (              )                      # map with
              +:- | ~:** & 2                       #   Difference, then square
                              | :sum |             # then sum, then
                                       ~:** & 0.5  # square root
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), <s>85</s> 80 bytes

```fortran
function d(A,n);real A(n,2);s=0;do5 i=1,n;s=s+(A(i,1)-A(i,2))**2
5 d=sqrt(s);end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBDoMgEEX3nGKWQJEU1FpDXHgUU7ShacYW6Pkto85i/ryfzFvWmOOE1XM5ji3O0xtGblXfC1fAS4Vncj7yoF5ChcEoK9SrBAr2iQGzVJ6PRDP6bfnhI4cV4ejc6cTy5NJwdX5tgRxYKF12qxEVhRVCSsta8EP6xsyTcCTcGmZqXXcAFva50ao6BkZTU@uGuNXUd/re/wE)
  <sub><s>[85 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY1BDoMwDATveYWPcWqiEqAURRx4Ci2hAiHTJvB@SiiqD17vyprtZ7/4lpNX/zs279oJGmmoqtDuplPEp0rZyIFGpKFOySCNuzCKZztN0MmGmByKtx94UeSE424L68PP6zKw@z/Ys4B3gg311XYzFBCJvNtwOTpSTKIYRKWMKMDV4eMXGdBG6paLNNNZCWDgmFtcSSkg1THJdB59oWNe6nv1BQ)</s></sub>

Instead of two vectors, I read all the data into two rows of array `A`. But Fortran 'helpfully' stores matrices by *column* so when I call the procedure `A` is transposed.

<sub>Using line number `5` instead of `enddo` saves 2 bytes :)

Saved 5 bytes using `function` instead of `subroutine`</sub>

Comment: If only the IMSL library was installed on TIO. I could have used the [DISL2](https://help.imsl.com/fortran/6.0/math/default.htm?turl=disl2.htm) function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
-²Sƭ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
-²Sƭ  # Implicit input
-     # Subtract
 ²    # Square
  S   # Sum
   ƭ  # Square root
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5.9, 86 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
let f={(p:[(Double,_)])in
sqrt(p.map{pow($0.1-$0.0,2)}.reduce(0,+))}
```

[Don't Try It Online, because TIO is too old. Here's a JDoodle link instead.](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/YbB)

`f` is of type `([(Double, Double)]) -> Double` -- it takes an array of pairs of coordinates, one per vector.

I just used the *subtract*-*square*-*sum*-*squareRoot* trick borrowed from other answers.