# Substitute numbers by their respective letter

Tags: code-golf, string

Create a function or program that takes a number as input, and outputs a string where ASCII-code points for the lower and upper case alphabet are substituted by their character equivalents.

- The upper case alphabet use the code points: `65-90`
- The lower case alphabet use the code points: `97-122`

If any adjacent digits in the input equals the code point of a letter, then that letter shall replace the digits in the output string.

**Rules:**

- The input will be a positive integer with between 1 and 99 digits
- You can assume only valid input is given
- You start substituting at the beginning of the integer (`976` -> `a6`, not `9L`)
- The input can be on any suitable format (string representation is OK)
- The output can be on any suitable format
- Standard rules apply

**Examples:**

```
1234567
12345C

3456789
345CY

9865432
bA432

6566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

6711110010100071111108102
Code000Golf
```

**Shortest code in bytes win!**

---

### Leaderboard

The Stack Snippet at the bottom of this post generates the catalog from the answers a) as a list of shortest solution per language and b) as an overall leaderboard.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
## Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
## Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```js
var QUESTION_ID=71735,OVERRIDE_USER=31516;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: *"The input will be a positive integer with between 1 and 99 digits"* In just about any programming language I know, it'll be a *string* with between 1 and 99 digits, as even a 64-bit int only holds up to 19 decimal digits...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I assume he meant integer in the mathematical sense, not the data type.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder valid point :-) Although, if I'm not mistaken, 1e99 is  technically still an integer. `long int` isn't enough, you need `super long int`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: Hah! :-) I'm sure there's a language somewhere with such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Jolf, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=z4FpTGHOnEdwd3B1RWTOokhkcEFI) I knew that upperLower function would be useful someday! Replace `ó` with `΢`, or just use the interpreter link. This is encoded in ISO 8859-7.

```
ρiLaΜGpwpuEdóH΅A
      pw           upper and lower
        pu         of the uppercase alphabet
     G    E        split by nothing (E = "")
    Μ      dóH     map each char to its numeric counterpart
  La               regex alternate array (e.g. La[1,2,3] => "1|2|3")
ρi            ΅A   replace input with the character code of the match (΅ is string lambda)
```

Answer (score 19):

### Perl, <s>39</s> 38 bytes

(1 byte added for the `-p` flag.)

```perl
$"="|";s/@{[65..90,97..122]}/chr$&/ge
```

```
s/                           /          replace...
  @{[                      ]}           this string, treated as a regex:
     join"|",65..90,97..122             65|66|67|68|...|121|122
                                   /ge  ...with this string, eval()'d:
                                 $&     the entirety of the last match
                              chr       convert to char from ASCII code
```

Right Tool for the Job™.

The explanation is outdated after one small optimization (thanks [dev-null](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48657/dev-null)!) that makes it a single byte shorter (but a bit less elegant): the `$"` variable represents what to `join` on when interpolating an arrray into a string, so setting `$"="|"` removes the need for `join`.

Demo:

```
llama@llama:~$ perl -pe '$"="|";s/@{[65..90,97..122]}/chr$&/ge' 
1234567
12345C
3456789 
345CY
9865432
bA432
6566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
6711110010100071111108102
Code000Golf
```

Comment: I guess you can save a single byte by setting `$"="|"` instead of join?

Comment: eg. `$"="|";s/@{[65..90,97..122]}/chr$&/ge`

Comment: @dev-null That does work, thanks!

Answer (score 11):

## Javascript, 80 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/6[5-9]|[78]\d|9[0789]|1[01]\d|12[012]/g,x=>String.fromCharCode(x))
```

See regex in action here: https://regex101.com/r/iX8bJ2/1

```js
f=
s=>s.replace(/6[5-9]|[78]\d|9[0789]|1[01]\d|12[012]/g,x=>String.fromCharCode(x))

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' +
    "f('1234567')\n" + f('1234567') + '\n\n' +
    "f('3456789')\n" + f('3456789') + '\n\n' +
    "f('9865432')\n" + f('9865432') + '\n\n' +
    "f('6566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990')\n" + f('6566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990') + '\n\n' +
    "f('6711110010100071111108102')\n" + f('6711110010100071111108102') +
'</pre>'
```

Just for curiosity, one thing I learned here:

I can't change `x=>String.fromCharCode(x)` to `String.fromCharCode` [because ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35340883/4227915)

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, 22 bytes

```
q{+'[,_el^{_is@\/*}/}*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cXsrJ1ssX2VsXntfaXNAXC8qfS99Kg&input=NjcxMTExMDAxMDEwMDA3MTExMTEwODEwMg)

#### Background

Simply replacing all occurrences of digit groups with the corresponding letters (in whatever order we may choose) will fail to comply with the left-to-right rule.

Instead, we can generate all prefixes of the input string, and attempt to make all possible substitutions while we're generating them. Since no code  point is contained in another code point, the order of these attempts is not important.

For example:

```
67466

6     -> 6
67    -> C
 C4   -> C4
 C46  -> C46
 C467 -> C4B

C4B
```

#### How it works

```
q                       Read all input from STDIN.
 {                  }*  Fold; push the first character, and for each subsequent
                        character, push it and do the following:
  +                       Append the character to the string on the stack.
   '[,_el^                Push the string of all ASCII letters.
                          See: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54348
          {       }/      For each ASCII letter:
           _                Push a copy of the letter.
            i               Convert to integer, i.e., compute its code point.
             s              Cast to string.
              @\            Rotate and swap.
                /           Split the modified input characters at occurrences (at
                            most one) of the string repr. of the code point.
                 *          Join, separating by the corresponding letter.
```

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, <s>110</s> <s>102</s> <s>101</s> <s>68</s> 67 bytes

Pretty hard challenge. <s>This is the best I could come up with.</s> This is a completely new version.

```
for($i=64;123>$i+=$i-90?1:7;)$t[$i]=chr($i)?><?=strtr($argv[1],$t);
```

Run like this:

```
php -r 'for($i=64;123>$i+=$i-90?1:7;)$t[$i]=chr($i)?><?=strtr($argv[1],$t);' 6711110010100071111108102;echo
> Code000Golf
```

- Saved 8 bytes by using `ctype_alpha` instead of `preg_match`, thx to manatwork
- Saved 1 byte by prepending `0` to the string instead of checking non-empty string: when the last character of the input is a 0, the substring I'm taking would be "0", which is falsy, whereas "00" is truthy, so it won't skip printing the last 0.
- Saved a massive 33 bytes by using `strtr` after building an array with conversion pairs
- Saved a byte by using short print tag

Comment: Yo will have to change the regular expression to `#[A-Z]#i` as the current one will happily allow “92” to be transformed in “\”. Or try [`ctype_alpha()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php) instead of `preg_match()`. So far seems to work.

Comment: `"0", which is falsy, whereas "00" is truthy` Good going, PHP.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, <s>211</s> <s>189</s> 188 bytes

```
def f(c,i=0,n=""):
 while i<len(c):a=1;x=int(c[i:i+2]);a=2 if 64<x<91 or 96<x<100 else a;x=int(c[i:i+3]) if a<2 else x;a=3 if 99<x<123 else a;x=chr(x) if a>1 else c[i];n+=x;i+=a
 return n
```

- #### Saved 23 bytes by replacing \n with ; thanks to Dennis

### Test

[image]

Comment: If you use `;` instead of line breaks, you can put the entire while loop on a single line. Also, the first line can become `def f(c,i=0,n=""):`.

Comment: `a=1;a=2 if 64<x<91 or 96<x<100 else a` -> `a=1+(64<x<91or 96<x<100)` etc

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
JkBC:CV)R
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwiSmtCQzpDVilSIiwiIiwiXCIxMjM0NTY3XCIgPT4gMTIzNDVDXG5cIjM0NTY3ODlcIiA9PiAzNDVDWVxuXCI5ODY1NDMyXCIgPT4gYkE0MzJcblwiNjU2NjY3Njg2OTcwNzE3MjczNzQ3NTc2Nzc3ODc5ODA4MTgyODM4NDg1ODY4Nzg4ODk5MFwiID0+IEFCQ0RFRkdISUpLTE1OT1BRUlNUVVZXWFlaXG5cIjY3MTExMTAwMTAxMDAwNzExMTExMDgxMDJcIiA9PiBDb2RlMDAwR29sZiJd) Link includes test cases.

Port of @KevinCruijssen's 05AB1E answer. 
*-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
JkBC:CV)R  # Implicit input
       )R  # Reduce by:
J          #  Append to the string
 kB        #  Push constant [A-Za-z]
   C       #  Convert to codepoints
    :C     #  Duplicate and convert back
      V    #  Replace codepoints with characters
           # Implicit output
```

Comment: `rt` can be `R`. 05AB1E lacks a `reduce-by` with body builtin, which is why I've used a `cumulative reduce` with `last` combination, but Vyxal doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

### Pyth, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
.Uu:G`CHHsrBG1+bZz
```

Same algorithm as @Dennis. It's a lot easier to code in Pyth on my phone than in Jelly.

```
                implicit: z=input
.U              Reduce the following lambda b, Z over z
                b is the string being built; z is the next char
   u                Reduce the following lambda G,H over +bZ
                    G is the string, H is the next letter to match
     :                  Replace
       G                in G
       ` C H            the char code of H
       H                with H
     s rB            where H takes on values:
          G              the lowercase alphabet (that's the global value of G)
          1              concatenated to its uppercased self.
     +          
       b
       Z
   z
```

*Thanks @isaacg*

Try it [here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.Uu%3AG%60CHHsrBG1%2BbZz&input=6711110010100071111108102&debug=1).

Comment: You just can't stay off this site on your phone, can you...?

Comment: Especially when I have the luxury of coding in all printable ASCII :D

Comment: That is true, probably nice to take a break from all that jelly... You know, a balanced diet ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Å»«žnÇDç:}θ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOuh3YdWH92Xd7jd5fByq9pzO/7/NzM3BAIDA0MgNDAAcwwNLAwNjAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HYo7CgJBEETzOcWysUHPr6vaZBMvomBgooEgLGio5l7CwAsIgsEOph7Ci4zL1oMHD2q3X64263o89F3b/C63pu36Ws7Da3h83ttyXZT7/PR91ln1IaascJNpzqg5xeA0qyqUahB4BEQkZCgAwij0DIxMzFSCpJk4hR8n4kdEpvDjU4Iz6B8) or [see a step-by-step reduction with just the first 9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOuh3YdWH92Xd7jd5fByq///zcwNgcDAwBAIDQzAHEMDC0MDIwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Å»         # Cumulative left reduce the (implicit) input-string by:
  «        #  Append the current character to the string
   žn      #  Push the builtin "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     Ç     #  Convert it to a list of integer codepoints
      D    #  Duplicate this list
       ç   #  Convert each integer to its character again
           #  (so it's a list of the characters, instead of a string)
        :  #  Replace all integers with these characters (at the same indices)
           #  (would only replace 0 or 1 time)
}          # After the cumulative reduce-by is done:
 θ         # Pop the list, and only leave the last string
           # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-p`, <s>50</s> 45 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork)

```ruby
gsub(/#{[*65..90,*97..122]*?|}/){$&.to_i.chr}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpclm0km6BUuyCpaUlaboWN3XTi0uTNPSVq6O1zEz19CwNdLQszfX0DI2MYrXsa2r1NatV1PRK8uMz9ZIzimohmqB6F-w0MzcEAgMDQyA0MABzDA0sDA2MIAoA)

Comment: You can use `*` instead of `.join`: “array * string_separator → new_string (…) When String argument `string_separator` is given, equivalent to `array.join(string_separator)`”.

Comment: @manatwork Ah, of course. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 164 <sup><s>169</s></sup> bytes

> -5 bytes thanks to @KevinCruijssen !

I tried without regexp, and it was surprisingly tricky to handle all the possibilities :')

I'm seven years late to the party, but nice challenge anyway!

```java
s->{var r="";for(int i=0,j,a,m=s.length();i<m;r+=a>64&a<91|a>96&a<123?(char)(a+0*(i=j)):s.charAt(i++))for(j=i,a=0;j<m&&(a=a*10+s.charAt(j++)-48)>0&a<13;);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVPLctowFN3nKzQsGCkGR8a2HhGmQ0maNiVt2vSVdrpQjE3k@sHIgkkn4duJTGhXYGkj3XvOuS8pkyvZz2Z/NovlXa5iEOeyrsGVVCV4PDoCQJUm0amMEzC1BmDXjdGqnIMU7g41Eta@bsC1kcZqTEEOok3dHz2upAY66nREWmlopYCKcC/ryV4R1W6elHNzD5FQw0JoJ5IjEnTlkHtPcsSJPXkD/xWM76VGUDr4GKooQ@i0dhvT2EDlOAg1wlmkejLCIhsW3S6UkTz2sPMflllYP2BohBtJXyChE7PUJdBivRFN2rvSd9mvKjUDhW3ArsBfv4HU8xr9K/9vbZLCrZbGXVi3yUuYuyns2GSDkNAOQsKiTk5A8rBIYpPMwCnY@iat9C2Z8b30hnzbyuaMhIE/2Mu@G1tPK5uEhBBKGOEUU48OqE8DGlJCKWWUM8w8NmA@C1jICKOMMc7x3lDj15Oz8zcXb99dvp9effh4/enzzZev377/uP3ZHp96dmHs2Y3x9uLZoHh/PZNqlljYRZWnh1S3L7JtVJwfmFPc3mZygMjP@csfWG@eAQ)

Comment: `j=i+(a=0)` can be `j=i,a=0` for -2 bytes, and `String r="";` can be `var r="";` in JDK 10+ for another -3 bytes: [try it online](https://tinyurl.com/yhjhs76w).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice! I didn't know the trick about the "," :o And i wasn't fond of using Java>8 because of the computer i use, but i can't ignore your optimization ;) My answer has been updated

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

```python
lambda x:re.sub("6[5-9]|[7-8]\d|90|9[7-9]|1[01]\d|12[0-2]",lambda r:chr(int(r[0])),x)
import re
```

Assuming we can take in strings, otherwise this would be 100 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7RioMwEHy/r1jyZEDLJjG7G6Ffoj60V6WBViV60AP/3UvL7cAwM8zALr/bfZ7cMZ6743F5Xm8XeDVpOK0/10JR66vQ7y1X0ne3PeAess6JadG8E2NbrGyvyv9par7vqYjTVqQWe63Ll/6Kz2VOG6ThGOcEEeIEylhXe2L4sAQIQr52FsgTEZNQYGTDlh3X7JmYWTgIihErTmrxQsIiEgICscmHaDIQP8bkJlp1WpdH3ArdLOn9UyxhLKIuQakS1mE5q25S@vgD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 228 bytes

As for these warnings... let's just ignore them.

```
s :=method(H,r(H slice(0,1),H slice(1)))
r :=method(H,T,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"foreach(i,H=H asMutable replaceSeq(i asString,i asCharacter))if(T=="",return H)r(list(H,T slice(0,1))join,T slice(1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5JT8MwFITv/ArLJ1vyweYACCkHKItZytKE9ea6L42La6fPDtufDwkSqG8ub0Yjzedi3ydyWKwhN3HBtECmSfLOApNCcfFnFOd8B7eLlaBHx5OT07NzfXF5dT29ub27n5XVw@PT88urmdsF1MvGrd78OsR2gyl37x@fX9@0jgjGNswJXWhi0rTLZu6BILTeWChhw9wQlxldWIrxnTQGjc2AnLuaVUVBqUDIHQaiOTLvUh55trD5Krrwn4zsfWJ0b18NJ6UaJOWvUfJAyV3KSTusZR/6Hw)

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 51 bytes

```powershell
$args-replace(65..90+97..122-join'|'),{[char]+"$_"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDZTsMwEEXf8xVWZEiiJpGdxTNGQqIUKPu@FYSq0LoLipqSFIHU9tuDmy4wfrDnHt@r0Yyzb5UXA5WmJe2RXTItaZL3Cy9X4zTpKFvEvi9ZTYLv8yDwPrLhyJpZjjt97QyS/K1m0rY5L@eGsWcbRJdrWzwIo1iA5S5fDctZk0pHqclCb/0BiSKOwkCD9/ri3gARCyFAoJDAgEMAIUQQgwAABIkMOQYYYoQxCgRElJLplPp@4@DwqHl8cnp2fnF5dX1ze3f/8Pj03Hr5Fw1cF2NcH8aqhus8tpiikXWVFptZ2tMGh8zIFplWRlpM8uGo7xKqfsaqM1FdvTTaXrJcFV/pRAvbepernxUxqb2CnvrcOJ2dtcU05uUv)

Explanation:

- replace by RegExp `65|66|67|68|...|121|122`
- replace to result of `{[char]+"$_"}`:

  ```powershell
      $_   object with matched string 
     "$_"  matched string 
    +"$_"  convert the string to int
  ```

  [char]+"$_"  convert the int to char