# Build a chessboard

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Saw this in a PHP challenge. The objective is to make a chessboard with 64 squares (8*8) with the minimum amount of code.
Simple enough, I made mine in PHP in 356 bytes (not impressive, I know) and I would like to see some other aproaches.
This can be made in a language of your choice, as long as you keep it vanilla, so no imports.
Smallest byte count wins.

The output should look like this:

[image: screencap]

And my code:

```
<table><?php
$c='black';function p($c,$n){echo'<td style="width:50px;height:50px;background:'.$c.'"></td>';if($n==1){echo"<tr>";}}for($i=1;$i<=64;$i++){if($i%8==0&&$c=="black"){$c="white";$n=1;}elseif($i%8==0&&$c=="white"){$c="black";$n=1;}elseif(isset($n)&&$n==1){$n=0;}elseif($c=="black"){$n=0;$c="white";}elseif($c=="white"){$n=0;$c="black";}p($c,$n);}
```

Or readable:

```
<table><tr>
<?php
$color = 'black';
function printcolor($color, $nl) {

    echo '<td style="width:50px; height:50px; background:' . $color . '"></td>';
    if ($nl == true) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
}
for ($i=1; $i<=64;$i++) {
    if ($i % 8 == 0 && $color == "black") {
        $color = "white";
        $nl = true;
    } elseif ($i % 8 == 0 && $color == "white") {
        $color = "black";
        $nl = true;
    } elseif (isset($nl) && $nl == true) {      
        $nl = false;
    } elseif ($color == "black") {
        $nl = false;
        $color = "white";           
        } 
    elseif ($color == "white")  {
        $nl = false;
        $color = "black";
    }       
    printcolor($color, $nl);
}
```

**Edit:**

Sorry I wasn't very specific at first:

- Squares should have 50px * 50px except for vectorial images.
- Output format or size is not relevant nor it needs to be an image.
- For evaluation purposes the output must be visible such as in an image file or a screenshot
- No libraries written after the challenge was posted

Comment: Minimum number of pixels? I assume 64 is not sufficient?

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, as it stands, this challenge doesn't really have anything to do with PHP, so I changed your tags. Also, I believe your reference implementation belongs as an answer, not in your question. As Stewie brought up, you should specify the required size of the image output, as well as things like colour specifics and whether a lossy image is allowed.

Comment: Can the output be in any image format?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, for some reason the JS on stackexchange has issues on my Google chrome. Sorry for not being very specific, it's my first post here. Image format or size is not relevant. Squares should have 50px * 50px.

Comment: So some ASCII-magic is not allowed? :(

Comment: This pattern is more commonly referred to as a [checkerboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkerboard), this challenge doesn't really have anything to do with chess as a game.

Comment: @DenkerAffe You could output in [PPM.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

Comment: @mınxomaτ Sorry, I just saw the title and instinctively added the chess tag :P I'll remove that.

Comment: How will you evaluate that the program works? Online compilers don't usually allow graphic output. Also, should the upper-left square be white, or can it be black?

Comment: @DenkerAffe, for ASCII there is [Chessboard pattern](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/chessboard-pattern).

Comment: @LuisMendo The output must be visible, like an image file or a print screen. It should start and end with a white square

Comment: Are vector graphics allowed as output?

Comment: Also can there be any kind of frame around the result?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Vector graphics are allowed, as long as the colors and dimensions of the squares are correct. There can be a frame around the result.

Comment: Define "imports"? Does using external programs in Bash count as imports? (Keep in mind that this would be a very severe restriction—even basic commands like `cat` are external programs.)

Comment: Basic commands in bash like cat are allowed.

Comment: How basic is basic? What is the definition of an "import"?

Comment: Bash suport cat outsider the box so it's valid. However if you download and include a third party library, it's not.

Comment: @Bruno do the squares have to be black and white? Can they be black and grey for example (as long as the difference is obvious)

Comment: @muddyfish they must be b&w like a propper checkerboard :)

Comment: @Doorknob You can't [say things like this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71093/build-a-chessboard/71111#comment173980_71093) and expect us not to see it as a challenge http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71111/11259 ;-)

Comment: It doesn't need to be an image but each square must be at least 50px? That seems self-contradictory to me.

Comment: @Bruno Bash does *not* support `cat` "out of the box." It's an external program. It's perfectly valid to be running Bash without having `cat` (although it would be very, very strange).

Comment: Those last 2 requirements seem unclear and contradictory as well. It doesn't have to be any particular size, nor an image, but you have to display an image. Can I return an array that can be displayed as an image? Does that array have to have a particular size, or does it simply have to *display* at a minimum size?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Both the example PHP and my PowerShell answer do not output images, yet each square is 50px...

Comment: Programming languages here are very diverse, including some that are made specifically for golfing and have many builtin functions. Therefore, I recommend that the restriction to non-library functions be removed, and that this question instead follow the default (all imports counted in byte count; no libraries written after the challenge was posted).

Comment: @Bruno, the requirement certainly becomes better, but I find that ”If you have to import it, it's not valid” ambiguous. That sounds like we can draw using ImageMagick in PHP as there no explicit import is needed, but we can not do the same in Perl, Python or Ruby as there an explicit import is needed.

Comment: @manatwork that is correct. Imagemagic is built into PHP so it's valid. However, if you have to do something like @import('imagemagic') or @include('thisscriptwhereipasscolorsandsizeanditwilloutputmeapng.php') it's not.

Comment: “Imagemagic is built into PHP” – Installed as separate package ([php5-imagick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/php5-imagick)), provided as separate library (imagick.so), configured through separate file (imagick.ini). Not so sure it is built in.

Comment: @manatwork i understand your point. The limitation is to prevent people from creating a library that automates the process and creating a file by simply doing generatechessboard(50,#000,#FFF) on the PHP file and thus have a 30 byte count. When you install php, imagemagic is included by default and you don't need to add any header to use it in your code so it's valid.

Comment: Oh. I see your point. For that reason suggested @ThomasKwa to formulate in the usual way: “no libraries written after the challenge was posted”.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Edited the description, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Why did you accept the Octave answer? The MATL answer is 7 bytes shorter.

Comment: The MATL answer starts with black instead of white. I couldn't test the image but I tested it with 1 and 0 online at http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ODp0IStRMlwK&input= by removing the TYG

Comment: @Bruno The question does not state any requirement that the top-left corner is white. That answer is valid.

Comment: The screenshots suggest otherwise. In any case, I wouldn't recommend silently disqualifying an answer because you *think* it doesn't work. At least post a comment on the answer.

Comment: @Mego comment #10. It should be added to the requirement but it's clearly stated

Comment: @edc65 Comments are not binding unless they are added to the spec, because comments are transient and can disappear without warning. That's one of the things listed on the things to avoid meta post.

Comment: If a border is allowed, can that border be an infinite extension of the board? It would shave Desmos down to at most 21 bytes, but it doesn't feel in the spirit of the challenge.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Octave, <s>20</s> 18 bytes

Thanks to [@Bruno](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/49903/bruno) for shaving off 2 bytes.

```
imshow(invhilb(8))
```

Result:

[image]

This answer uses a technique found [here](http://matlabtricks.com/post-31/three-ways-to-generate-a-checkerboard-matrix). It also relies on the automatic scaling of images in Octave depending on the size of the figure window.

Comment: @AlexA. I'm also not entirely convinced that the squares must be exactly 50x50 pixels, as the very next rule says "Output format or size is not relevant...". People have asked for clarification in the comments, but the question has not been updated.

Comment: Edited the question. Tested your code and it's working, so currently you have the lowest byte count :)

Comment: Also removed the >0 and it still works so you can shave 2 bytes there

Comment: @Bruno What? That is wild. So it's apparently clamping the values of the matrix (which are all <<0 or >>1) to 0 and 1. Thanks for the tip, I'll update! :D

Comment: Congrats on 2k!

Answer (score 27):

### vim, <s>47</s> <s>46</s> <s>44</s> 43

<sup>crossed out 44 is still regular 44...</sup>

```
iP1 400 <C-p><cr><esc>50i1<esc>YpVr0yk3PyG49PyG:m$<cr>p2GyG3P
```

```
i          enter insert mode
P1         signal to NetPPM that we're using black&white (PBM) format
400        width
<C-p>      fancy trick that inserts the other 400 for height
<cr><esc>  exit insert mode on the next line
50i1<esc>  insert 50 '1's (black)
YpVr0      insert 50 '0's (white) by duplicating the line and replacing all chars
yk         copy both lines (yank-up)
3P         paste three times; this leaves us on line two
yG         copy from line 2 to end of file (this is a full row of pixels now)
49P        we need 50 rows of pixels to make a complete "row"; paste 49 times
yG         copy the entire row of the checkerboard
:m$<cr>    move line 2 (the line we're currently on) to the end of the file
           this gives us the "alternating rows" effect
p          we're now on the last line: paste the entire row we copied earlier
2G         hop back to line 2 (beginning of image data)
yG3P       copy the entire image data, paste 3 times
```

Outputs in NetPPM format (PBM):

[image: output]

Comment: I love that you can complete a graphical output challenge with a text editor. Are there any other examples of PBMs from golfed vim?

Comment: @dohaqatar7 I dunno, but I've done TikZ with vim before, so graphics in vim is a thing for sure.

Comment: Wow, I never thought to try `<C-p>` in vim without having started typing a word... that is really handy!

Answer (score 18):

### CSS, 244 bytes

```
html{background:#fff}body{width:400px;height:400px;background:linear-gradient(45deg,#000 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 75%,#000 75%)0 0/100px 100px,linear-gradient(45deg,#000 25%,transparent 25%,transparent 75%,#000 75%)50px 50px/100px 100px}
```

```css
html {
    background: white;
}
body {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background:
        linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%) 0px 0px / 100px 100px,
        linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%) 50px 50px / 100px 100px
}
```

Explanation: A 100x100px diagonal linear gradient is created with four stops so that most of the gradient is transparent except for two 50px triangular corners. (See below snippet). Adding a second gradient with a 50x50px offset fills in the missing halves of the squares. Increasing the size of the body then allows the resulting pattern to repeat to fill the entire chessboard.

```css
html {
    background: white;
}
body {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%) 0px 0px / 100px 100px
}
```

Comment: Neat solution. It should work as well if you drop the last `} `.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here?

Comment: @flawr I've added a second snippet showing the partial effect, I hope that helps.

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: Do you really need the `html{background:#fff}`? By default 99% of browsers set the background to white, afaik

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ If I don't do that then the body's background gets applied to the canvas, ruining the effect.

Answer (score 17):

### Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
ArrayPlot@Array[Mod[+##,2]&,{8,8}]
```

The output is a vector image and is surrounded in a frame.

Instead of correctly positioning 32 rectangles, we can just generate a binary matrix and make `ArrayPlot` work for us:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Looking good. Can you please explain me where do you define each square as 50px? Also, is there an online emulator where I can test it?

Comment: @Bruno The output is a vector graphic, so there is no such thing as pixel sizes (the image has no intrinsic size - it can be scaled to and displayed at any size). That's why I asked.

Comment: Ok, silly me, I was thinking SVG :) Fair enough, I'll allow it. Good work

Comment: Wait, `GenerateChessBoardWithColorsAsParameters[ColorBlack, ColorWhite, 8, 8, 50, 50]` doesn't work? ;)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ It does, but that's 73 bytes.

Comment: Oh? Darn. Haha!

Comment: 33 bytes: `ArrayPlot[Plus~Array~{8,8}~Mod~2]`

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, <s>81</s> <s>72</s> 55 bytes

```
Graphics[Rectangle/@Select[Range@8~Tuples~2,2∣Tr@#&]]
```

[image: Input/Output]

Image is of a previous version's evaluation, but still looks the same.

Answer (score 9):

## Pure Bash (no external utilities), 133

I saw [@Doorknob's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71093/build-a-chessboard/71111#comment173980_71093) as a bit of a challenge. Its a bit long, but here goes:

```bash
echo \# ImageMagick pixel enumeration:400,400,1,rgb
for((;x=p%400,y=p/400,c=1-(x/50^y/50)&1,p++<160000;));{
echo "$x,$y:($c,$c,$c)"
}
```

Output is in [Imagemagick's .txt format](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#txt).  Note this is pure Bash.  Neither Imagemagick nor any other external utilities are spawned to generate this output.  However, the output may be redirected to a .txt file and viewed with the ImageMagick `display` utility:

[image]

This image format is nice because not only is it pure text, it is little more than a list of all pixels (x, y and colour value), one per line.  It is a fairly simple matter to derive all pixel values arithmetically in one big loop.

---

## Previous answer, 167

```bash
echo "\"400 400 2 1\"
\"  c white\"
\"b c black\""
printf -vf %50s
a="$f${f// /b}"
o=("\"$a$a$a$a\"" "\"${f// /b}$a$a$a$f\"")
for i in {0..399};{
echo "${o[i/50%2]}"
}
```

Output is in the [X_PixMap text image file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_PixMap#XPM2), which may also be viewed with the ImageMagick `display` utility.

Note I've taken as much out of the XPM format as I could such that `display` would still accept it.  I was able to take out all the [c](/questions/tagged/c) boilerplate with the exception of the `"` double quotes around each line.  No idea what other - if any - utilities will accept this.

Comment: Oooh, interesting ;)

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell + browser of your choice, <s>149</s> 143 bytes

<sub>The inability to use imports is really tough, as all of the GDI calls (i.e., the stuff PowerShell uses to draw) are buried behind imports in .NET ...</sub>

```
"<table><tr>"+((1..8|%{$a=$_;-join(1..8|%{'<td style="width:50px;height:50px'+("",";background:#000")[($a+$_)%2]+'"></td>'})})-join'</tr><tr>')
```

<sub>Edit - saved six bytes thanks to [@NotThatCharles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13950/not-that-charles)</sub>

This uses two for-loops from `1..8` to generate a big-ol' HTML string, similar to the PHP example provided, and output it onto the pipeline. Each time through we calculate whether to append `;background:#000` for the black backgrounds by taking our current position on the board modulo 2.

To use, redirect the output into the file of your choice (e.g., with something like `> chessboard.htm`) and then launch that in the browser of your choice. For the screenshot below, I used "c.htm" and Firefox.

[image: firefox]

Comment: This one was unespected but I quite like it somehow :)

Comment: `white` and `black` can be `#fff` and `#000`... but why bother specifying white?

Comment: try `(";background:#000","")[($a+$_)%2]` instead.

Comment: @NotthatCharles Durr, had my white and black flip-flopped, so it was only outputting white squares. Corrected for an additional 4 bytes saved.

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, 48 bytes

```
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​imwrite(kron(mod((t=0:7)+t',2),ones(50)),'.png')
```

This works exactly the same as my [Matlab answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71120/24877), but there is no `spiral` in Octave. Instead we use a feature that Matlab does not have: We can use the assignment of `t` already as an expression, and later use `t` again in the same expression.

(This is the rescaled version, I do not want to clutter the answers here=)

[image]

Comment: The top left corner should be white, not black.

Comment: The output should be a checkerboard, the orientation was not specified.

Comment: Sorry, flawr, the output should be a chessboard. A chessboard is always "Queen on her color, white on the right" (meaning the right hand of each player has a white corner square).

Comment: Then imagine one player sitting to the right, one to the left. Again: this was not specified by the challenge, that is just your interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://python.org), <s>365</s>, <s>288</s>, <s>270</s>, 256 bytes

Thanks @Razetime, @mehbark and @Amazeryogo for the suggestions

```python
from turtle import *
B=range
H=Screen()
A=Turtle()
def F():
    for C in B(4):A.fd(30);A.lt(90)
    A.fd(30)
for D in B(8):
    A.up();A.setpos(0,30*D);A.pd()
    for G in B(8):
        if(D+G)%2==0:E='black'
        else:E='white'
        A.fillcolor(E);A.begin_fill();F();A.end_fill()
```

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@IntrstedCoder/chessboard)

Admittedly not good:) first contribution

[image: Output]

Comment: `forward` can become `fd`, `left` to `lt`, `down` to `pd`. You can probably remove the definition of G since it has no parameters as well, including in main program. Since the background is white, you don't need the else statement.

Comment: oh, thanks :) will edit

Comment: [269 by refactoring the if statement](https://tio.run/##TY7NbsIwEITvfoq9VF4jZJmmqvgphxAE3Nt7FeINWHVtyzGq@vTBDqrUwx5mdvabDb/p6l01jrttbN2FmPkOPiZIt5gsQTtAww7bRr53kcihYHUWH9MyC009HFGsGfQ@QgPGwQ5fxLqWvcZKiU0tbcKVEgz@LHaQA6VbwFel5nkyUQ6BSOOiiMLZPzjLwq1ljhZOPgp@QDWv1GxfjKDzA1Pv6V@@9BhrO299RH62bffFZ1g9Pb8thI/852oS8XJ@potxnyWb8cepgpx@GHwc7w "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Lyxal It gives an error https://i.imgur.com/KOaiOEl.png

Comment: @agent355 just change the last `'` to `)`

Comment: https://gyazo.com/d0c985048b2883e9dd24553556e80348

Does not work

Comment: the last for loop can be written like this
`for G in B(8):A.fillcolor('white'if(D+G)%2else'black');A.begin_fill();F();A.end_fill()`

Comment: I believe you can shave 3 bytes by using `from turtle import*` and then `H=Screen()
A=Turtle()`

Comment: @Lyxal gyazo.com/d0c985048b2883e9dd24553556e80348 look at this, it doesn't fill them

Comment: Alright, [this works for 241 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY3NDoIwEAbvfYq9GLZoCIoH/zigRL3r3Sgs0ljaptYYnx4pauJtM5mdz7xcrVXStpXVDbiHdZJANEZbByFbp/asrsT26aGwRAo5y9JjL3VnSRVskS8YVNrCBoSCNU75IouqEpOYL7NIOpzHnMEPMW/mH3PmP7PoYdCbd3JG3zEeJXGYe2DKbqIv7/58XxJSFlpqi8FFnotbECLmwx0fTFZjrm3wrIWjwCcudBXq5P1uYtvPkCq/oG3f "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: It wasn't working because I forgot to re-include the part which dynamically chooses the colour (`D+G`) which I removed to test my refactoring.

Comment: [232 bytes, verified by running it locally](https://tio.run/##TY29DoIwFEb3PsVdDLdoCIqDogwgQXfdDT8FiaVtShl8eqSoidvNyfnOVS/zkCIYx1rLDsygDWfQdkpqAy5JIp2LhpFLdC01YwIpiaPbLE1nxWrIkIYEaqnhBK2ABLc0jL26wsCnh9jjBvc@JfBDxJrpx9zZZewNCq3ZM6Nkj/4q8N3UAlVNL@by@c@3pZbzUnKp0Sl4Xj4dFzFdnulic1xTuyxY04q71aZyNteZqL5gHN8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Doesnt work @Lyxal   https://gyazo.com/0fbe2379d56f30e9881a3fe940291de7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116870/discussion-between-agent355-and-lyxal).

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 11 (27) bytes

```
8:t!+Q2\TYG
```

This produces the following figure. It doesn't have an intrinsic size; it's automatically scaled depending on the size of the figure window. This seems to be allowed by the challenge.

[image]

#### Explanation

```
8:      % row vector [1,2,...8]
t!      % duplicate and transpose into column vector
+       % 8x8 matrix with all pairwise additions
Q       % add 1
2\      % modulo 2. Gives 8x8 matrix of zeros and ones
TYG     % draw image
```

---

If autoscaling is not allowed:

```
'imshow'8:t!+Q2\50t3$Y"0#X$
```

produces the following figure with 50x50-pixel squares

#### Explanation

[image]

```
'imshow'   % name of Matlab function
8:t!+Q2\   % same as above. Produces 8x8 matrix of zeros and ones
50t3$Y"    % repeat each element 50 times in each dimension
0#X$       % call imshow function with above matrix as input
```

Answer (score 5):

## Pyth, <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
J*4+*50]255*50]0.wm_mxkdJJ
```

Explanation

```
J                          - Autoassign J = V
           *50]0           - 50*[0]
    *50]255                - 50*[255]
   +                       - ^^+^
 *4                        - 4*^
                .w         - write_greyscale(V)
                  m      J - [V for d in J]
                   _       - reversed(V) 
                    m   J  - [V for k in J]
                     xkd   - k^d
```

Python equivalent

```
J = 4*(50*[255]+50*[0])
write_greyscale([[k^d for k in J][::-1] for d in J])
```

[Try it here (just the colour values)](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J*4%2B*50%5D255*50%5D0jbm_mxkdJJ&debug=0)

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Nice job on the byte count but I need a valid output with visible squares :)

Comment: @Bruno Output added! I installed PIL just for you :O (I hadn't actually tested it before)

Comment: @muddyfish sorry for the trouble and thanks. The board must start with and end with a white square tho :)

Answer (score 5):

## PHP + CSS + HTML, 136 bytes

Taking the table aproach to a higher level:

```
<table><?for(;++$i<9;)echo'<tr>',str_repeat(["<td b><td>","<td><td b>"][$i&1],4);?><style>td{width:50px;height:50px}[b]{background:#000}
```

It generates the following code:

```html
<table><tr><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><tr><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><tr><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><tr><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><tr><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><tr><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><tr><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><tr><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><td b><td><style>td{width:50px;height:50px}[b]{background:#000}
```

It relies heavily on browsers' kindness and CSS.

Comment: Good solution. Tho I had to include php after <? and include $i=0 as the first for parameter to get it working properly, giving a final result of 144 bytes.

Comment: @Bruno If you refer to the warning it gives, warnings are disregarded here. However, there's a trillion ways of disabling them. One of them is to replace `++$i<9` with `@++$i<9`. Also, for it to work without `<?php`, one must have the directive `short_open_tags=On`, which is default on some environments. Read more on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2185331/2729937

Answer (score 5):

## Jelly, 26 bytes

```
400R%2ẋ€50FU;$ẋ4;;;1j⁶;”PU
```

Since Jelly has no support for images built in, we print a PPM image.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#jelly#code=NDBSJTLhuovigqw1RlU7JOG6izQ7OzsxauKBtjvigJ1QVQ&input=) (smaller board for speed, raw PPM)

#### Results

[image: screenshot]

#### How it works

```
400R%2ẋ€50FU;$ẋ4;;;1j⁶;”PU  Main link. No arguments.

400                         Set the left argument to 400.
   R                        Yield [1, ..., 400].
    %2                      Compute the parity of each integer.
      ẋ€50                  Replace each parity by an array of 50 copies of itself.
          F                 Flatten the resulting, nested list.
                            This creates the first rank of the board.
             $              Combine the two atoms to the left:
           U                  Reverse the array of parities.
            ;                 Concatenate the reversed array with the original.
                            This creates the first two ranks of the board.
              ẋ4            Repeat the resulting list four times.
                            This creates all eight ranks of the board.
                ;           Append 400, the link's left argument.
                 ;          Append 400, the link's left argument.
                  ;1        Append 1.
                    j⁶      Join, separating by spaces.
                      ;”P   Append the character 'P'.
                         U  Reverse the resulting list.
```

#### Non-competing version (24 bytes)

The newest Jelly interpreter that predates this post didn't vectorize `x` properly. With the latest version, 2 additional bytes can be saved.

```
400R%2x50U;$ẋ4;;;1j⁶;”PU
```

The only difference is that `x50` yields a flat list (with every original element repeated 50 times), so `F` is no longer necessary.

Comment: It looks like you were writing a java answer and fell asleep slightly whilst typing a `;`... ;)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Java? You must be on Java 10.0, Golfing Edition, cause that doesn't look like any Java I've seen....

Answer (score 5):

## FFmpeg, 78 <s>82 100</s> bytes

Finally got around to cleaning the board.

```
ffplay -f lavfi color=s=400x400,geq='255*mod(trunc(X/50)+trunc(Y/50)+1,2):128'
```

[image]

---

**Older**:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=tan@0:256x256,format=ya8" -vf "scale=400:-1:alphablend=checkerboard" .jpg
```

Will exit with error, but after producing image below.

[image]

(board's collected some dust)

Answer (score 4):

## Matlab, 47 (24) bytes

```
imwrite(kron(mod(spiral(8),2),ones(50)),'.png')
```

This works exactly the same as my [Octave answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71118/24877), but I was able to use `spiral` which saved one byte. `spiral(n)` makes an `nxn` matrix and fills it spiraling with the first `n^2` integers.

If vectorgraphics are allowed, we could do it in 24 bytes:

```
imshow(mod(spiral(8),2))
```

(This is the rescaled version, I do not want to clutter the answers here=)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

HTML with utf-8 - 66b

```html
<div style="font:100 50px/48px serif">▚▚▚▚<br>▚▚▚▚<br>▚▚▚▚<br>▚▚▚▚
```

▚ is short-direct utf for entity **&# 9626 ;**

[Unicode Character 'QUADRANT UPPER LEFT AND LOWER RIGHT' (U+259A)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/259a/index.htm)

silly me, was looking for a 1 utf-8 char solution  -would have been... 1b!

Comment: Seems like fontsize is wrong.

Comment: You should use `▞` instead so that the top-left square is white like on a standard chessboard. Also, use `<pre>` instead of `<div>` so that you can use newlines instead of `<br>`.

Comment: Your bytecount appears to be wrong, it should be 98 bytes, as `▚` counts for 3 bytes using UTF-8 encoding. In the future, you can use [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4944/byte-counter-snippet) to check your UTF-8 Byte Count

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <sup><s>51</s></sup> 30 bytes

```apl
'P1'
2⍴400
50/50⌿(⍳8)⌽8 8⍴'01'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L96gKE6l9Gj3i0mBgZcpgb6pgaPevZrPOrdbKH5qGevhYIFUErdwFAdpPp/AQA)

Outputs a netpbm image. Save the result to a .pbm file and view [here](http://paulcuth.me.uk/netpbm-viewer/).

Since the output is too large for tio, here's the [generated output.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/razetime/code-golf/master/APL-code/chessboard.ppm)

-21 bytes(!) from Adám.

Here's the output converted to png:

[image]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG9qZv6jtgkG/9UDDNW5jB71bjExMODSMDU4PN3UQP9R72YLzUc9ezWAggpADJTWAMoBKXUDdU0dKNNQXVNT8z/FJgAA)

Comment: [30](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94L96gKE6l9Gj3i0mBgZcpgb6pgaPevZrPOrdbKH5qGevhYIFUErdwFAdpPp/AQA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 27 bytes

```
"P1"400__,2f%50e*_W%+4*~]S*
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=IlAxIjQwX18sMmYlNWUqX1clKzQqfl1TKg&input=) (smaller board for speed, raw PPM)

#### Results

[image: screenshot]

#### How it works

```
"P1"                        e# Push that string.
    400__                   e# Push three copies of 400.
         ,                  e# Turn the last one into [0 ... 399].
          2f%               e# Compute the parity of each integer.
             50e*           e# Repeat each parity 50 times.
                            e# This creates the first rank of the board.
                 _W%        e# Create a reversed copy of the resulting array.
                    +       e# Concatenate the original with the reversed array.
                            e# This creates the first two ranks of the board.
                     4*     e# Repeat the resulting array four times.
                            e# This creates all eight ranks of the board.
                       ~    e# Dump all of its items (the pixels) on the stack.
                        ]   e# Wrap the entire stack in an array.
                         S* e# Join that array, separating them by spaces.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yl6ahgqphz), 136 bytes

```
ceil(sin(x))\left\{6<x<29\right\}>=ceil(sin(y))\left\{0<y<26\right\}
ceil(sin(x))\left\{3<x<27\right\}<=ceil(sin(y))\left\{0<y<24\right\}
```

[image: A typical black and white chessboard with the first square being white, plotted on a graph, offset to the right of the y-axis by about three units.]
This was the first thing I thought of when I saw this challenge, hopefully it's not stretching it too far.

Comment: Nice answer! You don't need to worry so long as your answer fits the guidelines. (This question isn't very specific, so it's alright)

Comment: The code provided wasn't in the correct format for Desmos, per consensus [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19317/96155). The issue is with the inequalities, which don't work as nicely as they look like they should. I've gone ahead and fixed it for you, and using >= instead of ≥ saves a byte for each line as well.

Comment: 60-byter: `sin(\pi x)\sin\pi y>0\left\{max(abs(x-4),abs(y-4))<4\right\}`

Answer (score 2):

### PHP >=5.4, <s>175</s> <s>159</s> <s>149</s> 116 Bytes

```
<table><tr><? for(;@++$i<65;)echo'<td width=50 height=50 ',$i+@$m&1?:'bgcolor=0','>',$i%8<1?'<tr '.($m=@!$m).'>':'';
```

```html
<table><tr><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><tr 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><tr ><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><tr 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><tr ><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><tr 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><tr ><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><tr 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=0><td width=50 height=50 1><tr >
```

### Notes

- Shaved 16 bytes - Thanks @insertusernamehere
- Shaved 10 bytes - Thanks @msh210
- Shaved 30 bytes - Thanks @Ismael Miguel

Comment: Probably this can be golfed even more, but here you go (*152 bytes*): `<table><tr><?php for(;++$i<65;){echo'<td style="width:50px;height:50px;background:#'.(($i+$m)%2?'000':'').'"></td>';if($i%8<1){echo"</tr><tr>";$m=!$m;}}`

Comment: While i didn't remove the initial assignments(Works, personal quirk won't let me do it), Thank for this

Comment: According to even [the strict version](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html) of HTML 4, [you can skip](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.3) the end tag for `TR`.

Comment: Ok that was beautiful :)

Comment: thanks @msh210, same goes for `TD` didn't even think about that

Comment: Replace `++$i<65` with `@++$i<65`, since you are worried about the warnings. This means that you can reduce `$m=$i=0` to just `$m=0`, saving you 2 bytes. Instead of `echo 'a'.'b'.'c';`, you can do `echo 'a','b','c';`. This means that your `echo` can be `echo'<td style="width:50px;height:50px;background:#',($i+$m)%2?'':'000','">';` saving you more 2 bytes. Also, HTML attributes don't require quotes. Remove them and sabe 2 bytes. Also, there's a much shorter `bgcolor` attribute, that reduces more bytes! You can use a `print()` in the `for` to save even more bytes!

Comment: To save even more, I've replaced `($i+$m)%2` with `$i+@$m&1`, which allowed me to remove that `$m=0`. Ahead, I've been able to remove your `if`, and replaced it with a trenary operation. To save **even more**, I've removed your `style` and added the properties `width` and `height`. To get even more into the hacky side, I've figured that Chrome 48.0.2564.103 m uses black if the background color is `0`, using the property `bgcolor`. That allowed me to ever reduce more! More reductions is better!

Comment: The code: `<table><tr><?php for(;@++$i<65;)echo'<td width=50 height=50 bgcolor=',$i+@$m&1?'':0,'>',$i%8<1?'<tr '.($m=@!$m).'>':'';` - **119 bytes**, effectivelly [killing my own answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71127/14732)! Try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afd12390d40f03606befdcd77a61adfc006d7310 and test the output on https://jsfiddle.net/sgtuo1au/

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>166</s> <s>158</s> 155 bytes

Works in PHP 7.0.2 (short-tags enabled) and Chrome 48.0.2564.97 m

```
<table><tr><? while(++$i<=8){while(++$j<=8){echo"<td style=background-color:".($i%2==0?($j%2==1?0:""):($j%2==0?0:"")).";padding:9></td>";}echo"<tr>";$j=0;}
```

Comment: You can use the property `bgcolor=0` to generate the black background. That should shave off a ton of bytes! And instead of `$v%2==0`, use `$v&1`, which should shave a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [iKe](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok/tree/gh-pages/ike), 24 bytes

```
,(;cga;t=\:t:2!-20!!160)
```

[image: board]

The core of the technique is to generate a list of x coordinates, divmod them and then take an equality cross-product to generate an appropriate bitmap. Using smaller examples for illustrative purposes:

```
  !8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

  -2!!8
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3

  2!-2!!8
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1

  t=\:t:2!-2!!8
(1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1)
```

[try it here](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/ike/ike.html?gist=5735a344f4bd5c36868f). Technically iKe works on a logical 160x160 pixel canvas, but in full-screen mode (the default when following a saved link) this is upscaled by 3x. I think this is still following the spirit of the question, as the program could assemble a much larger bitmap with the same character count; it just comes down to an arbitrary display limitation.

### Update:

iKe isn't primarily designed for golf, but livecoding still benefits from brevity and sane defaults. As a result of tinkering with this problem, I've decided to permit it to use a default palette if none is provided. This particular solution could now be expressed with:

```
,(;;t=\:t:2!-20!!160)
```

Saving (an ineligible) 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 - 80

Generates a .PBM file:

```
print 'P1'.' 400'x2 .$".(((0 x50 .1 x50)x4 .$")x50 .((1 x50 .0 x50)x4 .$")x50)x4
```

Answer (score 2):

## GIMP, 539 bytes

```
gimp -i -b '(let* ((i (car (gimp-image-new 400 400 1))) (d (car (gimp-layer-new i 400 400 2 "b" 100 0)))) (gimp-image-insert-layer i d 0 -1) (define (t x y) (gimp-selection-translate i x y)) (define (x) (t 100 0)) (define (X) (t -100 0)) (define (y) (t 50 50)) (define (Y) (t -50 50)) (define (f) (gimp-edit-fill d 1)) (define (r) (f) (x) (f) (x) (f) (x) (f) (y)) (define (R) (f) (X) (f) (X) (f) (X) (f) (Y)) (gimp-image-select-rectangle i 2 0 0 50 50) (r) (R) (r) (R) (r) (R) (r) (R) (gimp-file-save 1 i d "c.png" "c.png") (gimp-quit 0))'
```

Ungolfed Scheme script-fu:

```
(let* ((i (car (gimp-image-new 400 400 GRAY)))
       (d (car (gimp-layer-new i 400 400 GRAY-IMAGE "b" 100 NORMAL-MODE))))

  (gimp-image-insert-layer i d 0 -1)
  (define (t x y) (gimp-selection-translate i x y))
  (define (x) (t 100 0))
  (define (X) (t -100 0))
  (define (y) (t 50 50))
  (define (Y) (t -50 50))
  (define (f) (gimp-edit-fill d BACKGROUND-FILL))
  (define (r) (f) (x) (f) (x) (f) (x) (f) (y))
  (define (R) (f) (X) (f) (X) (f) (X) (f) (Y))

  (gimp-image-select-rectangle i CHANNEL-OP-REPLACE 0 0 50 50)
  (r) (R) (r) (R) (r) (R) (r) (R)
  (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE i d "c.png" "c.png")
  (gimp-quit 0))
```

In batch mode, create a blank image, create a 50x50 rectangular selection, fill it, and then repeatedly move it around the image, filling in squares. Then save to `c.png` and exit.

Output:

[image: chessboard png]

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
image(matrix(1:0,9,8)[-1,],c=1:0,ax=F)
```

[Try it at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=image(matrix(1%3A0%2C9%2C8)%5B-1%2C%5D%2Cc%3D1%3A0%2Cax%3DF))

This nicely exploits R's argument-recycling to fill a `matrix()` with dimensions of `9,8` with values of `1:0` recycled to fill it.  We then use negative indexing `[-1,]` to chop-off the first row.

The `image()` function converts a matrix directly into a coloured image.  Here we specify the `c`olor as `1:0` (black & white), and the `ax`es as `F`ALSE.

[image]

Comment: How does this fit the 50 pixel per square rule?

Comment: 'except for vectorial images'.  If the image isn't saved, it's rendered (on most setups) in a resizeable graphics window (I took a screenshot to upload the image, so that would have 'fixed' it at a random size).

Comment: `image(matrix(1:0,9,8)[-1,],c=1:0,ax=F)` should work for -2 bytes.

Comment: @RobinRyder - good catch!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## AppleSoft Basic, 146 bytes

The best (standard) resolution available on the Apple II is `HGR2` mode, at 280x192 pixels, so the squares are 24x24.
Verified at https://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/

```basic
0HGR2:HCOLOR=3:A=0:B=167:GOSUB8:A=24:B=191:GOSUB8:END
8FORI=A TOB STEP48:FORJ=A TOB STEP48:FORK=0TO23:HPLOTI+K,J TOI+K,J+23:NEXT:NEXT:NEXT:RETURN
```

<sub>image credit: [Apple II Basic Bot](https://twitter.com/appleiibot/status/1332146305812992000?s=21) on twitter</sub>

[image]

If we totally ignore resolution & use `GR` mode, 107 bytes:

```basic
1GR:COLOR=15:A=0:B=7:GOSUB8:A=1:B=8:GOSUB8:END
8FORI=A TOB STEP2:FORJ=A TOB STEP2:PLOTI,J:NEXT:NEXT:RETURN
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 150

This can definitely be golfed.  It creates HTML.

```js
for(i=0;i<8;)console.log(`<b style=margin-${['lef','righ'][i++%2]}t:50;width:50;height:50;display:inline-block;background:#000></b>`.repeat(4)+'<br>')
```

Comment: Huh, I never knew about template strings in JavaScript. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby with Shoes, 97 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app(width:400){64.times{|i|stack(width:50,height:50){background [white,black][(i/8+i)%2]}}}
```

Sample output:

[image: Chessboard drawn by Ruby with Shoes]

Comment: Should start and end with white. Otherwise good job :)

Comment: Oops. Thanks @Bruno. Fixed.

Comment: Great, upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

## Lua + LÖVE, <s>138</s> <s>113</s> <s>112</s> 106 characters

```lua
function love.draw()for i=0,31 do
love.graphics.rectangle("fill",i%8*50,(i-i%8)/8*100+i%2*50,50,50)end
end
```

Sample output:

[image: Chessboard drawn by Lua + LÖVE]

Comment: Grr! Lua 5.3 has `//` integer division operator, but apparently there is still no LÖVE built with a LuaJIT featuring it. ☹

Answer (score 1):

### PowerShell + GDI, 346 bytes

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$f=New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$f.width=$f.height=450
$g=$f.CreateGraphics()
$f.add_paint({0..7|%{$y=$_;0..7|%{$g.FillRectangle((New-Object Drawing.SolidBrush ("white","black")[($_+$y)%2]),(new-object Drawing.Rectangle ($_*50),($y*50),50,50))}}})
$f.showDialog()
```

<sub>(newlines count same as semicolon, so newlines for readability)</sub>

As opposed to my other [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71106/42963), this one uses the .NET assemblies to call [GDI+](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533798(v=vs.85).aspx) function calls. Interestingly, it's about twice the length.

The first two lines load the `System.Windows.Forms` and `System.Drawing` assemblies. The first is used for the literal window and the canvas thereon, the second is used for the drawing object (in this code, a brush) that create the graphics on the canvas.

We then create our form `$f` with the next line, and set its `width` and `height` to be `450`. Note that this isn't `50*8`, since these numbers correspond to the border-to-border edge of the forms window, including titlebar, the close button, etc.

The next line creates our canvas `$g` by calling the empty constructor. This defaults to the upper-left of the non-system area of the form being equal to `0,0` and increasing to the right and downward, perfect for our needs.

The next line is the actual call that draws the graphics, with `$f.add_paint({...})`. We construct the graphics calls by double-for looping from `0..7` and carrying a helper variable `$y` through each outer loop. Each inner loop, we tell our canvas to `.FillRectangle(...,...)` to draw our squares. The first parameter constructs a new `SolidBrush` with a color based on where we're at on the board. Other options here [could be](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.brush(v=vs.110).aspx) a hatch, a gradient, etc. The second parameter is a new `Rectangle` object starting at the specified x `$_*50` and `$y*50` coordinates and extending for `50` in each direction. Remember that `0,0` is the top-left.

The final line just displays the output with `.showDialog()`.
[image: PowerShell Forms]

Note that since we're creating a *form* object, and PowerShell is all about the pipeline, closing the pop-up form will pass along a `System.Enum.DialogResult` object of `Cancel`, since that's technically what the user did. Since we're not capturing or otherwise doing anything with that result, the word `Cancel` will be displayed to STDOUT when the program concludes, as it was left on the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>33</s>31 bytes

I used a trick with binary.

```
   load'viewmat'
   viewmat 8 8$#:43605
```

... because 43605 in binary is 1010101001010101 (we use `#:` primitive to get it). Primitive `$` shapes this array of binary digits into a matrix specified with the dimensions `8 8`. And `viewmat` is just a system library.
[image]
The window is fully resizable.

Thanks to @FrownyFrog for shortening it to:

```
   load'viewmat'
   viewmat#:8$170 85
```

Comment: `viewmat 8$#:170 85` is 1 byte shorter

Comment: `viewmat#:8$170 85`

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 82 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs a checkerboard to the range `A1:H8` on the ActiveSheet object

```vba
Cells.RowHeight=48:[B1:B8,D1:D8,F1:F8,H1:H8].Interior.Color=0:[A2,A4,A6,A8].Delete
```

This function works by first creating 4 black columns in the range `B1:B8,D1:D8,F1:F8,H1:H8` and then offsetting the coloring in rows `2,4,6 and 8` to the left by one cell.

#### Sample Output

[image: CheckerBoard]

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 21 bytes

Outputs a PBM image.

```
„P1Ž1‘D‚T50×{Ƶ%×Â«4×»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9vc2FiaWX//@KAnlAxxb0x4oCYROKAmlQ1MMOXe8a1JcOXw4LCqzTDl8K7//8)

**Commented**:

```python
„P1                   # push the string "P1"
   Ž1‘                # push 400
      D‚              # duplicate and pair to [400, 400]
        T             # push 10
         50×          # repeat this 50 times as a string => "1010 ... 10"
            {         # sort the string                  => "00...011...1"
             Ƶ%×      # repeat it 200 times
                      # this is now a string of length 20000 which represents the top rank 
                Â     # bifurcate: push the string and a reversed copy
                 «    # concatenate both, this is now the top two ranks
                  4×  # repeat this string 4 times
                    » # join the stack on newlines 
                      # this joins all lists on spaces: [400, 400] -> "400 400"
```

[image: converted to png]
<sup>This image was converted to png, [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ovs-code/071fac9dbb854e2ec203f2b0c3b820b3/raw/d5cdfba16fe739982c3525abcdfc0b065da91e3b/board.pbm) is the original output.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky2), 79 bytes

```
draw.newImageData(400,400).mapPixels((x,y)=>[c=1-(x//50+y//50)%2c,c]).export"o"
```

Or, if any size tiles is allowed...

## [Funky 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky2), 67 bytes

```
draw.newImageData(8,8).mapPixels((x,y)=>[c=1-(x+y)%2c,c]).export"o"
```

This produces a file called `o` which is a PNG file.

[image: Result]

### Breakdown

```
draw.newImageData(400,400)  $ Create the 8x8 chessboard at 50x50 pixels per square
.mapPixels((x,y)=>          $ Map each pixel in the image according to a function
    [ c = 1-(x//50+y//50)%2 $ This is the x added to the y of the chess tile, mod 2.
                            $ We take the result from 1 as otherwise 0, 0 is black.
    c,c ]                   $ Take the result and use it in G and B
                            $ Funky2 doesn't require a , for arguments where it is unambiguous
).export"o"                 $ Write the image to a file called "o", defaultly a PNG file.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scratch 3](http://scratch.mit.edu) (557 bytes)

Sb3 file - 4.15kb

The file can be found here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJ8gaVUMKGW0xdC1tQSJqy0fvGsIp8n0/view?usp=sharing

You need to have scratch installed on the system.

Scratchblocks syntax - 557 bytes

```py
when gf clicked
wait(0.4)seconds
go to x:(140)y:(140
stamp
repeat(3
change y by(-80
stamp
end
go to x:(140)y:(140
change x by(-40
change y by(-40
stamp
repeat(3
change y by(-80
stamp
end
go to x:(140)y:(140
change x by(-80
change y by(0
stamp
repeat(3
change y by(-80
stamp
end
go to x:(140)y:(140
change x by(-200
change y by(-40
stamp
repeat(3
change y by(-80
stamp
end
go to x:(140)y:(140
change x by(-240
change y by(0
stamp
repeat(3
change y by(-80
stamp
end
go to x:(140)y:(140
change x by(-280
change y by(-40
stamp
repeat(3
change y by(-80
stamp
end
```

:)

Comment: [You might want to use this scoring method to get the byte count down to a more reasonable number](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/78850)

Comment: @Lyxal Can you please convert it for me? it all went over my head when i read it

Comment: [557 bytes](https://gist.github.com/Lyxal/e530009cf5b93a10e89dbe03c176df56). Just paste the text as your answer. [Visualiser](https://scratchblocks.github.io)

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Lyxal

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 142 bytes

```java
import java.awt.*;v->new Frame(){public void paint(Graphics g){for(int i=32;i-->0;)g.fillRect(i%4*100+58-i%8/4*50,i/4*50+38,50,50);}{show();}}
```

Screenshot of the output:

[image]

**Explanation:**

```java
import java.awt.*;         // Required import for Frame and Graphics
v->                        // Method with empty unused parameter and Frame return-type
  new Frame(){             //  Create a new Frame
    public void paint(Graphics g){
                           //   Overwrite its paint method
      for(int i=32;i-->0;) //    Loop `i` in the range (32,0]:
        g.fillRect(        //     Draw a solid rectangle, with:
                           //     (the color is black by default)
                           //      The x-coordinate of the top-left corner is:
          i%4*100          //       `i` modulo-4, multiplied by 100
          +58              //       Plus 50 since the first square is white
                           //       Plus 8 for the Frame's border
          -i%8/4*50,       //       Minus `i` modulo-8, integer-divided by 4, multiplied by 50
                           //      The y-coordinate of the top-left corner is:
          i/4*50           //       `i` integer-divided by 4 multiplied by 50
          +38,             //       Plus 8 for the Frame's border
                           //       Plus 30 for the Frame's title bar
          50,50);}         //      With a size of 50x50 pixels
    {                      //   And in an inner code-block:
      show();}}            //    Show the Frame
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 129 bytes

```js
q=()=>{for(s="",i=72;i--;)s+=i%9?`<canvas height="50"width="50"style="background:#${i%2?'eee':'000'}"></canvas>`:'<br>';return s}

console.log(q())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczRDoIgAEDRX3GUA1YWc2uVCv6KiISUgwS0Nee3U6u3@3Lunc/cC6efIZsvMY4UYcqWm3XIUwD2mp7zUmdZif2O6vRaN5Xg5kuSXmrVBwpOBLx0F/pf@fAeJAUtFw/l7GS6YrNddJrXUEoJC0gIgStg1fE/YU0Bq9YxWDoZJmcSv0ZhjbeDPAxWoRFhHD8)

Function that returns an html chess board. Used a light grey instead of white for visibility sake.

Explanation:

````javascript
q=()=>{for(s="",i=72;i--;)s+=i%9?`<canvas height="50"width="50"style="background:#${i%2?'eee':'000'}"></canvas>`:'<br>';return s}
q=()=>    // Function definition
     {for(s="",i=72;i--;)  // Loop 72 times, while we're at it, initialise an empty string.
         s+=i%9?  // Add the following to the string:
           // IF not the 9th tile:
             <canvas height="50"width="50"style="background:#${i%2?'eee':'000'}"></canvas>
           // IF is the 9th tile:
             <br>

return s
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## CSS, 115 bytes

Using `repeating-conic-gradient` we can make a repeating chessboard pattern pretty efficiently in CSS without specifying any markup (but relying on the browser's default DOM structure):

```
*{background:#fff}*>*{width:400px;height:400px;background:repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0%25%,#fff 0%50%)0%0/25%25%
```

```css
*{background:#fff}*>*{width:400px;height:400px;background:repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0%25%,#fff 0%50%)0%0/25%25%
```

### Explanation:

```
*{background:#fff}
```

This applies a background to all visible elements (being the `<html>` and `<body>`). This is needed to avoid the `<body>` background from stretching to fit the viewport width, which happens if the `<html>` element has no background.

```
*>*
```

Select all elements descendants of other elements. The only visible element this applies to is the `<body>`.

```
width:400px;height:400px;
```

Set chessboard dimensions

```
repeating-conic-gradient( 
    #000 0%25%,
    #fff 0%50%
)
```

Creates a conic gradient shape with a black first quarter (from 0% to 25% or 0 to 90 deg), a white second quarter (from 25% to 50%, or 90 deg to 180deg) and repeats this way of coloring through the whole circle, resulting in four squares.

```
0%0/25%25%
```

Positioned at 0% 0% (upper left corner) and the size is set to 25%, relative to the body dimensions. This gives the conic gradient a full width/height of 100px, making each of the square/cell 50px.

### HTML and CSS alternative, 98 bytes

The above can be shortened slightly by relying on three bytes of HTML, although that won't really be CSS-only:

```
<p>
p{width:400px;height:400px;background:repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0%25%,#fff 0%50%)0%0/25%25%
```

```css
p{width:400px;height:400px;background:repeating-conic-gradient(#000 0%25%,#fff 0%50%)0%0/25%25%
```

```html
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

### [SELECT.](http://esolangs.org/wiki/SELECT.), <s>8844</s> 8278 bytes

```
(9,9,50)EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOOP.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.CONJ.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LEFT.EXP.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOOP.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LEFT.END.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOOP.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.END.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOOP.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.SELECT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.PRINT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.LEFT.END.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.SELECT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOOP.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.END.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.EXP.LEFT.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.RIGHT.EXP.LEFT.SELECT.RIGHT.LOG.RIGHT.SELECT.LEFT.END.
```

Sure it's long, but the first two versions I generated for this task were twice as long.

#### Output:

[image: screenshot]

#### How it Works:

Here's the program used to generate it:

```
init(9,9,50)
makenum(8)
square()
dec()
loop("main",computei=True)
go(1)
makenum(8)
go(1)
copyfrom(-2)
intdiv(-1)
add(-5)           # n%8 blah blah blah blah n//8 k^(n//8) k^(n%8) (n//8+n%8)
go(1)
makeneg1()
exptarget(-1)
go(1)
ifnonpositive("drawtest")
go(1)
makenum(-4,-4)    # n%8 blah blah blah blah n//8 k^(n//8) k^(n%8) n//8+n%8 (-1)^(n//8+n%8) 4 1/2 I k^(-4I) -1 (-4-4I)
go(1)
multiply(-4,-11)   # n%8 blah blah blah blah n//8 k^(n//8) k^(n%8) n//8+n%8 (-1)^(n//8+n%8) 4 1/2 I k^(-4I) -1 -4-4I (nI//8)
add(-16)          # n%8 blah blah blah blah n//8 k^(n//8) k^(n%8) n//8+n%8 (-1)^(n//8+n%8) 4 1/2 I k^(-4I) -1 -4-4I nI//8 k^(nI//8) k^(n%8) (n%8+nI//8)
add(-4)           # n%8 blah blah blah blah n//8 (-1)^(n%8) 4 1/2 I k^(-4I) -1 -4-4I nI//8 k^(nI//8) k^(n%8) n%8+nI//8 k^(n%8+nI//8) k^(-4-4I) ((n%8-4)+I(n//8-4))
output()
endif("drawtest")
go(1)
endloop("main")
writetofile("chessboard4")
```

In other words, loop n from 0 to 63, drawing a square at (n%8-4) + (n//8-4)i if (-1)^(n//8 + n%8) is not positive.

Comment: Thats not really golf is it :p?

Comment: I cannot be certain it's the shortest program that does the task, no. However, I am fairly certain that the difference between this and the best possible solution in this language is insignificant compared to the total length of the program. I have one more idea in mind that may or may not be shorter. I'll try it out sometime soon.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 147

```js
for(i=0;++i<72;)document.write(`<div style="${i%9?'':(++i,'clear:both;')}float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background:#${i&1?'fff':'000'}"></div>`)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 57 bytes

```
c=50*"1"+50*"0"
print"P1 400 400 "+4*(200*c+200*c[::-1])
```

`c` is a line of 50 white and 50 black pixels, `200*c` is a row with a white in the front, `200*c[::-1]` the reverse.

Output as PPM, usage:

```
python golf_chess.py > chess.ppm
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 157 Bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
x,q,a;FILE*f;w(){f=fopen("a","w");fprintf(f,"P1400 400 ");for(;a++<8;)for(q=0;q++<400;)for(x=0;x++<50;)fprintf(f,"%d",(q+a)%2);fclose(f);}
```

This generate the file `a`, one [PBM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).
You should add the `.pmb` extension

#### Full Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
x,q,a;FILE*f;w(){f=fopen("a","w");fprintf(f,"P1400 400 ");for(;a++<8;)for(q=0;q++<400;)for(x=0;x++<50;)fprintf(f,"%d",(q+a)%2);fclose(f);}
main(){w();}
```

### C, Shorter Version (98 Bytes)

```
x,q,a;w(){printf("P1400 400 ");for(;a++<8;)for(q=0;q++<400;)for(x=0;x++<50;)printf("%d",(q+a)%2);}
```

This version print in the STDOUT the file. So you have to redirect it in the file manually.

Comment: Should one not add a `.pbm` extension rather than `.pmb`?

Comment: I think your 98 bytes long approach defines a function that is not reusable.

Answer (score 0):

**Mathematica 43 bytes**

```
ArrayPlot@Partition[Range[0,7]~Mod~2,8,1,1]
ArrayPlot@ArrayPad[{{0,1},{1,0}},3,"Periodic"]
```

Comment: It appears that this is two separate solutions - you should consider separating them and labeling the larger of the two as an alternate solution. Also, as this is a graphic challenge, including a screencap of the output really helps to make your solution stand out (and thus get more points :))

Answer (score 0):

## [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language), 121 bytes

> LibreLogo produces a vector graphic that can be exported to SVG.

**Code:**

```
x=90 pu fc 0 repeat 64[ y=repcount if y%2=0[ square 1 ]if y%16=0[ rt x fd 1 rt x ][ if y%8=0[ lt x fd 1 lt x ][ fd 1 ] ]]
```

**Result**:

[image]

**Result (Expanded):**

[image]

**Explanation:**

```
x = 90                        ; x                  = 90°
pu                            ; Pen Up
fc 0                          ; Fill Color         = #000
repeat 64 [                   ; Repeat 64 Times
    y = repcount              ; y                  = Loop Index
    if y % 2 = 0 [
        square 1              ; Draw 1pt Square
    ]
    if y % 16 = 0 [
        rt x                  ; Turn Right 90°
        fd 1                  ; Move Forward 1pt
        rt x                  ; Turn Right 90°
    ] [
        if y % 8 = 0 [
            lt x              ; Turn Left 90°
            fd 1              ; Move Forward 1pt
            lt x              ; Turn Left 90°
        ] [
            fd 1              ; Move Forward 1pt
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Tcl/Tk, 130 bytes

```
time {incr j
time {grid [text .t[incr i]_$j -bg [expr ([incr n]+$j)%2?"#000":"#FFF"] -wi 6 -he 3] -row $j -column $i} 8
set i 0} 8
```

Could not get exactly 50 pixels per square, so I went to a round-up!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 95 bytes

```hs
f s="Be7#"*>s<*[1..50]
main=mapM putStrLn$"P1\n400 400":f(concat.f<$>[["0 ","1 "],["1 ","0 "]])
```

Outputs to stdout a [portable bitmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) (PBM), shown below at half size.

[image]

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2FbJKdVcWUnLrthGK9pQT89UIZYrNzEzzzY3scBXoaC0JLikyCdPRSnAMCbPxMBAAYiVrNI0kvPzkhNL9NJsVOyio5UMFJR0lAwVlGJ1okGUDkggNlbz/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>74</s> 71 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Outputs a PBM file to STDOUT.

```c
i;main(){for(;i<16e4;i++)puts(i?L"01"+(i/'N '^i/50)%2:"P1 400 400 0");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOjcxM09Dszotv0jDOtPG0CzVxDpTW1uzoLSkWCPT3kfJwFBJWyNTX91PQT0uU9/UQFPVyEopwFDBxMAAjA2UNK1r//8HAA)

Comment: @ceilingcat Neato!

Answer (score 0):

## [Processing](https://processing.org/), 66 bytes

`for(int x=64;x-->0;square(x/8*12,x%8*12,12))fill((x/8&1^x&1)*255);`

[image: chessboard]

Answer (score 0):

## x86 machine code, IBM PC, 30 bytes

```
00000000: b006 cd10 b40c 99b1 ff8a c1c0 e805 32c3  ..............2.
00000010: cd10 8ada c0eb 04e2 f0fe c279 eac3       ...........y..
```

**Listing**

```
B0 06       MOV  AL, 6          ; BIOS set video mode 6 (640x200 CGA, 1 bpp) 
CD 10       INT  10H 
B4 0C       MOV  AH, 0CH        ; BIOS draw graphics pixel function 
99          CWD                 ; Y counter DL = 0 (incrementing) 
        Y_LOOP: 
B1 FF       MOV  CL, 255        ; X counter CL = 255 (decrementing) 
        X_LOOP: 
8A C1       MOV  AL, CL         ; AL = column square number 
C0 E8 05    SHR  AL, 5          ; AL = CL / 32 
32 C3       XOR  AL, BL         ; alternate pixel colors 
CD 10       INT  10H            ; draw pixel at [CX, DX] 
8A DA       MOV  BL, DL         ; BL = row square number 
C0 EB 04    SHR  BL, 4          ; BL = DL / 16 
E2 F0       LOOP X_LOOP         ; loop X 255 times 
FE C2       INC  DL 
79 EA       JNS  Y_LOOP         ; loop Y 127 times 
C3          RET
```

Standalone executable DOS COM program. Draws using the BIOS `INT 10h` routines in CGA graphics mode 6 (640x200 black and white). Due to the PAR of this mode (3.2:1), the squares are 32x16 pixels to be roughly square when aspect corrected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 101 bytes

Does this count?

```javascript
console.log([...Array(8)].map((v,i)=>[...Array(8)].map((b,y)=>(i+y)%2?"⬛":"⬜").join``).join`\n`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/OT@vOD8nVS8nP10jWk9Pz7GoKLFSw0IzVi83sUBDo0wnU9PWDotEkk4lUEIjU7tSU9XIXunRmtlKVkByjpKmXlZ@Zl5CApSOyUvQ5Pr/HwA)