# Create a checkerboard matrix

Tags: code-golf, number, matrix

Take a positive integer **n** as input, and output a **n-by-n** checkerboard matrix consisting of **1** and **0**.

The top left digit should always be **1**.

**Test cases:**

```
n = 1
1

n = 2
1 0
0 1

n = 3
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1

n = 4
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

Input and output formats are optional. Outputting the matrix as a list of lists is accepted.

Comment: Is a list of strings OK?

Comment: Yes, that's OK.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/71093/build-a-chessboard).

Comment: Your examples show spaces between numbers on the same row, is that required, so as to look more like a square?

Comment: @BradC it's not required. The first approach [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126710/31516) is valid.

Comment: Can we take the input in unary if our language doesn't have the concept of a number? (e.g. `####` for input 4)

Comment: https://oeis.org/A100241 has all of the binary representations of this. Dunno how I'd even begin to use it though lol.

Comment: Can we output whatever value for 0 and whatever value for 1?

Comment: No, it should be 1 and 0.

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

52 seconds!

```
+€ḶḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7UdOahzu2PdzR9P//fxMA)

Comment: "52 seconds!" like I'm not used to it...

Comment: Do ya'll have, like, a beeper, you wear 24/7 for new PPCG challenges?

Comment: @carusocomputing Those who have a faster internet connection are usually the lucky ones that will win.

Answer (score 9):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
:otYT
```

Try it at [**MATL online!**](https://matl.io/?code=%3AotYT&inputs=4&version=20.2.1)

#### Explanation

Consider input `4` as an example.

```
:    % Implicit input, n. Push range [1 2 ... n]
     %   STACK: [1 2 3 4]
o    % Parity, element-wise
     %   STACK: [1 0 1 0]
t    % Duplicate
     %   STACK: [1 0 1 0], [1 0 1 0]
YT   % Toeplitz matrix with two inputs. Implicit display
     %   STACK: [1 0 1 0;
     %           0 1 0 1;
     %           1 0 1 0;
     5           0 1 0 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
ÆÇ+X v
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=xscrWCB2&input=NSAtUQ==) (Uses `-Q` flag for easier visualisation)

#### Explanation

```
 Æ   Ç   +X v
UoX{UoZ{Z+X v}}  // Ungolfed
                 // Implicit: U = input number
UoX{          }  // Create the range [0...U), and map each item X to
    UoZ{     }   //   create the range [0...U), and map each item Z to
        Z+X      //     Z + X
            v    //     is divisible by 2.
                 // Implicit: output result of last expression
```

An interesting thing to note is that `v` is *not* a "divisible by 2" built-in. Instead, it's a "divisible by X" built-in. However, unlike most golfing languages, Japt's functions do not have fixed arity (they can accept any number of right-arguments). When given 0 right-arguments, `v` assumes you wanted `2`, and so acts exactly like it was given `2` instead of nothing.

Answer (score 7):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>16</s>, 15 bytes

```
Ài10À­ñÙxñÎÀlD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3BDpqGB9OGGQ2sPbzw8swJI9B1uyHH5//@/OQA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: c069 3130 1bc0 adf1 d978 f1ce c06c 44    .i10.....x...lD
```

Answer (score 7):

### [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>50</s> <s>41</s> <s>39</s> 38 bytes

*Thanks to nimi and xnor for helping to shave off a total of <s>9</s> 10 bytes*

```
f n=r[r"10",r"01"]where r=take n.cycle
```

Alternately, for one byte more:

```
(!)=(.cycle).take
f n=n![n!"10",n!"01"]
```

or:

```
r=flip take.cycle
f n=r[r"10"n,r"01"n]n
```

Probably suboptimal, but a clean, straightforward approach.

Comment: `concat.repeat` is `cycle`: `n!l=take n$cycle l`. If you go pointfree it saves one more byte: `(!)=(.cycle).take`.

Comment: Lovely! I knew there was a builtin for that, but couldn't remember the name for the life of me

Comment: I was going to suggest `f n|r<-take n.cycle=r[r"10",r"01"]` or similar. but Haskell seems to infer the wrong type for `r`? It works with explicit typing `f n|r<-take n.cycle::[a]->[a]=r[r"10",r"01"]`.

Comment: That is really weird, especially given that `f n=r[r"10",r"01"] where r=take n.cycle` seems to work fine (but gives the same byte count as the current solution)

Comment: @JulianWolf Haskell seems to have [trouble inferring polymorphic types](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38142597#38142597)

Comment: @JulianWolf: you can omit the space before the `where`, so your function from the comment is 38 bytes

Comment: @JulianWolf This is because of the [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction).  I'm not sure if it's legal, but this is disabled by default in GHCi, so you might be able specify "Haskell - GHCi" to get the bytes.

Comment: @zbw I thought this was the case but using `NoMonomorphismRestriction` didn't help. Nor did `Rank2Types` or `RankNTypes`. Do you know what's going on there?

Comment: [Another](https://tio.run/##ZYzBCoJAGITvPsUgHQrZyKCLVE9Qp7rZEluu7db6K7lRie9um1YQ3oaZ7xslyos0pmlS0CKOszwZ6uA8mtZ6zuJwPCbO67OLExdZyHnDGLZKlhL3/GYSHCTkQxytecIqiVJkEkbSyarIc@jfaxD2f7v4Qevq2/SlquUr7nmZ0IQFUqMLZKJY7/F2ZhwD7AhsiST3gOJmN/a6Itf6FMFHEKBU@R3kxk4rrpqs29O2@wm@37wA "Haskell – Try It Online") solution at `39` bytes using only list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
~2|⍳∘.+⍳
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///3/FR24Q6o5pHvZsfdczQ0wbSQLFDK4C0CQA)

#### Explanation

Let's call the argument `n`.

```apl
⍳∘.+⍳
```

This creates a matrix

```apl
1+1 1+2 1+2 .. 1+n
2+1 2+2 2+3 .. 2+n
...
n+1 n+2 n+3 .. n+n
```

Then `2|` takes modulo 2 of the matrix (it vectorises) after which `~` takes the NOT of the result.

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript ES6, <s>55</s> <s>54</s> <s>51</s> 46 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Neil*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Arnauld*

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map(_=>++i&1))
```

[Try it online!](https://vihan.org/p/tio/?l=javascript-node&p=y0ktUUizVciztYvW09NzLCpKrNTI04zVy00s0NCI18nUSdS0tUuEcbOAnLpM7Sw1Q01NLq7k/Lzi/JxUvZz8dI00DaCQNZqQEaaQMaaQCVDoPwA)

This outputs as an array of arrays. JavaScript ranges are pretty unweildy but I use `[...Array(n)]` which generates an array of size `n`

Comment: It's still a byte shorter to use the index parameters: `n=>[...Array(n)].map((_,i,a)=>a.map((_,j)=>(i+j+1)%2))`

Comment: @Neil huh, I never thought to use the third parameter in map, thanks!

Comment: @Arnauld thanks! that inspired me to save 5 more bytes!

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 25 bytes

```
1-Plus~Array~{#,#}~Mod~2&
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>33</s> 30 bytes

```
.+
$*
1
$_¶
11
10
T`10`01`¶.+¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYvLkEsl/tA2LkNDLkMDrpAEQ4MEA8OEQ9v0tA9t@//fFAA) Explanation: The first stage converts the input to unary using `1`s (conveniently!) while the second stage turns the value into a square. The third stage inverts alternate bits on each row while the last stage inverts bits on alternate rows. Edit: Saved 3 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder.

Comment: `$\`1$'` is just `$_`.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 7 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Emigna

```
LDÈD_‚è
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fx@Vwh0v8o4ZZh1f8/28MAA)

#### Explanation

```
LDÈD_‚sè» Argument n
LD        Push list [1 .. n], duplicate
  ÈD      Map is_uneven, duplicate
    _     Negate boolean (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0)
     ‚    List of top two elements of stack
      è   For each i in [1 .. n], get element at i in above created list
          In 05AB1E the element at index 2 in [0, 1] is 0 again
```

Comment: You can cut the `»` as list-of-lists output is okay and you can also remove `s`.

Comment: Explanation is a bit irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
:t!+2\~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36pEUdsopu7/fxMA)

**Explanation:**

```
         % Implicit input (n)
:        % Range from 1-n, [1,2,3]
 t       % Duplicate, [1,2,3], [1,2,3]
  !      % Transpose, [1,2,3], [1;2;3]
   +     % Add        [2,3,4; 3,4,5; 4,5,6]
    2    % Push 2     [2,3,4; 3,4,5; 4,5,6], 2
     \   % Modulus    [0,1,0; 1,0,1; 0,1,0]
      ~  % Negate     [1,0,1; 0,1,0; 1,0,1]
```

<sub>Note: I started solving this in MATL *after* I posted the challenge.</sub>

Comment: Equivalent, and shorter: `:&+o~`

Comment: Still learning :-) I'll update tomorrow. I liked your other approach too :-)

Comment: This is what I came up with, too. And hey, you only use the *pure* MATL instruction set, not those pesky `Y`-modified instructions @LuisMendo uses.

Comment: @Sanchises Pesky, [huh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116386/36398)? :-P

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>80</s> 77 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```java
j->{String s="1";for(int i=1;i<j*j;s+=i++/j+i%j&1)s+=1>i%j?"\n":"";return s;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU69asMwEJ6dpzgELXbdqBgyVbG7FTp0yth2UB3ZnKqchHQKhOBndwXJdN8/Z/VZb30wZI9/a8i/DkcYnU4JPjXSdVPdtcSayzl7PMKpOPWBI9L89QM6zqkpwcqWKZkZnZwyjYye5Psd7D@IzWziM9xqA0zQr3Y7XG8cUi86oSYfayQG7DuFe/tkVWp7bNsX2@KDfeyaQruhwDfxTeJVCBUN50iQ1LJWlSpPHC6JzUn6zDKUZXZUT1KH4C71rmlKYtks6z8)

Oh look, a semi-reasonable length java answer, with lots of fun operators.

lambda which takes an int and returns a String.  Works by using the row number and column number using / and % to determine which value it should be, mod 2;

Ungolfed:

```java
j->{
    String s="1";
    for(int i=1; i<j*j; s+= i++/j + i%j&1 )
        s+= 1>i%j ? "\n" : "";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the space to save a byte. The challenge states the output format is flexible. Oh, and you can save two more bytes by changing `(i++/j+i%j)%2` to `i++/j+i%j&1` so you won't need those parenthesis. Which make the total 1 byte shorter than my nested for-loop solution (`n->{String r="";for(int i=0,j;i++<n;r+="\n")for(j=0;j<n;r+=j+++i&1);return r;}`), so +1 from me. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yeah I was still waiting on a response on the space.  I didn't think about & having higher precedence than % and &1 == %2

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 15 bytes

```
^₂⟦₁%₂ᵐ;?ḍ₎pᵐ.\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P@5RU9Oj@cseNTWqAlkPt06wtn@4o/dRU18BkK0X8/@/6f8oAA)

#### Explanation

```
Example Input: 4

^₂               Square:                            16
  ⟦₁             1-indexed Range:                   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
    %₂ᵐ          Map Mod 2:                         [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]
       ;?ḍ₎      Input-Chotomize:                   [[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
           pᵐ.   Map permute such that..
             .\  ..the output is its own transpose: [[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,1]]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure, 36 bytes

```
#(take %(partition % 1(cycle[1 0])))
```

Yay, right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
<0&=$&1 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krBxkDNVkXNUMGAiys1OSNfIU3B5P9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 5 bytes

```
ᵒ+→2%
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fisfbp2k_ahtkpHqkuKk5GKo6ILlhlxGXMZcJhAuAA)

```
ᵒ+→2%
ᵒ+       Create an (input x input) matrix where the element at (i,j) is i+j
  →      Increment
   2%    Mod 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 19 bytes

```
⟦₁Rg;Rz{z{++₁%₂}ᵐ}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//9H8ZY@aGoPSrYOqqquqtbWBHNVHTU21D7dOAOH//03@RwEA)

Answer (score 2):

## Charcoal, 8 bytes

```
ＵＯＮ10¶01
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9jaGFyY29hbP//77y177yv77yuMTDCtjAx//81) Explanation: This roughly translates to the following verbose code (unfortunately the deverbosifier is currently appending an unnecessary separator):

```
Oblong(InputNumber(), "10\n01");
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, <s>69</s> <s>67</s> 63 bytes

*Thanks to @Kevin Cruijssen for saving two bytes and @ceilingcat for saving four bytes!*

```
i,j;f(n){for(i=n;i--;puts(""))for(j=n;j;)printf("%d",j--+i&1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcy7CoAwDIXh3aeQgpKgGbxswYeRSiUFq3iZxGevEXTyTD/fcCyN1sYopWcHAU83ryBdYCHi5dg3MAbxQa/oGZdVwu7AZIMpPVEheYV8RcV06iUAJmeS6hyofwf8Uv2n5k@t1hVv)

Comment: You can remove the space in `printf("%d "`, since that's another valid method of output.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Yeah, thanks.

Comment: You can save two bytes by changing `(j+++i)%2` to `j+++i&1` to remove those parenthesis.

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 9 bytes

```
VQm%+hdN2
```

[Try this!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQm%25%2BhdN2&input=10&debug=0)

another 9 byte solution:

```
mm%+hdk2Q
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=mm%25%2Bhdk2Q&input=10&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 87 bytes + input

```
/V/\\\///D/VV//*/k#D#k/k#D&k/k&DVk/k\D/SD/#/r
DSkk/10DSk/1D&/V#rV#0r;VV0;VVV1;V\D/r/S/&[unary input in asterisks]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcohCsAwEERR32ssRNT8RMfuDQKjYioKhVQl9yfdDswbM@u91nOvvRG9d8CR4GSY2/hNYXKF3WmOMQ9vY1ByDMUTsinLs0o5qlIV10kjnZG9Pw) (input for 4)

### Unary input in `1`s, 95 bytes + input

```
/V/\\\///D/VV//&1/k#&D&|D/#k/k#D&k/k&DVk/k\D/SD/#/r
DSkk/10DSk/1D&/V#rV#0r;VV0;VVV1;V\D/r/S/&&[unary input in ones]|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYoxCsQwEAP7@4Zh2/HWafcHBlVuUgQOnMpu83dniwg0EkLrPtf/Wnsjeu9AIIE5o1jYE5SRNSxpoWQPWq7MX7Qx8JqBh6EyVeo8pJqWH8rrpGHmn569Xw) (input for 8)

#### How does this work?

- `V` and `D` are to golf `\/` and `//` respectively.
- `/*/k#/` and `/&1/k#&//&|//` separate the input into the equivalent of `'k#'*len(input())`
- `/#k//k#//&k/k&//\/k/k\//` move all the `k`s to the `/r/S/` block
- `S`s are just used to pad instances where `k`s come after `/`s so that they don't get moved elsewhere, and the `S`s are then removed
- `#`s are then turned into `r\n`s
- The string of `k`s is turned into an alternating `1010...` string
- The `r\n`s are turned into `1010...\n`s
- Every pair of `1010...\n1010\n` is turned into `1010...\01010...;\n`
- Either `0;` or `1;` are trimmed off (because the `01010...` string is too long by 1)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 24 bytes

```matlab
@(n)~mod((a=(1:n))+a',2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjT7MuNz9FQyPRVsPQKk9TUztRXcdI83@ahonmfwA)

---

Or the same length:

```matlab
@(n)mod(toeplitz(1:n),2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjTzM3P0WjJD@1ICezpErD0CpPU8dI83@ahonmfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 23 bytes

```
ToeplitzMatrix@#~Mod~2&
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```r
n=scan();(matrix(1:n,n,n,T)+1:n-1)%%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTWiM3saQos0LD0CpPBwRDNLWBTF1DTVVVo/8m/wE)

-1 byte thanks to Giuseppe

Takes advantage of R's recycling rules, firstly when creating the matrix, and secondly when adding 0:(n-1) to that matrix.

Comment: You can drop a byte by getting rid of the `t` and instead constructing the matrix with `byrow=T`, i.e., `(matrix(1:n,n,n,T)+1:n-1)%%2`

Comment: `outer(1:n,1:n-1,"+")%%2` is quite a few bytes shorter :)

Answer (score 2):

### Swi-Prolog, 142 bytes.

```
t(0,1).
t(1,0).
r([],_).
r([H|T],H):-t(H,I),r(T,I).
f([],_,_).
f([H|T],N,B):-length(H,N),r(H,B),t(B,D),f(T,N,D).
c(N,C):-length(C,N),f(C,N,1).
```

Try online - http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/BuabBPrw.pl

It outputs a nested list, so the rules say:

- `t()` is a toggle, it makes the 0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0.
- `r()` succeeds for an individual row, which is a recursive check down a row that it is alternate ones and zeros only.
- `f()` recursively checks all the rows, that they are the right length, that they are valid rows with `r()` and that each row starts with a differing 0/1.
- `c(N,C)` says that C is a valid checkerboard of size N if the number of rows (nested lists) is N, and the helper f succeeds.

Test Cases:
[image]

Comment: Can't you strip off all newlines?

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>39</s> 36 bytes

```arturo
$[n][map..1n'x->map..1n'y->%x+y+1 2]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?MhWhVe)

-3 thanks to alephalpha's simpler method

Prettified and rearranged for clarity:

```
$[n][                     ; a function taking an argument n
    map 1..n 'x ->        ; map over 1..n, assign current elt to x
        map 1..n 'y ->    ; map over 1..n again, assign current elt to y
            (x+y+1)%2     ; what it looks like
]                         ; end function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ʁ∷:v=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgeKItzp2PSIsIiIsIjQiXQ==)

*-3 thanks to @lyxal* 
*-1 thanks to @emanresuA*

##### Explanation

```
ʁ∷:v=    implicit input
ʁ        range(input)
 ∷       mod 2
  :      duplicate
   v=    equals, vectorised over the top list
         (generates a nested list)
```

Old:

```
ɾ∷ẋ⁽†ẇ    implicit input
ɾ         range(1, input+1)
 ∷        mod 2
  ẋ       repeated input times
     ẇ    apply to every 2nd item:
   ⁽†     vectorised not
```

```
ʁ:∷:†$"$İ    implicit input
ʁ:           range, duplicate
  ∷:         mod 2, duplicate
    †        vectorised not
     $"      swap and pair
       $İ    swap and index in
```

Comment: [Seems to work on the official site](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgTriiLc64oCgJFwiJMSwIiwiIiwiMiJd)

Comment: @lyxal it works now, but when I answered the official site wasn't loading

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuKIt+G6i+KBveKAoOG6hyIsIiIsIjQiXQ==) for 6 bytes

Comment: @lyxal thanks, can you check my explanation?

Comment: 100% accurate. Good job!

Comment: [5](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLKgeKItzp2PSIsIiIsIjUiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
identity(Ans→[A]
Fill(1,[A]
cumSum([A]
2fPart(.5(Ans+Ansᵀ+[A]
```

Takes input in `Ans`.
-1 byte thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 56 bytes

Output as string

```php
for(;$i<$argn**2;)echo++$i%2^$n&1,$i%$argn?"":"
".!++$n;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkomT9Py2/SMNaJdMGLKSlZWStmZqcka@trZKpahSnkqdmqANkgSXtlZSslLiU9BSBknnW//9/zcvXTU5MzkgFAA)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 66 bytes

Output as 2 D array

```php
for(;$i<$argn**2;$i%$argn?:++$n)$r[+$n][]=++$i%2^$n&1;print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkomT9Py2/SMNaJdMGLKSlZQRkq4LZ9lba2ip5mipF0UAqNjrWFsjNVDWKU8lTM7QuKMrMK4kv0lAp0rT@//9rXr5ucmJyRioA)

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 19 bytes

```
[:|?[b|?(a+c+1)%2';
```

### Explanation

```
[:|         FOR a = 1 to b (b is read from cmd line)
?           PRINT - linsert a linebreak in the output
[b|         FOR c = 1 to b
?(a+c+1)%2  PRINT a=c=1 modulo 2 (giving us the 1's and 0's
';            PRINT is followed b a literal semi-colon, suppressing newlines and 
              tabs. Printing numbers in QBasic adds one space automatically.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 17 bytes

```
{_[__AAb*<_:!]*<}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/Oj46Pt7RMUnLJt5KMVbLpvZ/XXCalp/WfxMA)

Returns a list (TIO link has formatted output).

Comment: [out-golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/126774/61384)

Comment: @Challenger5 Sorry you can't outgolf with deleted answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + rs, 42

```bash
eval echo \$[~{1..$1}+{1..$1}\&1]|rs $1 $1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@kUJJaXJKcWJyqkJmnYKhgpGCsYKJgaq2Qks@lAAQFRZl5JWkKSnm2qsVWMXlKCiow9WDp4tQSBV1dhOD/1LLEHIXU5Ix8hRiV6LpqQz09FcNabSgdo2YYW1NUrKBiCET/Qaq4UvLzUv8DAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 38 bytes

```
n->(|>n).map(i->(|>n).map(j->i+j+1&1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ITUlJLPpfUJSZV6LxP0/XTqPGLk9TLzexQCMTmZOla5epnaVtqGaoqflfU8NE8z8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>73 63 62</s> 66 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [officialaimm](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59523/officialaimm)

```
r=range(input());print[''.join([`(x+y+1)%2`for x in r])for y in r]
```

Comment: Declaring `R=range(n)` and using `R` saves 3 bytes. 1 unwanted space between `)` and `for` can be removed as well.

Comment: @officialaimm Sweet, thanks for the tip! I'm new a golfing. I'm thankful for any tips :)

Comment: Just noticed your code is just a snippet, not a function or  full program which is not a healthy practice. [You can use this instead, only 8 bytes more!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v8i2KDEvPVUjM6@gtERDU9O6oCgzryRaXV0vKz8zTyM6QaNCu1LbUFPVKCEtv0ihQiEzT6EoVhPEroSw//83AwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @officialaimm Noted. Still better than my original submission. Thanks a bunch. :)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
Cos[+##/2Pi]^2&~Array~{#,#}&
```

Pure function taking a positive integer as input and returning a 2D array. Uses the periodic function cos²(πx/2) to generate the 1s and 0s.

For a little more fun, how about the 32-byte solution

```
Sign@Zeta[1-+##]^2&~Array~{#,#}&
```

which uses the locations of the trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 1):

## q/kdb+, <s>37</s> 16 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{x#x#'(1 0;0 1)}
```

**Example:**

```
q){x#x#'(1 0;0 1)}1
1
q){x#x#'(1 0;0 1)}2
1 0
0 1
q){x#x#'(1 0;0 1)}3
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
q){x#x#'(1 0;0 1)}4
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
```

**Explanation:**

2nd version is *much* simpler, and thus shorter and faster (4x). Create a 2-item list containing 01... and 10... to the length of the input, then take 'x' number of items from this new list.

```
{              } / lambda function
      (1 0;0 1)  / 2-item list of (0;1) and (1;0)
   x#'           / take 'x' items from each list, if x=3 then (1 0 1;0 1 0)
 x#              / take 'x' items from *this* list
```

**Notes:**

I've re-written this twice during this edit, went from 37->25->24->16 bytes. Now it's a little more competitive.

**Edits:**

- -21 bytes with complete re-write...

Answer (score 1):

## [braingasm](https://github.com/daniero/braingasm), 21 bytes

```
;$[$[>+o:<]p[>+<]10.]
```

Explanation:

```
;                       Read a number from stdin.
 $[                 ]   That many times...
   $[     ]               That many times...
     >+o:<                  Increase the next cell and print its value modulo 2.
           p[   ]       If the input was even...
             >+<          Increase the next cell once more.
                 10.    Print a newline.
```

Answer (score 1):

### J, 41 bytes

I know there's a J answer at 9, but I'm pleased to get anything working, even if it's not a tacit programming best possible..

```
ch=:monad define
2|(2$y)$(1+i.y),(i.y)
)
```

It takes a number `y` and generates two lists of numbers `1,2,3,..y` and `0,1,2,3,..y-1` to make the offset first and second row, appends them into one long list, reshapes that into a y,y matrix (wrapping around when it runs out), and then does modulo 2 on all the elements to make them a 1 or 0.

```
   ch 1
1

   ch 2
1 0
0 1

   ch 3
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1

   ch 4
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1

   ch 5
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 43 bytes

```hs
h=1:0:h
l=h:(0:h):l
s x=take x$map(take x)l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P8PW0MrAKoMrxzbDSgPI0LTK4SpWqLAtScxOVahQyU0s0IAwNXP@5yZm5tkWFGXmlagUKxga/AcA)

This creates the infinite checkerboard matrix and saves it to `l`.  Then our function `s` chops off a square.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

```
´Ṫ=↑İ¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARcA6P9odXNr///CtOG5qj3ihpHEsMKs////NA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 12 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.88 bytes

```
RD2%D1_ZPsAH
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZrglyMVF0M46MCih09IEJQmQULTSEMAA) or [see it in a nicer format](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FmuCXIxUXQzjowKKHT0gQlCZBQtNIQwA)

##### Explanation

```python
RD2%D1_ZPsAH  # Implicit input                Example: n=3
RD            # Duplicate range(input)        STACK: [0, 1, 2],  [0, 1, 2]
  2%D         # Duplicate ^ mod 2             STACK: [0, 1, 2],  [0, 1, 0],  [0, 1, 0]
     1_       # 1 - top copy of ^             STACK: [0, 1, 2],  [0, 1, 0],  [1, 0, 1]
       ZP     # Pair top two items            STACK: [0, 1, 2],  [[0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
         sAH  # 1-based modular indexing      STACK: [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
              # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
ř2%Đɐ=Ɩ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6Ewj1SMTTk6wPTbt/39DAwA)

```
ř                    implicit input; řangify
 2%                  modulo 2
   Đ                 Đuplicate
    ɐ=               for ɐll possible pairs, check for equality
      Ɩ              coerce booleans to integers; implicit print
```

Prints list of lists

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-S`, 8 bytes

```
%U$+GMCa
```

Other list-formatting flags such as `-l` and `-p` work too. Without a flag, the list of lists is printed without any separators (e.g. `1001` for input `2`), which seemed like stretching the permissive output format a bit too far.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSbrBS7IKlpSVpuhYrVENVtN19nRMhXKjo4mgTmAIA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
       a  ; Command-line argument
     MC   ; Map to a square coordinate grid of that size:
  $+G     ;   Sum the two coordinates
 U        ;   Increment
%         ;   Mod 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 89 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(n int){
for i:=1;i<=n;i++{
for j:=i;j<i+n;j++{Print(j%2)}
Println()}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70oPX_BmoLE5OzE9FSF3MTMvKWlJWm6FjcjM3ML8otK9JTSckuUuNJK85IV0jTyFDLzSjSrudLyixQyrWwNrTNtbPOsM7W1IUJZVraZ1lk2mdp51llAsYAioGqNLFUjzVouMDsnT0OzthZqgR_YTJCNGpoK1VwKQOONNIEUTKWSkiZY0BiboAm6INTUBQsgNAA)

Prints a multi-line string.

##### Explanation

```golang
import ."fmt"               // Boilerplate
func f(n int) {             // Function f taking an integer n:
for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {   //  Loop through each i in [1..n]:
for j := i; j < i+n; j++ {  //   Loop through each j in [i..i+n]:
Print(j%2)}                 //    Print j mod 2 without a newline
Println()}}                 //   Print a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RɗDȷ=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWy4NOTnc5sd12SXFScjFUbMFCYwgDAA)

Port of my Vyxal answer.

##### Explanation

```python
       # implicit input
R      # one range
 ɗ     # mod 2
  D    # duplicate
   ȷ   # outer product:
    =  #  equality
       # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊞=.◿2⇡
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_2_0__ZiDihpAg4oqePS7il78y4oehCgpmIDEKZiAyCmYgMwpmIDQK)

```
⊞=.◿2⇡
     ⇡  # range
   ◿2   # modulo 2
  .     # duplicate
⊞=      # table by equality
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
Table[Mod[i+j+1,2],{i,#},{j,#}]&
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 38 bytes

```
n->map(x->x%2,(1:n).+transpose(0:n-1))
```

The usual approach

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>72</s> <s>70</s> <s>61</s> 54 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun. -1 byte thanks to Wheat Wizard.*

```python
lambda n:[[i-~j&1for i in range(n)]for j in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjo6U7cuS80wLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjTzMWJJKFIvK/oCgzr0QhTcNQkwvM5IIJGKELGKMLmGj@BwA)

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjo6UztL21DNMC2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw1AnT9tQMxYkmoUh@r@gKDOvRCFNw1CTC8zkggkYoQsYowuYaP4HAA)

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjo6UztL21DNMC2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1VI08zFiSShSLyv6AoM69EIU3DUJMLzOSCCRihCxijC5ho/gcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 15 bytes

```
r;╗⌠╜+u⌠2@%⌡M⌡M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/7/I@tHU6Y96FjyaOke7FEgbOag@6lnoC8L//5sAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 43 bytes

```python
lambda n:[('10'*n)[i:i+n]for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKlpD3dBAXStPMzrTKlM7LzYtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSNPM/Y/XMhQx0jHWMdEx9SKi7OgKDOvRCFNI1PzPwA)

Anonymous function that outputs a list like `['1010', '0101', '1010', '0101']`.

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 82

```
time {set a "";time {set a $a[expr [incr i]%2]} $n;puts $a;if \!($n%2) incr\ i} $n
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/UESAPL68688)

Still a looser, but I think i can be golfed down a little bit further.

Answer (score 0):

**C#, 145 Bytes**

```
int u=1;int n=int.Parse(b.Text);for(int i=0;i<n;i++){if(i%2==0){u=1;}else{u=0;}for(int j=0;j<n;j++){t.Text+=u.ToString();u=1-u;}t.Text+="\r\n";}[enter link description here][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1krBxkDNVkXNUMGAiys1OSNfIU3B5P9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## Bash & coreutils, 82 bytes

```
x=$1;yes 10|tr -d \\n|dd bs=1 count=$[x*x*2]|fold -w$[x*2-1]|grep -om$x "^.\{$x\}"
```

Takes one command-line integer as input.  Apparently the spaces between are optional.

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, SBCL, 81 bytes

version 1:

```
(#1=dotimes(i(set'a(read)))(#1#(j a)(format t"~:[1~;0~] "(oddp(+ j i))))(terpri))
```

version 2:

```
(lambda(n)(#1=dotimes(i n)(#1#(j n)(format t"~:[1~;0~] "(oddp(+ j i))))(terpri)))
```

Two loops, and inside I print either 1 and space or zero and space based on parity of `(+ j i)`. `(terpri)` for newline.

It's long, I know:/

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 88 bytes

```cs
n=>{var r=new int[n,n];for(int i=0,j;i<n;i++)for(j=0;j<n;j++)r[i,j]=(i+j+1)%2;return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY9RS8MwEMff@ymOgpCQOlpxL6aZD4IvIog@@DD7ELpUErYEkmwyRj97vbag6xiieA93ubs///ulDpe186oDjHotQ4An79693CT95DDkPkKUUdewc3oFj1JbQr9W36I@XvYhqs3sfmvrUtuYAaZlVi2gAZF0ViwOO@nBC6s@hpXNbMUb5wk2oEWeGa5LyzVjtJ8akXODvcHeL3VmKkE0M6ygF1fcq7j1FjxvO55MKPobAQQ0ZE75ZIOmMN7Cdc6xlDDHgv4T3URrRq0Zteac9ujvd84Gt1azV6@jIgGpwVTAgKCNgGu4hfTNpnADaUrpCfgIXfyGuvgLdvFv7uJn8BOPZyVXD2pPjv7RDq@2@wQ)

I can't believe this is the shortest way to initialize a 2D array of integers, there must be another way...

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 49 bytes

```perl
$_=10x(($n=<>)/2).1x($n%2);say&&y/01/10/while$n--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbQoEJDQyXP1sZOU99IU8@wAshRNdK0Lk6sVFOr1Dcw1Dc00C/PyMxJVcnT1f3/39DgX35BSWZ@XvF/XV9TPQNDAwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>60</s> 59 bytes

```c
i;f(n){for(i=n*n;i--;)printf(i%n?"%d":"%d\n",i%n+i/n+1&1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk0jT7M6Lb9II9M2TyvPOlNX11qzoCgzryRNI1M1z15JNUXJCkjE5CnpAPnamfp52oZqhprWtf@BahRyEzPzNDS5qrkUgCBNAyheUFpSrKGkpGkNFTLCFDLGFDIBsmr/AwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>5</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Outputs a 2D array.

```
W£°v
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LW0&code=V6Owdg&footer=uA&input=NAotUg)